# Erro - "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent"

Tags: php, redirecionamento, http-headers

Tenho o seguinte código utilizando a função `header()` do PHP:

```
header("location: painel.php?spv=nav/regMove");
exit;
```

e quando ela é acionada reporta o seguinte erro:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Por que que isto possivelmente ocorre?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Esse erro deve ser o mais perguntado da história da Internet. Esta resposta é uma tradução de outra mais completa e explicativa [originalmente postada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php) no StackOverflow em Inglês feita por um colega de comunidade.

Adicionalmente eu revisei muito da tradução (incluindo gramática) e, obviamente, refiz toda a formatação para o *markdown* usado no/pelo Stack Overflow. Mas ainda assim, se houver(em) erro(s), sintam-se livres para corrigir ou complementar.

---

**Não emita *output* antes de enviar os *headers*!**

Funções que enviam/modificam *headers* HTTP devem ser chamadas **antes de que qualquer *output* seja feito**. Caso contrário, a chamada falhará.

> *Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent (output started at **file:line***)

Algumas funções que modificam os *headers* HTTP são:

- [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php) / [`header_remove()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header-remove.php)
- [`session_start`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php) / [`session_regenerate_id()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-regenerate-id.php)
- [`setcookie()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php) / [`setrawcookie()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setrawcookie.php)

*Output* pode ser:

- *Acidental*

  - Espaços em branco antes da *tag* `<?php` ou depois da `?>`
  - [UTF-8 *Byte Order Mark* (BOM)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_ordem_de_byte)
  - Mensagens de erros ou *notices* anteriores
- *Intencional:*

  - print, echo e outras funções que emitem *output*, como [`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/var_dump)
  - Código `<html>` antes do código dentro de `<?php`.

**Por que isso acontece?**

Para entender porque os *headers* devem ser enviados antes do *output*, é necessário olhar uma típica *HTTP Response*. *Scripts* PHP geram conteúdo HTML principalmente, mas também passam alguns *headers* HTTP/CGI ao servidor.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Powered-By: PHP/5.3.7
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<html><head><title>PHP page output page</title></head>
<body><h1>Content</h1> <p>Some more output follows...</p>
and <a href="/"> <img src=about:note> ...
```

A página/*output* sempre segue os *headers*. O PHP é obrigado a passar os *headers* ao servidor primeiramente. Ele pode apenas fazer isto uma vez. E depois da quebra de linha dupla (envio de *output* para simplificar), ele não pode adicionar mais *headers*.

Quando o PHP recebe o primeiro *output* (print, echo, ), ele irá enviar os *headers* coletados. Mais tarde, ele pode enviar todos o conteúdo do *output* que quiser. Mas, não é possível enviar novos *headers* a partir deste momento.

**Como você pode descobrir onde o *output* ocorreu?**

O *warning* da função [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php) contém todas as informações relevantes para localizar a raiz do problema:

> *Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by **(output started at** /www/usr2345/htdocs/**auth.php**:52) in /www/usr2345/htdocs/index.php on line 100*

Aqui, a **line 100** refere-se à linha do *script* onde a chamada da função [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php) falhou.
A mensagem dentro dos parênteses é mais importante. Ela menciona que a **linha 52** do arquivo **auth.php** é a raiz do *output*. Uma das causas mais populares deste erro são:

**Print, echo**

*Output* intencional de execuções print e echo vão acabar com a oportunidade de enviar *headers* HTTP. O fluxo da aplicação deve ser reestruturado para evitar isso. Use [funções](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.functions.php) e *templates*. Verifique se as chamadas para a função [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php) ocorrem antes de que as mensagens são enviadas.

Funções que podem enviar *output* incluem mas não se limitam a: print, echo, [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/printf), [`trigger_error()`](https://www.php.net/trigger_error), [`vprintf()`](https://www.php.net/vsprintf), [`ob_flush()`](https://www.php.net/ob_flush), [`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/var_dump), [`readfile()`](https://www.php.net/readfile), [`passthru()`](https://www.php.net/passthru), entre outras. E também funções definidas por você.

**Código HTML**

Códigos HTML que não são interpretados em um arquivo .php são *outputs* também. Códigos que chamarão a função [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php) devem ser feitas antes de qualquer código .

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <?php // Já não é possível enviar *headers*.
```

Espaços em branco antes de `<?php` quando "arquivo.php **line 1**" é mencionado.
Se a mensagem diz que o erro está na linha 1, então é normalmente espaços em branco, texto ou HTML antes da abertura da *tag* `<?php`.

```
 <?php # Há um espaço/linha em branco antes de <?php
```

Podem igualmente ocorrer com *scripts* "juntos".

```
?> <?php
```

O PHP, na verdade, coloca uma quebra de linha depois de fechar as tags.

**UTF-8 BOM**

Quebras de linhas e espaços podem ser um problema. Mas também há sequências de caracteres "invisíveis" que podem causar isto. o mais popular é o [UTF-8 BOM (*Byte-Order-Mark*)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_ordem_de_byte) que não é exibido pela maioria dos editores de texto. É uma sequência de bytes, que é opcional e redundante para arquivos em **UTF-8**.

Mas o interpretador do PHP o trata como *output*. Ele também pode mostrar como caracteres **ï»¿** no *output* (se o cliente interpreta o documento em *Latin-1*) ou algum "lixo" semelhante.

Particularmente, alguns editores gráficos e IDEs *Java-based* não notam sua presença.  Elas não vêem isso graças ao padrão Unicode. Entretanto, alguns editores e consoles mostram:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não é fácil reconhecer o problema logo no início. Sem um editor desses disponível ou [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) no Windows (que pode [resolver o problema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589358/fix-utf8-bom)), uma  outra solução seria um **hexeditor**. Programadores deveriam ter um, pois eles simplificam a identificação desses problemas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A solução fácil é definir o editor de texto usado para salvar arquivos como **UTF-8 (no BOM)** ou alguma outra nomenclatura semelhante ou traduzida. Muitos novos programadores criam novos arquivos por copiar/colar os antigos, apenas alterando seu conteúdo depois.

**Utilitários de correção**

Há ferramentas automatizadas para reescrever arquivos de texto. Para o PHP, especificamente, há o [*phptags tag tidier*](http://include-once.org/p/phptags/). Ele reescreve tags de abertura e fechamento em tags longas e curtas, mas também resolve facilmente problemas de *whitespace* e BOM:

```
phptags --whitespace *.php
```

> É sensato usar em um diretório completo ou no diretório do projeto.

**Espaços em branco após ?>**

Se a raiz do erro é mencionada depois do fechamento da `?>`, então aí é onde há algum espaço em branco ou texto escrito.

A *tag* de fechamento do PHP não termina a execução do script neste ponto. Quaisquer caracteres depois dela serão impressos como *output*.

É comumente dito aos novatos que a *tag* de fechamento deveria ser omitida. Isso evita uma parte significante destes casos. *Includes* normalmente são os culpados.

Novamente, `phptags --whitespace *.php` resolve isso rapidamente.

Igualmente, o comando `phptags --unclosed ./includes` pode remover tags `?>` redundantes dos *scripts*.

**Raíz do erro mencionada como "Unknown on line 0"**

Acontece tipicamente quando extensões PHP ou o *php.ini* definem se a raiz do erro não é especificada. Isso acontece principalmente com a *gzip stream* ou o [`ob_gzhandler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ob-gzhandler.php).

Porém, isso também poderia ser qualquer módulo carregado duas vezes, que deixam uma mensagem de *warning* implícita.

**Mensagens de erro anteriores**

Se algum outro comando PHP causa um *warning* ou *notice* sendo exibida, isso também conta como *output*. Neste casso, você precisa corrigir o erro, atrasar a execução do comando ou suprimir o erro com [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/isset) ou **@** - quando este não obstrui o *debugging* mais tarde.

**Nenhuma mensagem de erro**

Se você tem [*error_reporting*](https://www.php.net/error_reporting) ou [*display_errors*](https://www.php.net/display_errors) desabilitados pelo *php.ini*, então nenhum *warning* será exibido. Mas ignorar erros não resolverão o problema (\o/). Mesmo assim, os *headers* não poderão ser enviados após o *output*.

Então, quando `header("Location: ...")` o redirecionamento falha silenciosamente, é bom examinar os *warnings*. Habilite-os novamente com dois comandos simples (no início do *script*):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Ou se todo o resto falhar:

```
set_error_handler("var_dump");
```

Falando de redirecionamentos, você deveria usar algo parecido com isso para caminhos de código no final.

```
exit(header("Location: /finished.html"));
```

Ou mesmo uma função, que imprima uma mensagem quando uma chamada [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php) falhar.

**Controle de saída como gambiarra** ☠

O [controle de saída](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.outcontrol.php) do PHP é adequado para aliviar este problema. Isso não é tão confiável, mas deveria ser considerado uma gambiarra válida. Seu propósito real é minimizar transferências fragmentadas ao servidor. Reestruturar a aplicação para evitar *output* é preferível.

Todavia configurar [*output_buffering*](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/outcontrol.configuration.php) ajuda. Configure isso no *php.ini* ou via *.htaccess* ou até mesmo *.user.ini*. Com isso habilitado, o conteúdo fica armazenado em um *buffer* e não é instantaneamente passado para o servidor. Então *headers* HTTP podem ser agregados.

Isso pode também ser feito com uma chamada ao [`ob_start()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ob-start.php) no topo do *script*. Isto, entretanto, é menos confiável por algumas razões:

- Mesmo se `<?php ob_start(); ?>` começar o primeiro *script*, espaços em branco ou um problema de BOM podem ser ocasionados antes, tornando está técnica ineficiente.
- Isso pode ocultar espaços em branco para *output* HTML; mas na medida em que a lógica da aplicação tenta enviar conteúdo binário (uma imagem gerada, por exemplo), os espaços irrelevantes armazenados no *buffer* tornam-se um problema. Mesmo que [`ob_clean()`](https://www.php.net/ob_clean) seja uma outra gambiarra válida.
- O *buffer* tem um limite de tamanho. Embora geralmente um problema hipotético, pode no entanto acontecer - o que não seria fácil de descobrir/examinar.

Veja também um [exemplo básico](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/outcontrol.examples.basic.php) de uso no manual.

**Mas isso funcionou em um outro servidor!?**

Se você não teve *warnings* antes, então a configuração do *php.ini* mudou. O controle de saída então estava habilitado no outro servidor, mas não no atual. Veja a seção anterior.

**Verificando com headers_sent()**

Você pode sempre usar [`headers_sent()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.headers-sent.php) para examinar se ainda é possível enviar *headers*. Isso é útil para condicionalmente mostrar uma informação ou aplicar alguma outra lógica.

```
if (headers_sent()) {
    die("O redirecionamento falhou. Por favor, clique neste link: <a href=...>");
}
else{
    exit(header("Location: /user.php"));
}
```

**Gambiarra com a tag HTML**  ☠ ☠ ☠

Se a estrutura da sua aplicação é difícil de corrigir, então uma forma fácil (mas amadora) de criar um redirecionamento é injetando HTML. Um redirecionamento pode ser feito assim:

```
<meta http-equiv="Location" content="http://example.com/">
```

Ou com um simples atraso (o sobrinho aprova!):

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="2; url=../target.html">
```

Isso tornará seu site inválido (mesmo com falso XHTML) quando inserido fora do  . A maioria dos browsers ainda aceitam isso. Como alternativa, um *redirect* em Javascript poderia ser feito:

```
<script> location.replace("target.html"); </script>
```

É uma abordagem aceitável se este é usado como um *fallback* pelas funções de redirecionamento especializadas, o qual deveria primeiro tentar enviar um [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php) propriamente dito, mas usar a *meta tag* e uma mensagem amigável e um link como último recurso.

**Porque setcookie() e session_start() são também afetados**

Tanto o [`setcookie()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php) quanto o [`session_start()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php) precisam enviar um *header* **Set-Cookie**. As mesmas condições portanto se aplicam e mensagens de erros semelhantes serão exibidas.

Problemas de *output* de *headers* não são a única causa para a não-funcionalidade com eles, é claro. Cookies desativados no navegador ou até mesmo problemas de proxy deveriam ser sempre verificados. A funcionalidade da *session* também depende do espaço livre em disco e de outras configurações do *php.ini*.

**Links adicionais**

- Google oferece [uma longa lista](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20headers%20already%20sent) de discussões similares.
- E claro, [muitos outros casos específicos](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20headers%20already%20sent) foram cobertos no Stack Overflow Inglês também.
- O FAQ do The Wordpress explica ["Como solucionar o problema de *headers already sent*?"](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F) de forma mais genérica.
- Adobe Community: Desenvolvimento PHP: [Por que redirecionamentos não funcionam? (*headers already sent*)](https://kb2.adobe.com/community/publishing/505/cpsid_50572.html)
- Nucleus FAQ: ["O que *headers already sent* significa?"](https://web.archive.org/web/20150502180708/https://faq.nucleuscms.org/item/79)
- [HTTP Headers e a função header() - Um tutorial por NicholasSolutions](https://web.archive.org/web/20080430141149/http://www.expertsrt.com/tutorials/Matt/HTTP_headers.html) - disponível somente nos Arquivos da Internet, mas é uma das mais minuciosas respostas. Explica HTTP em detalhe e dá exemplos de reescrita de *scripts*.

Comment: *um colega de fórum*? Quase morri agora :D

Comment: Eu estava quase enlouquecendo pois eu queria um simples redirect para a home através de meu script, não importava o caso. Nada funcionava até que o seu exemplo de javascript `echo '<script> location.replace("/"); </script>';` resolveu!!! Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha ajudado :)

Comment: me ajudou demais cara, muito obrigado!

Comment: Que resposta ótima !

Answer (score 41):

A mensagem `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by` indica que os headers já foram enviados pelo PHP.

Isto é causado ou por algum código anterior, ou por algum caractere literal que aconteceu antes de você abrir o `<?php`.

Notar que isto também pode acontecer quando o PHP envia erros ou *warnings*, então código que dependa de redirect deve sempre suprimir os erros na página e os enviar apenas para um **log**.

Outra parte das possibilidades já foi explorada na resposta do @Gabriel Santos, e para complementar, caso você tenha mesmo que mudar os headers após a geração de conteúdo, recomendo estudar o **[Output Buffer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)** do PHP, que permite você "segurar" o conteúdo da página antes de enviar para o cliente.

> Notar que a solução mais comum é usar o `header()` antes de enviar conteúdo. O Output Buffer é uma técnica mais avançada, e só deve ser usado quando realmente for necessário.

<sub>Observação: Não tem a ver com o problema mencionado, mas se possível use o endereço completo com `http://`.. no redirect, para ter a tranquilidade dele funcionar sempre como esperado. É fácil construir o endereço completo usando variáveis `$_SERVER`.</sub>

Answer (score 35):

Verifique se não há espaços em branco antes de `<?php`. Isso porque cabeçalhos (headers) devem ser definidos antes de enviar texto.

Mais uma coisa, se a codificação do arquivo for UTF-8, salve-o sem o BOM (byte order mark). Por exemplo, no Notepad++ você faria assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 21):

Esse tipo de erro geralmente acontece porque o servidor da sua aplicação já começou a enviar o corpo da resposta à requisição HTTP atual. O cabeçalho, que por definição vem antes do corpo, então não pode mais ser enviado.

Numa aplicação PHP, quando isso costuma acontecer?

- Quando uma mensagem de erro foi emitida antes do output começar (um erro de conexão no banco de dados, um warning do PHP, etc.)
- Quando um script PHP possui a tag de fechamento "?>", fazendo que o que vem depois dessa tag seja enviado como output
- Quando o PHP está desatualizado e solta avisos de funções depreciadas, forçando o output

Tente verificar esses pontos que deve resolver.

Answer (score 16):

A função `header` apenas pode ser utilizada antes do script enviar qualquer tipo de resposta ao cliente, pois o header modifica o cabeçalho da resposta HTTP (e este não pode ser modificado depois que se envia algum conteúdo).

Fique atento a funções como `echo` antes de chamar a função `header` -- ou se houver conteúdo HTML antes da instrução `<?php`, pois são o motivo mais comum para este tipo de erro.

Answer (score 13):

Eu tive esse mesmo problema, provavelmente você está usando o `header()` dentro de uma include, pra resolver isso é só colocar `ob_start()` na `index.php` no começo do código.

Comment: Poderia por favor, explicar melhor o que `ob_start` faz?

Comment: `ob_start` resolve o problema, mas não serve pra essa finalidade. A melhor forma de resolver esse erro é escrevendo o código corretamente. Ex: Evitar espaços antes da tag de abertura, evitar a tag de fechamento caso o código seja unicamente PHP (para não haver espaços posteriores) e utilizar UTF-8 sem BOM.

Comment: Realmente funciona.

Answer (score 11):

Como complemento: O que faz com que muitos programadores sejam surpreendidos com esse erro é que, geralmente, o Xampp (ou até mesmo uma instalação comum entre PHP e Apache) vem com a opção `output_buffering` marcado como `4096`.

A surpresa ocorre porque, no caso dessa opção estar ativa, faz com que haja um efeito similar ao `ob_start` sendo chamado na primeira linha do código. Ele faz com que o buffer de saída seja iniciado assim que o script é inicializado

Aí, quando "subimos" o sistema para produção, geralmente os servidores vem configurado com a opção `output_buffering` como `Off`. Então, o que vai acontecer? Um erro do tipo Warning, que você nunca tinha visto ocorrer em desenvolvimento, vai acontecer no ambiente de produção

Temos então três opção mais simples:

- Podemos alterar o valor de `output_buffering` na configuração do PHP em produção, deixando da mesma forma que o ambiente de desenvolvimento (claro, se você tiver acesso a isso no seu servidor).
- Criarmos o hábito de sempre colocar `ob_start` no início do código sempre.
- Desativar o `output_buffering` em desenvolvimento, já que em produção geralmente vem desativado.

Nos casos acima, a última opção me parece o mais viável. Eu não gosto muito de esconder meus erros debaixo dos panos. Esse erro, como já foi dito, é ocasionado pelo próprio programador, que está tentando definir um `header` depois que a saída já foi enviada para o cliente.

## Limpando o buffer iniciado

Outra forma também que já vi sendo utilizada em frameworks para poder modificar o header depois de já haver conteúdo sendo guardado por `ob_start` é assim:

```
while (ob_get_level() > 0) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

O exemplo acima faz com que tudo o buffer de saída seja "esvaziado", o que tornaria possível, por exemplo, a definição de headers com um status http específicos, no caso de uma aplicação com exceptions ou outros tipos de tratamentos de erros.

Veja esse simples exemplo:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>

<div> Alguma coisa</div>

<?php
   if (! $usuario->find($id)) {
         throw new Exception('Página não encontrada');
   }

?>

<?php
  set_exception_handler(function($exception)
  {
      // Não deixa sair nada para o browser, senão o exception
      while(ob_get_level() > 0) ob_end_clean();
     
      echo $exception;  
  });

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema, consegui resolver fazendo o seguinte:
Adicione este código no começo:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Assim vc vai habilitar que a mensagem de erro apareça na tela quando vc enviar o email. Vai aparecer em qual linha do código está acontecendo o output.
No meu caso, era um comentário que eu tinha adicionado nas primeiras linhas do código.