# Como resolver o erro "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by” no PHP?

Tags: php, header

Porque quando fazemos o uso das funções [`header()`](http://php.net/header) e [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/setcookie) acontece o erro:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (**output started at /teste.php:10**) in **/teste.php** on **line 21**

Porque esse erro acontece? Como resolver?

Comment: Seria melhor se vc mostrasse o código, não? Aliás, o SOPT merece uma versão do [How to fix “Headers already sent” error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php/), esses erros vão pingar dia sim dia não por muuuuito tempo.

Comment: @brasofilo Minha pergunta foi proposital, exatamente para isso. Boa idéia montar esse guide! Se ninguém responder eu respondo :)

Comment: possível [duplicada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/funcao-header-no-php) ?

Comment: @perdeu, pois sim. Pena que o título da outra é tão pouco descritivo...

Comment: nada impede de editarmos o título da outra, ou impede?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na verdade, ele não é um erro. É um aviso(warning).

Isso é feito quando o seu navegador faz uma requisição ao servidor web. Com a resposta do servidor web. Ele te entrega um cabeçalho de resposta(*header*). Esse cabeçalho contém informações sobre a codificação da página, tamanho da página, tempo de duração do cache, hora da ultima atualização e tudo que seja relevante, sobre uma página da internet, para um navegador.

Quando você lê *"headers already sent"* significa que o servidor já enviou o *header* e APÓS esse envio você está tentando alterar alguma informação que deva ser enviada no header.

Mas se você não está manipulando nada que venha no *header*. Você não fez nada e está recebendo este erro.

No PHP o *header* começa a ser enviado logo que você insira o primeiro caracter HTML. Seja fora do PHP ou dentro do código PHP com um echo ou print().

```
<?php
  $numero_1 = 5;
  echo $numero_1;
?>
```

Tudo que está fora do código PHP é HTML, um espaço na linha 1 antes da abertura de código do PHP seria o motivo de uma resposta para o cliente. Qualquer função, sessão, cookie iria causar erro.

Para arrumar este aviso. Você teria que colocar todo o código que trabalhe com session, cookie, redirecionamentos, etc... antes de qualquer caractere pro HTML. Nada de tentar definir/criar um cookie depois de enviar um mensagem de "Olá mundo" para o navegador.

Se você precisa definir/criar um cookie antes de enviar uma mensagem "Olá mundo" ou qualquer coisa, repense o que você está fazendo.

Answer (score 2):

Depende, se você está editando com DreamWeaver ele adiciona aos seus arquivos no momento de salvar uma opção chamada CODIFICAÇÃO BOM (algo do tipo), isto impede que seus scripts em PHP rodem corretamente principalmente em servidores linux, em windows funciona normalmente.
Caso contrário, veja se verificações em php como:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['teste'])){
  header("Location: index.php");
  // é essencial utilizar o exit() após um redireccionamento com header() para evitar possíveis erros
  exit();
}
?>
```

E demais verificações encontram-se no cabeçalho da página, ou seja, as linhas que fazem uma verificação/redirecionamento devem sempre estar acima do código, sempre com as tags no começo da página HTML.
Formulários, textos, etc, jamais podem estar acima do php quando são feitos redirecionamentos. Sempre acima. Poste seu código para nós que fica mais fácil de ajudar.

Comment: Jura que o dreamweaver salva com BOM por padrão? Que coisa...

Comment: Consideramos isto uma irônia, porém, muitos não sabem... Achei interessante ressaltar.

Comment: É bom sim ressaltar. Não esperava que algum programa ainda fizesse isso hoje em dia. Ainda bem que passo bem longe do dreamweaver :)

Comment: Utilizei o DreamWeaver muito tempo, até a versão mais nova (CS6) faz isto infelizmente. Não vejo utilidade nesta codificação mas, deve ter alguma né... Porém passei a utilizar o Netbeans e o Sublime Text, no meu ponto de vista são os melhores, simples e rápidos. Tem também o Eclipse que ouvi muito falar, porém tive pouco contato com ele.