# "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by"

Tags: php

Estou a obter o seguinte *warning* no PHP:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at newclient.php:683)

Aqui está a linha 683:

```
...
682 </div>
683 <?php
684 if(...)
...
```

Já estive a ver no SOen mas não me aparece nada de concreto para este caso.

Já vi [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8961/7210) e [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4251/7210) mas não me esclareceram em nada quanto a este assunto em particular.

[EDIT] O restante código é PHP e HTML "normal" uns `if`, uns `echo`, umas *tags* HTML.

Comment: Tem algum `session_start()` antes da linha 682?

Comment: Sim, pelo que me parece é duplicada. Se a tua questão for mais particular tentar dar mais detalhes...

Comment: Estão ali os detalhes da linha. @CesarMiguel então qual é o problema na linha 683?

Comment: Não há como responder sua pergunta especificamente sem saber o que você faz no php a partir da linha 684. Quando acontece um aviso de “headers already sent”, significa que o servidor já enviou o header, e depois você está tentando criar ou alterar alguma informação que deveria ser enviada via header. Se você melhorar sua pergunta, poderemos tentar ser mais objetivos.

Comment: Não sei, se não deres mais detalhes não é fácil. Com a tua pergunta assim não vais obter mais nenhuma resposta para além das que foram respondidas nas outras duas perguntas

Comment: Se estiver usando DW pode ser um erro relacionado ao momento em que salva o arquivo aonde sem perceber salva com a opção `Incluir assiantura Unicode (BOM)` marcada. Isso insere automaticamente um caractere estranho antes do `<?php` ... e dispara o Warning.

Comment: Antes da linha 682 e depois da linha 684 tenho código PHP e HTML "normal" nada daquelas opções que falam na outra pergunta. O código é muito grande para por aqui.

Comment: PHP puro mesmo @marcosvinicius.

Comment: @JorgeB. Não existe apenas uma possibilidade, e nem isso de HTML e PHP "normal". Se você não pode mostrar o que faz no código, o pessoal só pode tentar adivinhar. Se o código é grande demais, pode passar detalhes em um pastebin ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Problema resolvido, estava a redirecionar a página em *loop* o problema era esse. Obrigado @Blau foi o teu comentário que me ajudou.

Answer (score 1):

Retirado de: [Resolvendo o problema de “headers already sent”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

**Resolvendo o problema de “headers already sent”**

Um erro que muito programador iniciante acaba se deparando aí é o famoso “Warning: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent by…” ou “Warning: Cannot send session cookie – headers already sent by…” e nem sempre é fácil de descobrir o que se fazer para resolver esse erro (que na verdade não é erro, é um warning, um aviso).

Antes de resolver o problema você precisa entender por que esse erro acontece..

**Por que “headers already sent”?**

Toda página na internet está hospedada em servidor e o seu navegador “pede” ao servidor da página, o resultado (HTML) da página com endereço X… Aí o servidor move os seus pauzinhos, interpreta os arquivos e começa a te responder, enviando um cabeçalho de resposta (o famoso header) esse cabeçalho contém informações sobre a codificação da página, tamanho da página, tempo de duração do cache, hora da ultima atualização e tudo que seja relevante, sobre uma página da Internet, para um navegador.

Depois do envio do header o servidor envia o HTML da página toda e o seu browser começa a montar ela pra você.

Quando você lê “headers already sent” no aviso, significa que o seu servidor já enviou o header e APÓS esse envio, você está tentando criar ou alterar alguma informação que deva ser enviada no header.

Por exemplo, os cookies: são definidos antes do envio do header e enviados para o navegador DENTRO do header… Se você tentar criar ou alterar um cookie depois que o header foi enviado você receberá o aviso de erro.

Outro exemplo que segue a mesma lógica dos Cookies é a Sessão, que são como cookies encriptados que ficam salvos no servidor. Toda sessão possui um cookie identificador (session cookie) que é enviado para o visitante a fim de identificá-lo e manter os valores da sua sessão… Se você tentar criar ou remover algum valor da sessão depois do envio do header vai receber a mensagem de erro “Warning: Cannot send session cookie – headers already sent by…“.

**E quando raios eu enviei o header? Eu não fiz nada!**

Realmente, se você não usa nenhuma função de manipulação de headers, você não fez nada e está recebendo esse erro… Mas há uma explicação pra isso!

Em se tratando de PHP (e acredito que o mesmo ocorra com todas as outras linguagens WEB que precisam ser lidas por um parseador), o header começa a ser enviado logo que você insira o primeiro caractere no HTML final da página… Seja fora do código PHP com HTML normal, seja dentro do código PHP com um echo ou print().

```
<?php 
$numero = 3; 
$dobro = $numero * 2; // 6 
?>
```

Imagine que, na linha 1, antes do “” é HTML, então um espaço ali seria como o 1° caractere do HTML causando o envio do header… Qualquer função de sessão/cookie/etc. dentro do bloco de PHP iria causar o erro.

```
<?php 
echo 'Olá mundo'; 
session_start(); // Inicio de sessão depois do envio do header?! Problema! 
?>
```

Esse é outro caso clássico.. O desenvolvedor tentou criar uma sessão (que definirá um cookie de sessão novo) após enviar o header (por causa do echo).

**Tá, e como eu resolvo?**

Lembra que eu disse que você não fez nada e ainda tá recebendo o erro? Pra resolver o problema é a mesma coisa: nada (além do normal) precisa ser feito… Você só precisa colocar todo código que trabalhe com headers (sessões, cookies, redirecionamentos e etc.) antes de enviar qualquer caractere pro HTML… Nada de tentar definir/criar um cookie ou sessão depois de enviar um “Seja bem vindo!” ou enviar o  do seu site.

Cookies e sessões, bem como os redirecionamentos e encriptação de conteúdo devem ser enviados, criados, definidos e modificados ANTES de qualquer HTML… Afinal, todo o HTML pode e deve depender desses fatores.

E antes que você comente dizendo “mas meu site precisa enviar HTML antes de criar um cookie!” eu te respondo “erro de planejamento”. :)

Espero que menos pessoas tenham esse problema a partir de hoje!

Abraços e até a próxima :D