# Warning ao tentar session_start(); PHP

Tags: php, session

Alguém sabe o que pode ser este warning?

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at *caminho*) in *caminho* on line 2

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at *caminho*) in *caminho* on line 2
```

A única coisa que se encontra nesta linha 2 do arquivo é:

```
session_start();
```

Grato desde já!

Como pedido, postando o arquivo *index.php*:

```
<?php

session_start();

require("require/config.php");
require(REQUIRE_PATH . "db.php");
require(CLASS_PATH . "class.login.php");

if(isset($_GET["url"]) && !empty($_GET["url"])){

    $url = $_GET["url"];

    if(in_array($url, $config["secure_pages"])){

        $file = INCLUDE_PATH . $url . ".php";

        if(file_exists($file)){

            include($file);

        } else{

            include(INCLUDE_PATH . "home.php");

        }

    } else{

        include(INCLUDE_PATH . "home.php");

    }

} else{

    include(INCLUDE_PATH . "home.php");

}
}
```

Comment: Suspeito que o ficheiro em questão tenha um UTF-8 BOM no inicio. Experimente guardar o ficheiro como ASCII ou UTF-8 sem BOM.

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-do-php-cannot-modify-header-information. Na verdade é a mesma pergunta, e a resposta lá esclarece o seu problema. Mas a resposta aqui está tão boa que não sei se devo marcar como duplicata.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

O erro "headers already sent" significa que já foi enviada informação para o cliente no momento em que a linha é executada.

O `session_start` deve ser chamado no inicio, antes de qualquer HTML, visto que altera headers do HTTP.

Em particular:

- Não pode ter nenhum texto antes do `<?` com o `session_start`;
- Não pode ter nenhum `echo`, `print` ou qualquer outra coisa que imprima texto;
- Não pode ter nenhuma chamada à função `flush`
- Se incluir algum ficheiro (`require_once`, etc.), então esse ficheiro também não pode imprimir nada;

  - Isso inclui texto a seguir ao `?>` que termina o ficheiro. Nem sequer linhas em branco, nem espaços.
- Os ficheiros PHP em questão não podem ter Byte Order Mark (BOM).

O UTF-8 BOM é um conjunto (opcional) de 3 bytes no inicio do ficheiro que indica que um ficheiro está em UTF-8.

Quando o editor de texto vê o BOM, sabe o que deve fazer: interpretar o resto do ficheiro como UTF-8 e esconder o BOM. Quando o PHP interpreta o ficheiro, não sabe o que é o UTF-8 nem o BOM. Em vez disso, lê o ficheiro como se fosse um ISO-8859. Esses 3 bytes são, portanto, 3 caracteres a enviar para o browser. Tal como texto antes do `<?` é enviado para o navegador, o BOM também é porque o PHP não percebe a diferença.

Quando o navegador recebe o BOM, sabe que o deve ignorar e todos os navegadores (IE, Firefox, Chrome, etc.) fazem isso correctamente. Daí que o BOM não seja visível (nem mesmo no "Ver código fonte desta página"). No entanto, está lá e foi enviado.

Em HTTP, os cabeçalhos (*headers*) têm obrigatoriamente de ser enviados antes do conteúdo da página. Assim, quando o PHP envia texto para o cliente de alguma forma, tem primeiro de enviar os cabeçalhos. A partir do momento em que os cabeçalhos são enviados, não podem ser alterados para essa página sem recarregá-la. Ou seja, quando o PHP envia o BOM para o cliente, envia os cabeçalhos primeiro.

O `session_start` altera os cabeçalhos. No entanto, os cabeçalhos já foram enviados para o cliente ("headers already sent"). Daí que não funcione.

Removendo o BOM, o PHP deixa de enviar os cabeçalhos antes de chegar ao `session_start`, e como tal a função funciona correctamente.

Comment: Pergunta do stackoverflow em inglês relevante: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Muito obrigado luiscubal, de acordo com o que me respondeu e seu comentário, consegui resolver o problema em questão, agora você poderia me esclarecer uma última dúvida? eu mudei a formatação do ficheiro para UTF-8 sem BOM, gostaria de saber porque o BOM causou esse erro, se possível, em uma breve explicação... Agradeço

Comment: @Thomerson Demasiado longo para um comentário, por isso editei a resposta. Espero que ajude.

Comment: Eu tenho que mudar o meu '<meta charset '? Não entendi muito bem. Meu código está igual ao da pergunta, porém não consegui resolver

Comment: Olha estava com um problema bem parecido, no meu caso, por increça que parível, bastou colocar a abertura do php "<?php" na primeira linha do arquivo!