# Erro ao logar no painel administrativo - Session_start

Tags: php

Ola, Pessoal estou com um erro de Session start em que o cara mesmo não logado está conseguindo acessar o painel

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/emanoelgomes/public_html/eba/paineldecontrole/includes/header.php:1) in /home/emanoelgomes/public_html/eba/paineldecontrole/includes/header.php on line 1
```

index.php

```
session_start(); 

@$Usuario = $_SESSION["Usuario"];
@$Senha   = $_SESSION["Senha"];

if (isset($Usuario) && isset($Senha)){

    header("Location: inicial.php");    
}
```

acaologin.php

```
require_once    '../includes/configuration.php';

$userName = $_POST["user-name"];
$userPass = $_POST["user-pass"];
$criptSen = hash("whirlpool", $userPass);
@$rediURL = $_GET["url"];

$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT Usuario, Senha FROM administradores WHERE Usuario='$userName' AND Senha='$criptSen' ");

if(mysql_num_rows($SQL) != 0){

    session_start();

    $_SESSION['Usuario'] = $userName;
    $_SESSION['Senha']   = $criptSen;

    if(isset($rediURL)){

      header("Location: ../$rediURL");

    } else {

         header("Location: ../inicial.php");

    }

} else {

    header("Location: ../index.php");

}
```

No caso quando o usuario loga na index.php ele vai ser redirecionado para loginacao.php, se estiver tudo certo ele vai para a inicial.php, porém, ele mesmo sem login se eu acessar direto o inicial.php ele ja entra , o que pode ser ?

Comment: Possível quadriplicada de... http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8961/como-resolver-o-erro-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28359/warning-ao-tentar-session-start-php, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27864/warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by/27875

Comment: Por favor pesquise pelo erro antes de abrir uma pergunta.

Comment: eu ja pesquisei por isso tal pergunta.

Comment: mostra essa linha 1 da sua header.php   A mensagem de erro indica que já foram enviados os headers