# Como incluir arquivos php contendo "session_start()", "echo", etc., em um outro arquivo php, sem que ocorra o erro "headers already sent"?

Tags: php

Eu já investiguei aqui no Stack sobre tal erro, mas não encontrei uma forma de resolver o meu problema específico.

Tenho um arquivo salvo como PHP que funciona como um "index", basicamente cheio de HTML. Lá pela metade da estrutura do arquivo, no `body`, quero inserir um contador de visitas no site e um display de usuários online. Fiz um arquivo PHP para cada uma dessas duas coisas e incluí (com "include") dentro deste "index". Contudo, ocorreu o seguinte erro:

```
"Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\wamp64\www\administrador\indexadmin.php:192) in C:\wamp64\www\administrador\usuariosonline.php on line 3
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0007  244648  {main}( )   ...\indexadmin.php:0
2   0.0050  265496  include( 'C:\wamp64\www\administrador\usuariosonline.php' ) ...\indexadmin.php:206
3   0.0050  265544  session_start ( )   ...\usuariosonline.php:3"
```

Como resolver?

Eis os códigos:

o "index.php" é este (no body):

```
<div class="col col-3">
<div class="visitassite">

    <h4>Visitas ao Site</h4>        

    <p>

    <?php include "totalvisitas.php"; ?>

    </p>
</div>
</div>


<div class="col col-3">
<div class="usuariosonline">

    <h4>Usuários Online</h4>        

    <p>

    <?php include "usuariosonline.php"; ?>

    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Os dois arquivos php que estão sendo incluídos são estes:

> Arquivo **totalvisitas.php**:

```
<?php
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=contador', 'root', '');
}catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$selecionar = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM visitas");
$selecionar->execute();
$resultados = $selecionar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($resultados as $results):
    echo "Total de visitas ao site: ".$results['visitas'];
    $contar = $results['visitas'] + 1;
    $update = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE visitas SET visitas=:visitas");
    $update->bindValue(':visitas', $contar);
    $update->execute();
endforeach;
?>
```

O outro é este (usuariosonline.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
$session_path = session_save_path();
$visitors=0;
$handle = opendir($session_path);
while (($file = readdir ($handle)) != FALSE)
{
    if ($file!="."&&$file!="..")
    {
        if (preg_match("/^sess/",$file))
        $visitors++;
    }
}
echo "Há $visitors visitantes online.";
?>
```

Comment: Você pesquisou ? [Erro ao logar no painel administrativo - Session_start](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191412).

Comment: A. Goes publiquei no meu servidor os 3 arquivos, fiz teste, e aqui comigo não deu erro não. O estranho é o numero de visitantes online. Veja http://kithomepage.com/sos/session_start.php

Comment: Oi wmsouza! Pesquisei sobre o problema... mas o que busco (e talvez tenha sido feliz no título mas infeliz na descrição do post) é a forma de consertar no meu caso específico... talvez algo como o André respondeu... A solução bem explicada não foi por mim encontrada no fórum (talvez não tenha esgotado a pesquisa, mas futuquei bastante...). Talvez tal solução, já que é um problema tão comum, se bem detalhada, possa ser de muita utilidade para muitos de pouca experiência como eu...

Leo, obrigado pelo teste! Por eliminação, já adiantou bastante! Obrigado a todos pela velocidade nas respostas!

Comment: Relacionada: [Erro - “Cannot modify header information - headers already sent”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4251/74)

Answer (score 0):

Cara, eu mudaria a forma de fazer isso.

1. traria os includes para o topo do arquivo
2. dentro dos includes, no lugar do echo jogaria os resultados para variáveis
3. finalmente onde estavam os includes, daria um echo nas variáveis criadas pelos includes.

Comment: André, em cheio! Eu fui infeliz na descrição do problema. Acho que compreendo qual é o problema: chamando o php no meio do body (ainda mais depois de outro php com "echo"), eu estou querendo reenviar informações depois do envio do "header", o que causa o aviso. A questão é de que forma eu faria a disposição do php (desconfiei que deveria ser no início) de modo que eu pudesse "chamá-lo" no devido lugar do body sem ser por meio do include, mas apenas mostrando a mensagem de que preciso. Seria possível explicar ou indicar leitura sobre sua solução com as variáveis? Não sei como faço isso!

Comment: Cara, primeiro você terá que arrumar o totalvisitas.php

Comment: 1. sua consulta do totalvisitas.php me parece errada, vc deveria retornar algo como um **select count(*) as visitas from visitas** para poder usar o visitas... ou então esse campo deve existir na tabela visitas;
2. vc está fazendo um loop no resultado e vai imprimir várias vezes o texto: "Total de visitas ao site"
3. esse arquivo deveria retornar somente o resultado da query

Algo como:
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=contador', 'root', '')
$row = $pdo->query( "select count(*) as visitas from visitas" )->fetch();
$visitas = $row["visitas"];
$pdo = null;

Comment: Já o usuariosonline.php

seria só alterar o `echo "Há $visitors visitantes online.";` por `$visitanteonline =  "Há $visitors visitantes online."`

Comment: Por último subiria os includes para o topo e daria um echo nessas variáveis `$visitas` e `$visitanteonline` onde hoje aparecem os includes no index.

Comment: André, muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento e prontidão na ajuda! Deu certíssimo! Fiz tudo o que disse e aproveitei também a dica do Juven.

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver o erro relacionado a sessão pode ser utilizado uma outra abordagem. Basicamente você cria um novo arquivo, por exemplo **sessao.php** e coloca o seguinte conteudo:

```
//chama o session_start apenas se não tiver sido chamado anteriormente
function iniciar_sessao(){
    if(!(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)){
        session_start();
    }
}
```

Com isso você pode remover todas as chamadas a session_start nos outros arquivos, e passar a incluit no topo de cada arquivo (na primeira linha)

```
require_once 'sessao.php';
iniciar_sessao();
```

Não haveá problema se você chama-la mais de uma vez, pois a função `iniciar_sessao()` já faz o tratamento adequado.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, Juven_v! Utilizei aqui! Fica realmente melhor!