# Erro ao criar COOKIE... Cannot modify header information

Tags: php

Acabei de pegar um projeto com um amigo e me deparei com o seguinte erro de Cookie:

```
Warning: Cannot Modify header information - headers already send by (output started at...)
```

Vou colocar o trecho do código:

```
<?php
ini_set('output_buffering','On');
ob_start();
require 'admin/util/Conexao.class.php';
require 'admin/util/protecao.php';

if(!empty($_REQUEST['login']) && !empty($_REQUEST['senha'])){
    $login = $_REQUEST['login'];
    $senha = $_REQUEST['senha'];

    $busca = new Conexao("SELECT * FROM convites WHERE login = '$login' AND senha = '$senha'");
    $rs = $busca->query();
    $total = mysql_num_rows($rs);

    if($total != 1){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Login incorreto")</script>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "login.php"</script>';   
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    $busca->desconectar();

    setcookie('id_convite',$row['id_convite'],time()+3600);
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.open("formulario.php", "_parent");    </script>';

}elseif(!empty($_REQUEST['cpf']) && !empty($_REQUEST['email'])){
    $cpf = anti_injection($_REQUEST['cpf']);
    $email = anti_injection($_REQUEST['email']);

    $busca = new Conexao("SELECT * FROM convites_alunos WHERE cpf = '$cpf' AND email = '$email' AND confirmado = 'N'");
    $rs = $busca->query();
    $total = mysql_num_rows($rs);
    if($total != 1){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Login incorreto")</script>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "login.php"</script>';   
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    $busca->desconectar();

    setcookie('id_aluno',$row['id_aluno'],time()+3600);
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.open("formulario_aluno.php", "_parent");</script>';

}else{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Login incorreto")</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "login.php"</script>';
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

E o erro ocorre na linha onde é criado o cookie:

```
setcookie('id_convite',$row['id_convite'],time()+3600);
```

Poderiam me ajudar??? Conforme podem ver já iniciei o buffer e encerrei, conforme vi na net, mas nada... Usei o comando:

```
ini_set('output_buffering','On');
```

Porém, o erro persiste, estou apenas na dependência disso pra entregar o projeto.
Obrigado.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-do-php-cannot-modify-header-information

Comment: A resposta está na pergunta linkada acima. Você não pode dar nenhuma saída (por exemplo, `echo`) antes de setar o cookie.