# Redirecionamento em PHP

Tags: php, html

Seguinte, criei uma página para editar um conteúdo e gostaria que, ao clicar no botão de atualizar, ele voltasse para a página anterior.
Estou usando o seguinte comando:

```
header("Location: visualizarNovaPrevisao.php");
```

Porém, um aviso aparece:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\VertrigoServ\www\marco\php\editaNovaPrevisao.php:276) in

Já li sobre esse aviso, mas não entendo o que falam sobre *output* na linha 276. Alguém sabe como posso usar o redirecionamento?

Comment: Isso é típico de quando fica algum espaço depois do fechamento da _tag_ `?>`

Comment: Como assim? Quando fica um espaço depois do fechamento da tag do php? Mas não tem como ter espaço! A não ser que vc quer dizer, espaço da seguinte form ?    >, isso?

Comment: Da uma olhada no item 3 da resposta do Otto. Era isso que eu estava querendo dizer. É até aconselhável nem colocar a _tag_ de fechamento do PHP, justamente para evitar esse problema.

Comment: De uma olhada no wiki da tag php la tem duas respostas sobre esse erro.

Comment: No wikipedia, @perdeu?

Comment: Não, quando você clica na tag linguagem ela abre as perguntas e uma aba chamada `info` lá geramente tem varias informações como lista de recursos, problemas comuns etc. [link da tag](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) O conteudo sobre o erro está no final da pagina.

Comment: Desculpe @perdeu, não entendi ainda.

Comment: @GustavoSevero qual parte você não entendeu?

Comment: Gustavo, cada tag aqui no site tem uma wiki: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Answer (score 0):

1) Encontrar o header () , a declaração de que está causando o problema. O erro deve ser igual ao citado acima.

2) Procure por todas as declarações que poderiam enviar a saída para o usuário antes desta declaração de cabeçalho. Se você encontrar um ou mais, encontrar alguma maneira de mover a declaração do cabeçalho antes deles. Complexas declarações condicionais podem complicar o problema, mas elas também podem ajudar a resolver o problema. Considere uma expressão condicional no início do script PHP que determina o valor de cabeçalho tão cedo quanto possível, e fixa-lo lá.

3) Certifique-se que não há espaço em branco fora do início e fim das tags php. Enquanto uma linha em branco antes do

4) Um detalhe importante, os editores com suporte a UTF-8 como o DWCS4 e Eclipse salvam o arquivo .php com Assinatura Unicode (BOM), basta desmarcar esta opção, salvar e problema resolvido.

Comment: Eu tenho isso no início do meu php:
include"conexao.php";
session_start();

$id =  $_SESSION['id'];
$usuario =  $_SESSION['usuario'];

  $cc = $_GET['cc'];
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $nAnalise = $_GET['na'];

  $qryBusca = "SELECT * FROM [RDO].[dbo].[ANALISE_CRITICA] WHERE NMANALISE='$nAnalise' AND ID='$id' ";
  $stmtQry = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $qryBusca );

?>
Depois disso é um html para mostrar o conteúdo que vou editar.

Comment: viu todos os 4 passos ?

Comment: O 4º eu não entendi direito. Colocar como meta tag no html?

Comment: nao podemos tentar melhorar a leitura .... alguns editores podem salvar o arquivo com codificacao utf-8 com bom sendo necessario salvar com o encoding utf-8 somente entendeu

Answer (score 0):

Você esqueceu do href -

```
function voltar () { 

    window.location.href="http://www.google.com.br   ou  seu caminho da pagina" ;
}
```

e no botão

```
<input type="button" onclick="voltar()">
```

Comment: Bom, consegui de uma forma antiga que aprendi quando aprendi php. Quando clico em atualizar, mando para outro php fazer a atualização e no final coloquei o header para onde eu queria e pronto!

Comment: Essa resposta era mesmo pra essa pergunta?!

Comment: @bfavaretto realmente essa resposta não tem nada a ver com redirecionamento php kkk tem cada louco

Answer (score 0):

O erro está acontecendo porque não é possível enviar o header após o conteúdo do arquivo.

Em algum lugar antes do `header()` existe ou uma tag html, um `echo` ou até mesmo um espaço em branco fora do `<?php ?>`.

Ele mostra o erro no arquivo `editaNovaPrevisao.php`na linha 276, pois é lá que foi escrito um conteúdo para o arquivo.

Se não for possível remover ou modificar o lugar da saída de dados você terá de fazer o redirecionamento via JavaScript.

Nesta outra pergunta você encontra um explicação mais detalhada do que pode causar esse erro:

[Erro - "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-do-php-cannot-modify-header-information)

Answer (score -1):

Se você tiver usando Dreamweaver, ele deve tá salvando alguns caracteres a mais no início do seu código. Faça o seguinte: Abra seu arquivo php e vá em Salvar como e desmarque a opção: Incluir Assinatura Unicode (BOM). Caso ainda persista, abra o script no Notepad++ e remova os caracteres existentes no início do código.