# Como pagar dados do navegador após cadastrar no banco de dados

Tags: php

Pessoal tenho uma página para cadastro de usuário e insert em uma única página, preciso apagar os dados após clicar em cadastrar e inserir no banco, pois se atualizo a página o registro se duplica no banco, alguma idéia?

```
      <?php
    if (isset($_GET['cadastra']) && $_GET['cadastra'] == 'add') {
        $cadastra = mysql_query("INSERT INTO cliente (ordemservico, nome, data,fone, produto, status, descricao) VALUES ('$ordemservico', '$_GET[nome]', '$_GET[data]', '$_GET[fone]', '$_GET[produto]', '$_GET[status]', '$_GET[descricao]')");
    if($cadastra == '1') {
        echo "Cadastrado com sucesso ! OS Número: $ordemservico <br /> <a href=\"admin.php\">Atualizar<a/>";
    }else{
        echo "Erro ao cadastrar !";
}
}
?>
```

Formulário

```
      <form id="form1" name"form1" method"post" action"" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div align="center">
     <table border="0" align="center">
         <tr>
           <td colspan="2" align="center"></td>
         </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>Nome:</td>
           <td><span id="sprytextfield1">
             <label>
               <input name="nome" type="text" id="nome" size="43" />
             </label>
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1" color="#FF0000" >Informe seu nome</font></span></span></td>
         </tr>
           <td>Fone:</td>
           <td><label>
             <input name="fone" type="text" id="fone" size="43" />
             <br />
           </label></td>
          </tr>
           <td>Produto:</td>
           <td><span id="sprytextfield2">
             <label>
               <input name="produto" type="text" id="produto" size="43" />
             </label>
             <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1" color="#FF0000" >Informe o produto</font></span></span></td>
          </tr>
           <td>Status:</td>
           <td><label>
             <label for="status"></label>
                <select name="status" id="status" >
                <option value="-1" selected="selected">Selecione</option>
                  <option>Aguardando</option>
                  <option>Em Atendimento</option>
                  <option>Finalizado</option>

             </select>
             <br />
           </label></td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Descrição:</td>
           <td><label>
             <textarea name="descricao" cols="46" rows="5" id="descricao"> </textarea>
           </label></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><label for="data"></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="data" id="data" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d')?>" /></td>
           <td align="right"><label>
             <input type="hidden" name="cadastra" value="add" />
             <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="  Cadastrar  " />
            </label></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
   </form>
```

Comment: Faça um _http redirect_ logo após o cadastramento no DB em vez de mostrar conteúdo. Pode redirecionar para a mesma página, que também funciona.

Comment: @Bacco no meu código agora estou fazendo um refresh de 2 segundos "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='2;URL=clientes.php'>" mas não me parece uma boa idéia, sabes me dizer como posso fazer este redirect?

Comment: Você pode apagar os dados do form após o insert, e quando for atualizado com F5, será exibida a sua mensagem informando para preencher os campos.

Comment: @Bacco o código esta assim como você descreveu mas ao cadastrar recebo o erro: "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\pasta\admin\cadastro_clientes.php:196) in C:\xampp\htdocs\pasta\admin\cadastro_clientes.php on line 220"

Comment: @RafaelAssmann essa parte é fácil, e é sinal que está no caminho certo. Agora é só tirar todas as coisas que emitam informação na tela do PHP antes de dar o redirect. Veja mais aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/

Comment: Entendido, consegui aqui! Muito obrigado pelo apoio, 10! @Bacco

Answer (score 2):

Uma possível solução sem grandes alterações no código é esta:

```
if($cadastra == '1') {
   // Montamos o caminho para o mesmo script:
   $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
   // Deixamos a mensagem para depois do redirect:
   $mensagem = urlencode( 'Cadastro feito com sucesso' );
   // Redirecionamos repassando a mensagem adiante:
   header( "Location: $url?mensagem=$mensagem" );
   // E encerramos o script neste ponto:
   die();
}else{
   echo "Erro ao cadastrar !";
}
```

Depois, basta acrescentar algo deste tipo para mostrar a mensagem só depois do redirect:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['mensagem'] ) ) {
   echo htmlentities( $mensagem );
}
```

(essa segunda parte é fora do `if` que insere os dados, pois será executada em separado)