# Erro de output no FPDF - PHP

Tags: php, fpdf

Tenho um relatório que gero utilizando a classe FPDF.
Enquanto estava desenvolvendo ele na minha máquina local estava tudo uma maravilha, agora que fiz a hospedagem dos arquivos na kinghost, comecei a ter problemas com ele.

O erro apresentado pela página é:

> FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file
>   (output started at /home/brancosistemas/www/teste/inicio.php:12)

Já revisei tudo, segui diversas dicas e sugestões que encontrei por ai (estou desde ontem tentando resolver o problema), e nenhuma delas funcionou.
Ele acusa que o output foi iniciado na minha página inicial...

Será que alguém consegue me ajudar nessa?

Código do PDF:

```
<?php
    include "fpdf/fpdf.php";

    session_start();

    // Turn off all error reporting
    error_reporting(0);

    //selecionando exame da empresa.
    $sql = "SELECT RQ_EXAME FROM db043 
            WHERE RQ_IMPR = 'P' 
            AND RQ_EMPR = ".$_SESSION['cliente']['C_CODI']." ";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    $registro = $row['RQ_EXAME'];

    //selecionado cabeçalho do exame
    $sql = "SELECT R.RQ_EXAME, R.RQ_VALOR, R.RQ_DATA, R.RQ_DEPE, E.C_FANT EMPR, 
            L.C_FANT LABO, concat_ws(', ', L.C_ENDE,  L.C_NUME) C_ENDE, L.C_TIPO, F.F_NOME, F.F_FONE
            FROM db043 R 
            JOIN db02  E ON (R.RQ_EMPR=E.C_CODI)
            JOIN db02  L ON (R.RQ_LABO=L.C_CODI)
            JOIN db021 F ON (R.RQ_EMPR=F.F_EMPR) AND (R.RQ_FUNC=F.F_CODI)
            WHERE R.RQ_EXAME = $registro";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    $cabec = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

    $emissao = date_create($cabec["RQ_DATA"]);
    $emissao = date_format($emissao, 'd/m/Y');


    $sql = "SELECT R.RQ_TIPO, E.NOME
            FROM db0431 R 
            JOIN db26   E ON (R.RQ_TIPO=E.CODIGO)
            WHERE R.RQ_EXAME = $registro";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    $nome_exame = '';

    while($exames = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        if ($nome_exame == ''){
            $nome_exame = $exames["NOME"];
        } else {
            $nome_exame = $nome_exame.", ".$exames["NOME"];
        }   
    }   

    $nome_exame = utf8_decode(" > > > > > [ ".$nome_exame." ] < < < < < ");


    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage('P','A4');

    /******************** DADOS DA PRIMEIRA VIA ********************/
    for ($i=0;$i < 2;$i++) { 

    //com essa $pos eu defino a posição de impressão das duas vias no laço.
    $pos = 0;
    if($i == 1){
        $pos = 152;
    }

    $pdf->Line(10,  10+$pos,  10,  135+$pos);//linha esquerda 
    $pdf->Line(200, 10+$pos,  200, 135+$pos);//linha direita  
    $pdf->Line(10,  10+$pos,  200, 10+$pos); //linha superior


    /*** dados do primeiro bloco ****/
    $pdf->Image('http://www.biovel.com.br/img/convenios/convenio-sindconvenio.jpg', 12, 12+$pos, 0, 18, 'JPG');

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',20);
    $pdf->Text(53,19+$pos, 'SINDCONVENIOS');

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $pdf->Text(49,25+$pos, utf8_decode('Medicina e Segurança do Trabalho'));

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
    $pdf->Text(145,20+$pos, 'Fone(45) 3223-4662');

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $pdf->Text(130,15+$pos, utf8_decode('CEP: 85.812-001 - CASCAVEL - PARANÁ'));
    $pdf->Text(124,25+$pos, utf8_decode('Av. Brasil, 5964 - 1º Andar - Salas - 12, 13 e 14'));

    $pdf->Line(10,  30+$pos,   200, 30+$pos);//linha que encerra o primeiro bloco 


    /*** dados do segundo bloco ****/
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $pdf->Text(15,35+$pos, utf8_decode('REQUISIÇÃO'));
    $pdf->Text(120,35+$pos, $emissao);

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $pdf->Text(44,34.5+$pos, utf8_decode('-  Exame  -  Saúde Ocupacional'));
    $pdf->Text(110,34.5+$pos, utf8_decode('Data:'));

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
    $pdf->Text(189,34.5+$pos, str_pad($registro, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));

    $pdf->Line(10,  37+$pos,   200, 37+$pos);//linha que encerra o segundo bloco 


    /*** dados do terceiro bloco ****/
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
    $pdf->Text(19.6,42+$pos, utf8_decode('Empresa:'));
    $pdf->Text(21.3,48+$pos, utf8_decode('Usuário:'));
    $pdf->Text(15,54+$pos,   utf8_decode('Dependente:'));

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
    $pdf->Text(35,42+$pos, utf8_decode($cabec["EMPR"]));
    $pdf->Text(35,48+$pos, utf8_decode($cabec["F_NOME"]));
    $pdf->Text(35,54+$pos,   utf8_decode($cabec["RQ_DEPE"]));

    $pdf->Text(170,42+$pos, utf8_decode($cabec["F_FONE"]));

    $pdf->Line(10,  57+$pos,   200, 57+$pos);//linha que encerra o terceiro bloco 

    /*** dados do quarto bloco ****/
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
    $pdf->Text(65,61.2+$pos, '(   ) Consulta');
    $pdf->Text(110,61.2+$pos, '(   ) Exame');

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
    $pdf->Text(170,61.2+$pos, 'OCUPACIONAL');

    if($cabec["C_TIPO"] == 'C') {
        $pdf->Text(66.3,61.2+$pos, 'X');
    } else {
        $pdf->Text(111.3,61.2+$pos, 'X');
    }

    $pdf->Line(10,  64+$pos,   200, 64+$pos);//linha que encerra o quarto bloco 


    /*** dados do quinto bloco ****/
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
    $pdf->Text(12,68+$pos, utf8_decode('Clínica/Laboratório:'));
    $pdf->Text(27,77+$pos, utf8_decode('Exames:'));

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
    $pdf->Text(40,68+$pos, utf8_decode($cabec["LABO"]));
    $pdf->Text(40,72+$pos, utf8_decode($cabec["C_ENDE"]));

    $pdf->SetXY(40,75);
    $pdf->MultiCell(150,4,$nome_exame, 0, 'J', false);

    $pdf->Line(10,  101+$pos,   200, 101+$pos);//linha que encerra o quinto bloco 


    /*** dados do sexto bloco ****/
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
    $pdf->Text(20,115+$pos, '- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -');
    $pdf->Text(35,118+$pos, utf8_decode('Carimbo e Assinatura da Empresa'));

    $pdf->Text(113,115+$pos, '- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -');
    $pdf->Text(135,118+$pos, utf8_decode('Assinatura do Usuário'));

    $pdf->Line(10,  121+$pos,  200, 121+$pos);//linha que encerra o sexto bloco


    /*** dados do sétimo bloco ****/
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
    $pdf->Text(55,125.5+$pos, utf8_decode('Os valores dos exames só terão validade quando fornecidos pela SINDCONVÊNIOS'));

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
    $total = $cabec["RQ_VALOR"] * 100;
    $total = str_pad($total, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $pdf->Text(13,125.5+$pos, "A0".$total."B");

    $pdf->Line(10,  128+$pos,  200, 128+$pos);//linha que encerra o sexto bloco


    /*** dados do sétimo bloco ****/
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',9);
    $pdf->Text(15,133+$pos, utf8_decode('obs: A Guia não pode ser rasurada e nem utilizada para outra finalidade, podendo comprometer o pagamento da mesma.'));
    $pdf->Line(10,  135+$pos, 200, 135+$pos);//linha inferior 
    }

    $pdf->Text(10,150, '- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -');  

    if($registro > 0){

        ob_end_clean(); 

        if(!ob_get_contents()){
            $pdf->Output("Requisição_".$registro.".PDF", 'D');
        } else {
            echo ob_get_contents();
        }
    } 
// segundo o manual do php... fechar essa tag é desnecessário nesse caso, mas já tentei de ambas as formas... "? >"


<?
    session_start();
    include "admin/inc/conexao.php";
    $raiz = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/teste";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <base href="<?=$raiz?>"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <link href="../css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="../js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/funcoes.js"></script>
        <title>SINDConvênios</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="geral">
            <div class="topo">
                <a href="principal" title="Clique aqui para retornar a Pagina inicial!"><div class="logo">SINDConvênios</div></a>

                <?
                    if(isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
                ?>
                        </br>
                        <fieldset class="user_ident">
                            <legend>Usuario</legend>
                            <label><?=$_SESSION['cliente']['C_NOME']?></label></br>
                            <a class="linkusr" href="javascript:logoff()">Sair!</a>
                        </fieldset>
                <?
                    }
                ?>

                <br clear="all"/>
            </div>

            <br clear="all"/>
        </div>

        <div class="conteudo">
            <?
                if(isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
                    $permitidos = array('co_requisicao', 'empresas', 'funcionarios', 'imprimir', 'login', 'nv_requisicao', 'principal');

                    if((isset($_GET['p'])) and (array_search($_GET['p'], $permitidos) !== false))
                        include "inc/".$_GET['p'].".php";
                    else
                        include "inc/principal.php";
                } else {
                    include "inc/login.php";
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Olhou essa [questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-do-php-cannot-modify-header-information)

Comment: Qual é a linha 12 em `inicio.php`?

Comment: Jorge, a linha 12 tem isso:
<base href="<?=$raiz?>"/>

Já tentei fazer um teste removendo ela, e ele apontou o erro para a primeira linha em que eu abria a tag "<?".

Comment: Acabei de adicionar o código do "inicio.php" junto ao tópico.

Comment: Verificou o encode do arquivo?

Comment: Verifiquei... todos os arquivos estão em UTF-8 sem BOM.

Comment: Verificou se a kinghost tem suporte a short tags no php?

Comment: Sim Rodrigo, eles possuem suporte a short tags.

Comment: Coloca essas duas linha no inicio do arquivo que está com problema e veja se aparece mais algum warning. `ini_set('display_errors', true);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` Qual a versão do php dos dois hosts?

Comment: @perdeu

5.3 em ambos.

Quando adicionei essas linhas no imprimir.php ele continuou com a mesma mensagem...

Agora quando inclui elas no inicio.php a mensagem foi:
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /home/brancosistemas/www/teste/inc/imprimir.php on line 4.

Comentei a linha session_start no imprimir.php, e o erro voltou a ser o mesmo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A configuração "Output_Buffering" estava desativada no servidor (kinghost).

Este era o causador do erro. Percebi isso assim que li essas informações do manual:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/outcontrol.configuration.php

Obrigado a todos que participaram com seus comentários!