# Problema com header

Tags: php, header, warnings

Tinha esse código a rodar no localhost do meu PC mas quando coloquei no servidor ele já não roda. Quando chamo a função `verificaLoginAdmin()` ele retorna sempre:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/xxxxx/public_html/admin.php:1) in
>   /home/xxxxxx/public_html/cmd/funcoes.php on line 42

Eu tive esse mesmo problema no localhost do meu PC mas para resolver foi simples, coloquei a função `ob_start();` no princípio dá página de funções e o `ob_clean()` no fim, e já estava resolvido, mas agora no servidor não está a dar o mesmo resultado.

```
function redireciona($url=''){  
    header("Location: ".BASEURL.$url);
}

function verificaLoginAdmin(){
     $sessao = new sessao();
     if($sessao->getNvars()<=0 || $sessao->getVar('nivel_ur')!='admin' || $sessao->getVar('ip_ur')!=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){
         redireciona('index.php');
     }
}
```

Comment: Veja se isso http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-do-php-cannot-modify-header-information pode te ajudar

Comment: cara valeu mesmo! eu tinha um espaço antes de abrir o PHP, obrigado mesmo.