# Qual a função do '@' (arroba) no inicio de expressões em PHP

Tags: php

Qual a função do `@` no inicio de expressões em PHP?

Tenho visto em algumas classes e não consegui obter a função de se colocar este `@` no inicio.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`@` [operador de controle de erro](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) no início de chamada de função ou variável é ocultar a mensagem de erro. Não é indicado fazer isso pois mascara o `erro/warning` e deixa sua detecção mais sutil.

Em alguns casos raros seu uso obrigatório, pois algumas funções do php ainda lançam a mensagem de erro de forma descuidado ou seja uma saída de texto não esperada que pode gerar um [Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4251/91)

Um exemplo é a função [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) e [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), o manual diz que seu retorno é boolean, porém além do `false` um `warning` é gerado.

Um exemplo do uso indevido da arroba (`@`) é ocultar um  `warning`, o comum undefined index ...

```
$id = @$_GET['id'];
```

Faça:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';

 ou

$id = ''; 
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
   $id = $_GET['id];
}
```

**Relacionado:**

[Por que dizem que utilizar @ arroba pra suprimir erros é uma má prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84178/91)

**Referências:**

[Why Suppressing Notices is Wrong](http://www.sitepoint.com/why-suppressing-notices-is-wrong/)

[Suppress error with @ operator in PHP - SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/136912/1342547)

Comment: vi este @ em classes grandes e muito utilizadas de frameworks e bibliotecas

Comment: Qual framework?

Comment: @rray aposto todas minhas fichas no CodeIgniter xD

Comment: @gmsantos, pensei a mesma coisa e como tem arroba. Tinha um framework que era baseado no CI se não me engano era o kohana, se baseou no CI tem coisa errada ai haha

Comment: PHPCrawl, um framework pra desenvolvimento baseado em componentes PHP que não me lembro o nome