# Porque usar @ em uma variável?

Tags: php

Estava analisando alguns códigos `PHP` que não programei e encontrei um `@` (arroba) antes de uma variável. Qual a utilidade dele no código?

```
if( @$f_outro_valor ){ $where[] = " `f_valor` = '{$f_outro_valor}'"; }
```

Comment: [Qual a função do '@' no inicio de expressões em PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50166/91)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usar `@` na frente de expressões é usado para suprimir a exposição de erros na tela (mas não elimina a ocorrência de erros).

> Com esta solução não será exibido mais `notices` como o `Unexpected Index` ela basicamente tem a mesma função do `@` no inicio das expressões suprimindo a necessidade de uso do mesmo, Esta solução **NÃO** é indicada em 99% dos casos então nunca suprima erros a menos que seja extremamente necessário.

Para configurar o php.ini para não exibir as mensagens de notificação você deve deixar da seguinte forma:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Outra forma é colar esta linha no arquivo inicio do arquivo `.php`:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "0");
```

Outra forma é colar esta linha no arquivo inicio do arquivo `.php`:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); // ira reportar todos esceto os `notices`.
```