# Como colocar o db_connect com o my_sqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Meu código:

```
<?php


class DB_CONNECT {

// constructor
function __construct() {
    // connecting to database
    $this->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {
    // closing db connection
    $this->close();
}

/**
 * Function to connect with database
 */
function connect() {
    // import database connection variables
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

    // Connecting to mysql database
    $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysqli_error());

    // Selecing database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

    // returing connection cursor
    return $con;
}
/**
 * Function to close db connection
 */
function close() {
    // closing db connection
    mysql_close();
}

}

?>
```

Para resolver superficialmente vi que se colocar um @ em frente o my_sql_connect funcionaria.

```
 // Connecting to mysql database
    $con = @mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Mas vejo que logo logo se tornará obsoleta, como ficaria o código com o my_sqli?

Comment: Se não existe uma resposta canônica sobre isto, deveria existir. Certamente existem várias perguntas que já responderam isto.

Comment: MIgrar de mysql para mysqi?

Comment: [Como converter uma ligação de MYSQL para MYSQLI?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32820/91) e [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)

Comment: Certamente já vim procurando bastante sobre isso, e infelizmente não achei algo que desse certo pra mim. Li que praticamente era só mudar oque estava escrito com my_sql para my_sqli, porém da erro nos parametros.

Comment: A sintaxe muda, para todas as funções mysqli_*(modo procedural) o primeiro argumento é sempre a conexão.

Comment: O mais legal desta pergunta é que colocando um @ resolve o problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50166/101

Comment: Teria algum problema deixar o @ ? Já que com ele funciona,  mas daria algum problema futuramente?

Comment: @bigown Só esclarecendo: não resolve o problema. Antes do PHP 7, não aparecem erros sobre as funções `mysql_*`, somente avisos ou advertências. O `@` serve somente para dizer "não mostre avisos para as funções prefixadas com @". Para não mostrar erros pode-se recorrer a `ini_set('display_errors', 'Off'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida vc não entendeu a piada

Comment: @bigown Desculpa!

Answer (score 0):

conexão é feita com

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "banco_de_dados");
```

e fechada com

```
mysqli_close($conexao);
```