# Link de Generos($_GET)

Tags: php, mysql

Estou trabalhando em um projeto para aprender sobre PHP, e no momento travei para fazer um link acessar o banco e trazer tudo que tenha o seu mesmo valor ou id...

```
<?php
    $generos  = explode(',', $post['genero']);

    foreach ($generos as $categ){
        $dbCheck = DBRead('generos', "WHERE id ='". $categ . "'");
?>

<a href="index.php?catalogo=<?php @$categ['id']; ?>"><?php echo $dbCheck[0]['genero']; ?></a>
<?php
        if (isset($_GET['catalogo'])) {
            $catalogo = $_GET['catalogo'];
            $dadoCat = DBRead('posts', "WHERE status = 1 AND genero = '".$categ."' ORDER BY data DESC");
        }
    }
?>
```

Neste caso o `$dbCheck[0]['genero'];` está me retornando o Gênero que tem cadastrado a este vídeo.

Assim que o valor é retornado a tela, é gerado um link nele para que ao clicar traga todos os vídeos deste mesmo gênero

Estou no inicio do aprendizado, então não consegui fazer muitos testes.

Comment: Não entendi direito ... o o problema é que o link é montado sem id? evite usar [arrobas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50166/91)

Comment: @rray os genero são valores retornados do banco, para usuário eles serão links, e ao clicar ele filtra todos os registros com o mesmo genero. Clica em Ação, retorna tudo de ação na index;

Comment: o link é montado corretamente? `$dbCheck[0]['genero']` pq é indexado em zero?

Comment: Meu caro sua pergunta me fez encontrar o erro! Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Aproveitei os links que gerei na pagina inicial, que utilizava GET para filtrar o conteudo do banco:

```
$cWhereTipo = "";
$cWhereGenero = "";
//Verifica se tem tipo vindo do cliente:
$aGet = array();
//Se for setado TIPO na url, gera 2 variais $cWhereTipo
//para instrução SQL e $aGet[] para tipo=filme ou serie ou animes
if (isset($_GET['tipo'])){
    $cWhereTipo = " AND tipo = '" . ucfirst($_GET['tipo']) . "'";
    $aGet[] = 'tipo=' . ucfirst($_GET['tipo']);
}
```

Adicionei mais um bloco para filtrar o novo GET:

```
if (isset($_GET['genero'])){
   $cWhereGenero = " AND genero LIKE '%" . ucfirst($_GET['genero']) . "%'";
   $aGet[] = 'genero=' . ucfirst($_GET['genero']);
}
```

Os Links ficaram da seguinte forma, fazendo aproveitamento dos SELECT dados pela function DBRead:

```
$post = DBRead('posts', "WHERE id = '{$id}' LIMIT 1");
$generos = DBRead('generos', "ORDER BY genero DESC");
<?php
    $generos  = explode(',', $post['genero']);
    foreach ($generos as $categ){
        $dbCheck = DBRead('generos', "WHERE id ='". $categ . "'");
?>
<a href="index.php?genero=<?php echo @$categ['id']; ?>"><?php echo $dbCheck[0]['genero']; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Quando iniciei este projeto foi assistindo algumas video aulas, por este motivo utilizo as function... Minha ideia é parar de utilizar deste meio e voltar a raiz do código e assim, quem sabe ter um melhor entendimento sobre as funcionalidades.

Proximo passo é incluir este mesmo genero, agora na index, abaixo de cada video.

Comment: Coloca o código que mudou. O que era e explica pq mudou. Aproveite que está aprendendo e veja [essas dicas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info)