# Como colocar dois resultados $row em variável?

Tags: php, array, variáveis

O código abaixo dá erro, ele não adiciona os resultados da `$row`, só a virgula e o ponto. O que fazer?

**Codigo que não da certo**

```
  mysql_select_db('cadastro',$conexao);

$sql="select * from usuario";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro: " . mysql_error());

   // Obtém o resultado de uma linha como um objeto
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
$variavel=($row['email'].",".$row['senha']."^") ;
// quero que tudo isso que esta entre () vire uma $variavel    
echo $variavel
?>
```

**Codigo que da certo**

```
<?php
@$conexao = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

  mysql_select_db('cadastro',$conexao);

$sql="select * from usuario";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro: " . mysql_error());

   // Obtém o resultado de uma linha como um objeto
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
  echo $row['email'].",".$row['senha']."";    
  echo "^";
  ?>
```

Esse é o codigo, ai o resultado que ele me aparece é 
EXEMPLO: joao@hotmail.com,123456,^

o email e a senha estão no meu banco de dados
o que eu quero é que todo esse echo, esse resultado vire uma variavel

Comment: Verifique se os nomes dos campos(email e senha) estão corretos.

Comment: fazendo `echo $row['email'];` e `echo $row['senha'];` os valores são impressos corretamente?

Comment: Sim aparecer EXEMPLO: joao_santos@hotmail.com,123456,^
Ai preciso que esse resultado vire uma variavel

Comment: você quer so imprimir essa variável? quer que ela vire um array?

Comment: quero que concatene o email e a senha em uma variavel por exemplo

joao_santos@hotmail.com,123456,^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, não tenho muito tempo, por isso serei breve.
O teu erro está no **looping**, visto que tu declaraste o inicio, mas não estabeleceste um fim, ou, as linhas afetadas por esse **looping**, veja:

```
// Obtém o resultado de uma linha como um objeto
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
$variavel=($row['email'].",".$row['senha']."^") ;
// quero que tudo isso que esta entre () vire uma $variavel    
echo $variavel
```

Normalmente colocam-se delimitadores, para indicar o incio e o fim da expressão que faz parte do determinado grupo determinado pela expressão de início dos demais variados tipos de estruturas de controle. Mas para o `while` temos: `{}` ou `:` e `endwhile;`.

Abaixo 2 exemplos, utilizando os 2 tipos de delimitadores *[sinais para agrupar]* acima descritos.

## 1º {Chavetas}

```
// Obtém o resultado de uma linha como um objeto
$variavel = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){

$variavel .= $row['email'] . "," . $row['senha'] . "^";

}
echo $variavel;
```

Repare que neste exemplo, instanciei antes a variável `$variavel` fora do **looping**, e só depois concatenei os valores captados dentro do `while` usando o operador `.=`

## 2º Utilizando o `:` e `endwhile;`

```
// Obtém o resultado de uma linha como um objeto
$variavel = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)):

$variavel .= $row['email'] . "," . $row['senha'] . "^";

endwhile;
echo $variavel;
```

Outra observação é, em relação ao `@` no início da expressão de conexão, que deve ser mantida em observação, tendo em conta que ela *suprime erros* retornados naquela expressão, e também em relação ao `mysql`. Deixo abaixo algumas boas fontes.

[Por que dizem que utilizar @ arroba pra suprimir erros é uma má prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84178/por-que-dizem-que-utilizar-arroba-pra-suprimir-erros-%C3%A9-uma-m%C3%A1-pr%C3%A1tica)

[Qual a função do '@' no inicio de expressões em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50166/qual-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-no-inicio-de-express%C3%B5es-em-php/50167#50167)

[Operadores de Controle de Erros - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Se eu pudesse ter-te-ia explicado melhor.

Comment: Deu certo cara vlw...era isso ai mesmo coloquei entre chaves como voce descreveu acima e deu certo

Answer (score 1):

Bem, a julgar pelo descrito você é bastante iniciante.
A primeira coisa que você deve fazer sempre quando estiver desenvolvendo é habilitar os erros (só os desabilite quando a aplicação estiver em servidor de produção, por exemplo).
Parece-me que você recai numa dessas situações:

### Campos com valores vazios

`$row['email']` e/ou `$row['password']` são strings vazias;

### Índices de array ou campos na tabela não existem

password e/ou email são índices não existentes, no entanto você não obtém erro algum pois a diretiva [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) em seu `php.ini` está definida com valor Off/0, desabilitando os erros, portanto;

Se for esse o caso, isso justifica o fato do valor de `$variavel` ser sempre `",^"`.

---

### Passos que ajudarão a identificar o porquê desse comportamento:

Comece inserindo essa porção de código imediatamente no início do script:

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

O trecho acima fará com que qualquer erro seja exibido.
Em seguida, remova também o `@` da variável `$conexão`. Desde que esse operador (@) irá suprimir a mensagem de erro da atual expressão (se houver). Só justificaria ali sua existência se houvesse logo a seguir da chamada da função um `or die('ERROR!');` ou `or exit('ERROR!');` como parte da inteira expressão. Mas claro, aqui é quase certo (pra não dizer 100%) que não há qualquer erro com a conexão pois se fosse o caso a expressão  `mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro: " . mysql_error());` teria impresso o erro independente de como estão suas diretivas de controle de erros.

Comment: Acho que seria legal explicar o porquê da remoção do `@`. Talvez indicar a função `isset()`?

Answer (score -4):

```php
<?php
    //Incluir a conexão com banco de dados
    include_once('conexao.php');

    //Recuperar o valor da palavra
    $cursos = $_POST['palavra'];

    //Pesquisar no banco de dados nome do curso referente a palavra digitada pelo usuário
    $cursos = "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE nome LIKE '%$cursos%'";
    $sub_menu_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, $cursos);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($sub_menu_cursos) <= 0){
        echo "Nenhum curso encontrado...";
    }else{
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sub_menu_cursos)){
            echo "<li>".$rows['nome']."</li>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sinto cheiro de [injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injeção_de_SQL) e de [XSS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). E também não consigo entender como isto supostamente responde ao que foi perguntado.