# erro de Permissão de pastas

Tags: php

Boa tarde, estou com um erro de permissão de pastas, meu código monta a galeria
grava a primeira foto como capa e em seguida, cria uma pasta dentro do diretório 
estipulado por mim, e o mesmo coloca as imagens da galeria lá dentro.

ele grava a primeira foto e os dados mas não grava a galeria.. retorna pra mim:

permissão!permissão! como estipulei num if que verão no código a seguir, só que eu mesmo colocando as permissões 777 não grava a pasta, e no outro servidor funciona, mas nesse não.. segue o código.

` 
    // Incluir o arquivo conecta.php que faz a conexão com o banco de dados
    include "conecta.php" ;

```
//Dou um Extract e jogo o valor dentro da variavel $arq1
  extract($_POST);
  $arq1=$_FILES["imagem"]["name"];
//Seleciona a ultima entrada do banco na tabela galeria
  $s_trab = "SELECT id
                 FROM portifolio";
  $t_trab = mysql_query($s_trab) or die(mysql_error());  
  $trab   = mysql_fetch_array($t_trab);
//Dou um nome para a foto que será o ultimo id + 1
  $nome = $trab[id] + 1;
//crio um nome único para a imagem
  $arq1 = $nome.$_FILES['imagem']['name'];
//cria um nome temporário para mover o arquivo
  $arq1_tmp = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];
//Comando para mover o arquivo para o doretório especificado, aplicando o nome definido anteriormente
  move_uploaded_file($arq1_tmp,"foto_portifolio/".$arq1);

// galeria 
$p = 0;
$countArr = count($_FILES['arquivo']['name']);
for($i = 0; $i < $countArr; $i++){

  // verifica se foi enviado um arquivo 
  if(isset($_FILES['arquivo']['name'][$i]))
  {

    $arquivo_tmp  = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $nome         = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'][$i];

    // Pega a extensao
    $extensao = strrchr($nome, '.');

    // Converte a extensao para mimusculo
    $extensao = strtolower($extensao);

    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png;.bmp', $extensao))
    {
      // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
      $novoNome = md5(microtime()) . $extensao;

      if($p == 0){
        $trataEspaco = str_replace(" ", "", $_POST['titulo']);
        @mkdir('foto_portifolio/galeria/'.$trataEspaco.'/');
        $p = 1;
      }

      // Concatena a pasta com o nome
      $destino = 'foto_portifolio/galeria/'.$trataEspaco.'/' . $novoNome;

      // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
      if(@move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino))
      {
        echo "Fotos salvas com sucesso!";
      }
      else
       echo "Permissao!";
    }
    else
      echo ".jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;"; 
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Você não enviou nenhum arquivo!";
  }

}
// /galeria

//Gravando o nome do arquivo tabela do banco de dados 

  $i_galeria = "INSERT INTO `imagi_new`.`portifolio` ( `titulo`, `chamada`, `cliente`, `destaque`, `imagem`, `data` ) 
  VALUES (  '$_POST[titulo]', '$_POST[chamada]', '$_POST[cliente]', '$_POST[destaque]', '$arq1', now())";
    mysql_query($i_galeria) or die (mysql_error());


//Retorno a página de formulário
echo "
 <script language='javascript'>
 alert('Dados cadastrados com sucesso!');
 parent.location='portifolio_adm.php';
   </script>
";
?>
```

`

Comment: Provavelmente o problema está no `@mkdir('foto_portifolio/galeria/'.$trataEspaco.'/')`, adicione os parâmetros modo, e recursividade: `mkdir($dir, 0777, true)`. sobre o uso do operador de controle de erro `@`: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50167/13561

Answer (score 1):

Clique com o botão direito na pasta e clique em propriedades. Em seguida mude o Grupo e o Proprietário da pasta, caso as permissões estejam restritas ao root, por exemplo.

PS: Faz tempo. Mas caso alguém possa se beneficiar da resposta, fica aí uma dica.

Answer (score 0):

Tem servidores que precisam de permissões meio que em cascata, ex:

```
/user/teste/arquivos/fotos/etc
```

Se a sua pasta `/etc` tem `777` mas a fotos não tem, não funciona.

Tente dar permissão `777` para as pastas acima da que você quer.

Faça um teste e nos fale se ajudou.

Ps: permissão `777` é perigo na esquina, tente encontrar uma permissão mais segura e que funcione para você.

Comment: Ok vou testar e já retorno aqui , pois é eu queria deixar 755, mas como que faz ?? o servidor dos caras é foda .. eles falam que é erro no meu código . mas se funciona em outro servidor será que é mesmo erro no meu cód. kk ..