# Quando usar o @ em PHP

Tags: php

Quando usar o @ antes de fazer a conexão, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
@mysqli_connect
```

e quando usar somente

```
mysqli_connect
```

Comment: [Por que dizem que utilizar @ arroba pra suprimir erros é uma má prática?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84178/91) e [Qual a função do '@' no inicio de expressões em PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50166/91)