# Como suprimir aviso de uma determinada linha de código?

Tags: php

Como suprimir corretamente os avisos gerados pelo PHP em uma determinada linha de código? Tentei utilizando o "@", mas mesmo assim o aviso é gerado no log.

**Trecho do código que está gerando o Aviso:**

```
...
    while ($SrcPos <= strlen($Src)-1) {
      $SrcAsc = (ord($Src[$SrcPos]) + $OffSet) % 255;
      $SrcAsc = @$SrcAsc ^ ord($Key[$SrcPos]); //***** Nesta Linha! (inseri o @ mas ainda assim está gerando o Aviso)
      $Dest   = $Dest.strtoupper(dechex($SrcAsc));
      $OffSet = $SrcAsc;
      $SrcPos = $SrcPos + 1;
    }
...
```

**Arquivo de Log gerado pelo Nginx:**

```
2017/11/03 16:01:01 [error] 2295#0: *382 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string...
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 11 in /usr/share/nginx/www/util/functions.php on line 475
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 12 in /usr/share/nginx/www/util/functions.php on line 475
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 13 in /usr/share/nginx/www/util/functions.php on line 475
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 14 in /usr/share/nginx/www/util/functions.php on line 475
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 15 in /usr/share/nginx/www/util/functions.php on line 475...
```

Comment: pq não um `isset()` para tratar o erro? `$Key[$SrcPos]` deve ter um indice inválido.

Comment: @rray Vou testar e postar o resultado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao acessar `$Key[$SrcPos]` em alguma iteração do while gera um warning devido ao valor de `$SrcPos` não corresponder a nenhuma chave do array, nesses casos é mais simples e correto usar um `isset()` para tratar a situação.

O erro acontece em `ord($Key[$SrcPos]` e não na atribuição `@$SrcAs` se fosse aplicar a arroba (não recomendado) deveria ser dessa forma: `$SrcAsc = $SrcAsc ^ ord(@$Key[$SrcPos]);`

Pode resolver o problema com um ternário:

```
$SrcAsc = isset($Key[$SrcPos]) ? ord($Key[$SrcPos]) : 0;
```

Ou bloco if/else:

```
if(isset($Key[$SrcPos])){
   $SrcAsc = ord($Key[$SrcPos]);
}else{
   //faz outra coisa
}
```

**Relaciondas:**

[Qual a função do '@' no inicio de expressões em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50166/91)

[Por que dizem que utilizar @ arroba pra suprimir erros é uma má prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84178/91)

Comment: Isso mesmo @rray, funcionou corretamente. Foi melhor desta forma, pois está evitando o aviso ao invés de ocultando. Só não entendi o porque do "@" não ter funcionado também. Obrigado!

Comment: @CarlosAndrade editei a resposta com mais detalhes.

Comment: Exatamente. Agora está compreendido o uso do "@".

Comment: Estava fazendo uns testes em um editor online e o `@` também não estava funcionando, não sei porque, em casa vou testar novamente na minha máquina.

Comment: @KaduAmaral olha [esse exemplo](https://ideone.com/4mEh0x). Tem um extensão que desativa a `@` mais detalhes [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30910462/1342547)

Answer (score 2):

O correto é sempre tratar os erros, para uma melhor performance do seu *script*, porém como a pergunta é sobre **suprimir**:

#### Suprimindo em todo o Sistema

```
<?php

// Desliga o report de erros
error_reporting(0);

// Reporta apenas erros de execução
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Reportar E_NOTICE pode ser bom também (reportar variáveis não 
// inicializadas e etc...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Reportar todos os erros exceto E_NOTICE
// Este é o padrão setado no php.ini
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

// Reportar todos os erros
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// O mesmo que error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

<sub>**Fonte:** [Este código foi copiado e os comentários traduzidos da documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-reporting.php)</sub>

Comment: Muito bom. Obrigado pelas dicas!