# Não exibir Warning de foreach

Tags: php

Exemplo, tenho 2 **warnings**:

```
ksort($var);
foreach($var as $v)...;
```

> Warning: ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in
>   C:\www\teste.php on line 15 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach() in C:\www\teste.php on line 30

**Para não imprimir o Warning** do `ksort()`, simplesmente adiciono "`@`" (ficando `@ksort()`) e me resolve.

**Mas no** `foreach`, se eu fizer isso, `@foreach`, ele **retorna erro**:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in
>   C:\www\teste.php on line 30

---

- Por que acontece isso?
- Quais seriam as **opções de não imprimir o Warning** de um `foreach`
  **específico**?

Comment: A opção de não imprimir o *warning* é resolver o problema. Se não há problema, não haverá *warning*. Tome como regra para a vida: tente sempre resolver o problema, não apenas omití-lo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu sei, mas eu só quero saber se existe a opção! Eu não preciso tratar o erro. 

Comment: para evitar esse warning eu sempre coloco um `if()`

Comment: Ninguem esta achando que é burro, mas com certeza, vc pensa que "serve pro seu caso", mas na verdade é um engano seu, pq só "parece que serve", na verdade isso é um equivocou e estamos apenas querendo te orientar.

Comment: Eu não preciso tratar, se não eu faria simplesmente um `if`, mas eu não quero tratar, é de propósito. Eu entendo 100% do "remendo", e estou certo disso. Só queria saber o porque não funciona no foreach, e quais opções tem. Só isso. Que no caso a opção do `if` já seria um tratamento, e eu não queria assim... queria realmente não imprimir o Warning! Se eu usar um `if`, ainda assim irei fazer "nada", ou seja, mesma coisa que o "@".

Comment: @rbz Ahhhh, entendi, tá vou resumir esse trecho na resposta. De qualquer forma para explicar isso vc poderia ter usado um exemplo sem erros, assim não nos levaria a outro entendimento né? Mas agora vou tentar te orientar nisso

Comment: kkkkkk... é que vocês são muito avançados, aí vai no automático em foco no "não faça isso, está errado, pelo amor!"... ✌️

Comment: Caro @rbz resposta editada, veja se agora atende a suas duvidas

Comment: Resolvido Dr.! rs 

Comment: A pergunta não seria mais de como o operador `@` funciona ? É que gerou muita confusão com o código que tem e pareceu me que o foco da pergunta era só esse

Comment: @Isac pois é, o titulo foi o que levou a confusão de entendidmento, fosse algo como, `"por que @ não funciona com foreach?"` ao invés de `"Não exibir Warning de foreach"`, já que na verdade no @foreach nem tem warning o que tem é "Parse error", que é um tipo de erro totalmente diferente.

Comment: É que eu pensei assim: "Não exibir Warning de foreach" que é relativa a 2a questão "Quais seriam as opções de não imprimir o Warning de um foreach específico?" ... Aí eu quis dar um exemplo, funcionando no `ksort` e não no `foreach` (lembrando que é relacionado ao Warning), então seria a 1a questão "Por que acontece isso?" (não funciona o @ no foreach) .... acho que a confusão foi mais por conta de que de fato "não se deve usar isso (o '@') mesmo que exista essa função" rs ... analogia: "Mesmo que dá para pular pela janela do carro, não é correto fazer isso"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `@` no `foreach` emite o erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in C:\www\teste.php on line 30

pois isso é um **"erro de sintaxe"**, ou seja no parse da linguagem, veja que até em um script certo o erro ocorre:

- https://ideone.com/gydCXF

O `foreach` **não é uma função**, ele é parte da sintaxe da linguagem, para o interpretador isso não tem sentido do que você esta fazendo, ou seja após o `@` era esperado outra coisa mas ele se deparou com o **foreach** e a mensagem diz "foreach não esperado (T_FOREACH)"

Por exemplo, isso também seria errado para a sintaxe:

```
(foreach (range(1, 10) as $value) {
     var_dump($value);
});
```

Veja: https://ideone.com/fdcxoU - o mesmo erro é emitido

O `foreach` é parte da instrução da linguagem, como `while`, `switch`, `for` e `if`, veja um exemplo com if:

```
<?php
@if ($foo) echo 1;
```

Isto causa um erro semelhante:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

---

### Sobre suprimir avisos e erros com arroba @

Tenha em mente que a função `ksort` não retorna iterável (não retorna um *array* ou objeto iterável) ele retorna *booleano*, conforme documentação http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php:

> bool ksort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )

Outra coisa, não imprimir na tela o *warning* não quer dizer que ele não ocorreu, o `@` é apenas como colocar uma cortina pra ninguém ver o que você esta fazendo por traz dela, o comportamento não muda em nada internamente, só fica oculto, mas ainda sim o script esta falho e irá desencadear erros.

Ou seja o `@` é somente para suprimir, mas não significa que não ocorra, na verdade ele é bem inutil em minha opinião, para muitos casos `display_errors=Off` no `php.ini` resolveria já, recomendo que leia esses links na ordem:

- [Qual a função do '@' (arroba) no inicio de expressões em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50166/3635)
- [Por que dizem que utilizar @ arroba pra suprimir erros é uma má prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84178/3635)
- [Por que usar error_reporting com display_errors e display_startup_errors?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/3635)

Comment: Guilherme, eu sei os erros, meu array vem vazio e causa o warning nos 2. O que eu gostaria era saber o porque o @ funciona no ksort e não no foreach. E qual a opção de mascarar warning no foreach.

Comment: Isso, desculpa... vem erro de query!

Comment: Que erro iniciante eu cometi! Obrigado por esclarecer.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a questão é o @ no foreach... Publiquei na pergunta: Por que acontece isso? Quais seriam as opções de não imprimir o Warning de um foreach específico? ... Ainda não entendi sua resposta

Comment: Eu sei! Mas eu quero somente ocultar! rs ... tem um propósito! juro! 

Comment: Caraca pessoal, não sou burro assim de fazer remendo, só quero saber, simplesmente! (e ainda sim, pro meu caso serve) 

Answer (score 2):

Além de todos os problemas associados ao uso do `@`já citados na resposta do @GuilhermeNascimento, a [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) é clara quanto aos locais em que se pode utilizar o operador de controle de erro `@`:

> **Nota:** O operador @ funciona somente em [expressões](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.expressions.php). Uma regra
>   simples para lembrar disso: se você pode pegar o valor de alguma
>   coisa, você pode prefixar isso com o @. Assim, você pode prefixar
>   chamadas de variáveis, funções e [includes](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php), constantes e afins.
>   **Você não pode prefixar definições de funções ou classe, estruturas condicionais como o if, foreach e assim por diante.** *(grifo meu)*

Ou seja, é simplesmente algo da linguagem. Não se pode usar `@` com estruturas condicionais, logo isso representa um erro de sintaxe para o *parser* do PHP.

Como um "contorno" (uma gambiarra, vá), imagino que você possa encerrar seu `foreach` em uma função e depois chamar a função com `@`. A sintaxe do `foreach` estará correta e, como a chamada de função é uma expressão, quaisquer erros contidos nela devem ser suprimidos.

Comment: Muito bem completado! Obrigado nunks! +1 

Answer (score -3):

Apesar de tópico antigo, vou deixar minha solução ao problema apresentado.
Já foi explicado o porque do erro e etc etc etc

A solução para o problema de não gerar o aviso :

`<?php`

`error_reporting(0);`

Fonte: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-reporting

Comment: Olá Fábio, devo discordar da sua resposta, apesar do error_reporting parecer trazer o mesmo efeito de display_errors=Off ao usar o valor como zero, o que na verdade ocorre internamente é muito mais, recomendo que leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/3635, fora que o problema da pergunta aqui é sobre uso do @ em um lugar incorreto, desligar todos erros não impedirá que o script pare, só não irá exibir o erro.