# Abrindo nova página e em seguida executando header

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Atualmente tenho um botão (imprimir) que realiza um submit no formulário (visto que preciso de alguns campos que estão nesse formulário). Este por sua vez executa o código que está no action, onde possuo o seguinte código:

```
echo "<script>window.open('".$url."', '_blank');</script>";
```

Pois bem, se executo o script dessa maneira, é aberto uma nova aba no navegador, porém a página original ocorre um erro (variável indexada que não recebe valor). Para contornar esse erro, pensei em executar um header.

**Ficando assim:**

```
header('location:../paginaOriginal.php');
echo "<script>window.open('".$url."', '_blank');</script>";
exit;
```

Porém quando eu coloco o header, não é aberto a nova aba, simplesmente recarrega a página.

**Script do botão:**

```
    $("#botao1").click(function(){
        $("#form").submit();
});
```

O ideal seria a página original, permanecesse estática, por se tratar de um botão de imprimir. Porém eu preciso de alguns campos que estão no formulário dessa página e colocar esses dados em um layout já pronto.

Comment: Você não pode dar nenhuma saída (por exemplo, nenhum `echo`) antes dos headers, eles devem ser a primeira coisa a ser enviada pelo servidor. Ver http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-do-php-cannot-modify-header-information

Comment: Não entendi bem aonde você quer chegar. Parece que você não quer que o formulário seja submetido, mas ao mesmo tempo está forçando que seja. Qual é o erro que ocorre na página original?

Comment: Qual erro que aparece? já tentou colocar um onready para esperar o carregamento da pagina ?

Comment: @bfavaretto, se fosse possível abrir essa nova aba com as informações que estou enviando no $url, seria o ideal, porém não consegui faze-lo.

Realizando o echo depois do header, a aba não é aberta.

Comment: O erro é referente a uma variável que foi indexada porém não recebe nenhum valor.

Comment: Edite a pergunta para colocar exatamente qual foi a mensagem de erro. Eu entendi que você quer abrir outra aba com essa URL, mas o que quer que aconteça com a página original? Para que serve o formulário? Você precisa dar mais contexto para podermos de indicar o melhor caminho.

Comment: @bfavaretto, veja se está melhor. Editei a pergunta como você tinha pedido. Obrigado.

Comment: Eu não entendo por que você submete um formulário que não quer que seja submetido! Quando você submete, ele recarrega a página. Isso é pelo menos parte do problema.

Comment: Tenta colocar window.open dentro de $(document).ready(), assim ele vai executar depois da pagina carregar

Comment: O `header` (php) executa do lado do servidor. `header('location:../paginaOriginal.php');
echo "<script>window.open('".$url."', '_blank');</script>";` nunca vai executar o `window.open`, pois o navegador não renderiza páginas com redirecionamento do lado do servidor.

Answer (score 1):

acredito que você não precisa do PHP para essa função.
envie seu post para uma nova aba.

```
<form action="pagina.php" type="post" target="_blank">
<input name="test" value="1" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">     
</form>
```

pagina.php

```
<?php
//seu código vai aqui
//--------------
//redirect se você realmente precisa disso
header('location:'.$url);
```