# Melhoramento de Projeto em PHP

Tags: php, design-pattern

Estou com uma dúvida sobre padrão de projeto em php.
Tenho uma classe `DAO` que tem um método de seleção, bom o que acontece é que tive que colocar nesse método alguns códigos HTML estilizado com bootstrap, isso que fiz esta correto?

```
class CategoriaDao {
public function selecionaTudo($sql) {
    $conexao = new PDOUtil();
    $consulta = $conexao->conectar()->query($sql);     
    while ($sqlSeleciona = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){       
        echo "<td>" . $sqlSeleciona->descricao . "</td>";
        echo '<td><a href="index.php?action=update&id='.$sqlSeleciona->id_categoria_pagina.'" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar</a></td>';
        echo '<td><a href="index.php?action=delete&id='.$sqlSeleciona->id_categoria_pagina.'" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Excluir</a></td>';
        echo "</tr>";   
    }
}
```

Comment: obs: não estou com problemas relacionados a lógica mas sim referente a padrões de projeto.

Comment: Olha.. o padrao é voce que faz por que o projeto é seu.. Porém para ficar um negócio bonito e com esse "padrao" que voce procura seria recomendado que nao houvesse HTML assim em classes internas e sim nas paginas em que a classe é manipulada..

Comment: Pesquise sobre MVC, a princípio.

Comment: Model view e controller é tranquilo em arquiteturas como JSF ou Spring o problema é que não estou utilizando nenhum framework, isso foi definido no inicio do projeto, o php não tem uma arquitetura mais fechada o que na minha humilde visão é mais ruim pois acaba aceitando gambiarras como essa.

Answer (score 1):

O ideal é seperar o HTML da lógica PHP, dessa forma o código pode ser reaproveitado sem nenhum efeito colateral como [Cannot modify header information](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4251/91) outro ponto é sua classe deve ter uma unica responsabilidade e seus métodos devem realizar apenas uma tarefa, `selecionaTudo` faz duas coisas manipula o banco e formata uma saída de texto(que não é responsabilidade da classe CategoriaDao).

Se forem poucos registros exibidos e o select não tiver nenhum where pode simplificar o método dessa forma:

```
public function selecionaTudo($sql) {
    $conexao = new PDOUtil();
    return $conexao->conectar()->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
}
```

**Sugestões**

Ao invés de criar uma variável de conexão para cada método da sua classe, pode torna-la membro da classe e chame PDOUtil no construtor do DAO.

```
class CategoriaDao {
   private $conexao;

   public function __constructor($db){
     $this->conexao = $db;
   }

   public function selecionaTudo($sql) {
     return $this->conexao->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   }
 }
```

A chamada ficaria assim:

```
$DAOCategoria = new CategoriaDao(PDOUtil::conectar());
$categoria = $DAOCategoria->selecionarTudo($sql);
```

Como não está usando nenhum framework, uma forma de seperar o html do php é usar um template engine como o [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Answer (score 0):

separe a lógica da view.

Entregue o objeto da consulta, como por exemplo um array dos itens, na visualização(HTML) faça um simples while. Assim você não é obrigado a ficar utilizando apenas Bootstrap e poderá aproveitar em outro projeto sua classe.

Uma dica é ter sua classe de Bootstrap, assim pegue o objeto com os itens e aplique sua chamada nesta classe, sendo ela específica para o Boostrap.

Answer (score 0):

Você está criando um padrão ou quer seguir um padrão? Antes de pensar sobre o código temos que pensar sobre a arquitetura do projeto. Embora você diga que não tem problema de lógica esse método não faz "echo" na abertura da `"<tr>"` gerando uma tabela potencialmente problemática para engines de browser que não compensem tags mal criadas (IE até 8, por exemplo). Ele também iria de encontro com o princípio da generalidade já que sua pesquisa vai precisar retornar de forma "garantida" um `"id_categoria_pagina"` e também teria problemas com o encapsulamento, já que a abertura da tabela e seu fechamento estariam em outras classes. Se estiverem na mesma entidade (algo como `CategoriaView`) poderia não ser um problema, mas ainda assim pensaria seriamente em deixar o que é "view" no View. ;)

Comment: obrigado pela crítica, apesar da mesma não responder a pergunta.