# Cannot send session cache limiter em session_start()

Tags: php

Tenho um arquivo `conexao.php` que faz a conexão com o banco, eu incluo ele em todas as páginas do meu site usando um `require_once`, logo após essa linda inicializo a sessão com um `session_start()`.

O problema é que as informações da sessão não estão sendo gravadas corretamente, ao acessar o sistema com outro usuário a sessão vai estar com os dados do último usuário logado, ao trocar de login e senha, etc. O erro que me aparece é o seguinte:

> "Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at "

Se eu colocar o  `require_once` abaixo do `session_start()` esse problema desaparece e a sessão volta a funcionar normalmente, porém eu fico com um problema em meu layout (a página quando ocupa 100% da tela fica em branco quando utilizados o scroll).

Esses problemas estão acontecendo no meu servidor remoto (Advanced Host), quando testado localmente em um servidos WAMP ele funciona normalmente.

Comment: Matheus, recomento que [formate sua questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) para um melhor entendimento e fique também legível. Você pode fazer isso em [edit]. Leia mais em [ask]

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-do-php-cannot-modify-header-information

Answer (score 1):

Com estas informações, deduz-se que o `conexão.php` está enviando conteúdo, ou, no mínimo os cabeçalhos, e não deveria.

Deduzo eu (pois não tenho seu código) que a conexão ao banco de dados está gerando um Warning que não é visível no navegador. Você terá que ver o código fonte do navegador ou então utilizar um outro software que te mostre melhor tudo o que o servidor retorna.

Para ver tudo o que o servidor envia, existe o `HTTP Client` para o OS X, mas para o Windows não conheço. Em último caso pode usar algo como o `Wireshark`, software de análise de dados de rede/protocolo, e olhar o conteúdo dos pacotes de dados.

Depois precisa resolver o que está gerando o Warning ou coisa semelhante.

**Edição:**

Outra coisa a verificar é se há algum problema no acesso ao banco de dados em si. O componente do banco de dados pode não retornar erro e devem ser executadas as funções para poder saber o que está acontecendo, por exemplo `mysql_error()`.

Answer (score 0):

A seção deve ser iniciada no início do código, se houver alguma string anteriormente de você iniciar a seção ele dará erro.

Você precisa finalizar a seção antes de logar com outro usuário.

```
session_destroy();
```

Se você deixar um espaço no código anterior o PHP vai transformar aquele espaço em string e você não poderá iniciar a seção.

Answer (score -2):

Eai pessoal, tudo bem? Obrigado pela ajuda de todos.
No fim das contas, o problema estava no background que estavamos utilizando. Não sei o motivo, mas fizemos uma alteração nele e os problemas sumiram. Obrigado pela ajuda de todos!
Apenas voltamos  o start_session() para o início, como estava antes e com essa alteração no background ele funcionou.

Novamente, muito obrigado pela força.