# Problema com envio dos headers

Tags: php, html

Boas pessoal.
Esta pergunta deve ser a mais perguntada porém eu já tentei tudo (acho que tentei tudo) porém continua sem dar.

Tenho aqui um ficheiro php

```php
<?php
                $ligacao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "banco");
                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                    echo "Erro na ligação MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                }
                if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

                    $seccao = $_POST["seccao"];
                    $target_dir = "img/galeria/" . $seccao . "/";
                    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
                    $uploadOk = 1;
                    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
                    if ($check !== false) {
                        $uploadOk = 1;
                    } else {
                        echo "O ficheiro não é uma imagem.";
                        $uploadOk = 0;
                    }
                    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
                        echo "Desculpa, o ficheiro é demasiado grande.";
                        $uploadOk = 0;
                    }
                    if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif") {
                        echo "Apenas JPEG, JPG, PBG, GIF são permitidos";
                        $uploadOk = 0;
                    }
                    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                        echo "O ficheiro não foi carregado.";
                    } else {
                        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                            echo "O ficheiro " . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . " foi submetido. <a href='index.php'>Clique aqui</a> para voltar para o inicio";
                        } else {
                            echo "Houve um erro com o upload do ficheiro.";
                        }
                    }
// colocar em variáveis os valores recebidos do formulário (método post) e que foram colocados no array associativo $_POST.
                    $nome = $_POST["nome"];
                    $descricao = $_POST["descricao"];
                    $foto = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

                    $sql = "insert into foto (nome, imagem, descricao, seccao) values ('$nome', '$foto', '$descricao', '$seccao')";

                    $resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql);
                    mysqli_close($ligacao);
                }
                ?>
```

Pronto, eu estive a ver alguns dos erros comuns que fazem despoletar este erro como os os echos e prints, as tags html, espaços em branco, etc e já tentei corrigir mas continua sempre a dar o mesmo erro.
Já agora o erro que me dá é este `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\inserirFotos.php:105) in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\inserirFotos.php on line 155`
A linha 105 é onde começa a tag `<?php` e supostamente é ai que os outputs supostamente são lançados. Só que eu não encontro o porque disto acontecer!!
Alguém me consegue desvendar isto?!

PS - o código aqui mostrado está sem alterações que eu fiz para tentar resolver.

Obrigado

Comment: [Erro do PHP - Cannot modify header information](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4251/91) Tem mais algumas respostas aqui, uma alternativa que vc não falou foi verificar o encode do arquivo.

Comment: Qual é a linha 155?

Comment: se o script que postou inicia a contagem na linha 105 e possui 48 linhas,  logo, pressuponho que está faltando mais códigos para chegarmos a linha 155.

Comment: Se você estiver usando o Sublime ou outro editor de texto que tenha a opção de Salvar Com Codificação ... UTF8, faça isso. Em inglês, Save with Encoding... UTF8. As vezes ele salva com UT8 with BOM.

Comment: quando for direcionado para a página que teria que executar o head, abra o console de depuração do seu navegador, veja o código que ele apresenta, se existe quebra de linha, comentário ou algum código no html exibido, teoricamente teria que ter apenas a linha 1 vazia.

Answer (score -1):

A principio o header só vai funcionar se ele for a primeira sentença, não pode haver echo, texto ou qualquer outra coisa antes dele, o header deve ser a primeira instrução de execução do PHP.

Comment: Apenas um adendo, um cabeçalho (header) pode ser enviado em qualquer parte do código, não necessariamente na primeira linha antes de tudo. O que não pode haver é conflito entre cabeçalhos já enviados.

Comment: http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/168071-header-nao-funciona-nem-a-pau-redirecionamento/

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-do-php-cannot-modify-header-information

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: @DanielOmine, creio que o que o Michel quis dizer é que não pode ser feita a modificação do cabeçalho após uma saída do corpo, como `echo` ou conteúdo antes da _tag_ do php `<?php`. Agora, acredito que não tenha problema reescrever um cabeçalho mais de uma vez, apesar de eu ainda não ter testado isso.

Comment: Exatamente, só um ponto que acho equivocado é dizer que deve ser a primeira instrução de execução.. Aliás, eu não negativei a resposta.. não sei quem o fez.. Sobrescrever o cabeçalho é possível desde que não tenha sido disparado. Caso tenha feito, há um modo de reverter, limpando o cache ob_clean(), flush() e funções equivalentes.

Comment: quando disse sentença, me referi ao que é interpretado pelo navegador... vc pode ter 'n' linhas como case, for, if, includes, o que não pode haver antes do header são instruçoes, mesmo que seja quebra de linha explicita, echo, print, comentarios  `<!-- -->` etc... se voce abrir seu ´navegador onde diz que o header não funciona, verá que ele exibe algum conteudo.