# Funcionamento da função header() no PHP

Tags: php, header

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
if (!$lRet):
    // Volta para o cartão eletrônico.
    header('Location: '.$_SESSION['CFG_DIR_ROOT'].'index.php');
endif;
```

Desta forma simplesmente não funciona e segue executando o script, mas se incluirmos uma linha de código abaixo de header() funciona.

```
if (!$lRet):
    // Volta para o cartão eletrônico.
    header('Location: '.$_SESSION['CFG_DIR_ROOT'].'index.php');
    die();
endif;
```

Deste jeito funciona, ou seja, vai para index.php e não executa o die().
Se eu substituir die() [exit() também funciona] por outra instrução tipo echo ou $a = 'b', etc., também não funciona.

Qual é a mágica ?

---

Hoje vou tentar rodar em outro servidor, desta vez Linux, para ver se tenho funcionamento diferente ou alguma mensagem de erro. Depois posto aqui o resultado.

Comment: Habilite as flags de erro do PHP, provavelmente você terá uma mensagem do tipo "**Headers already sent**". Post aqui a mensagem de saída de erro, com base nela poderei te orientar melhor.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção Fábio.
As mensagens de erro estão habilitadas. 
Ocorre que não dá erro nenhum, simplesmente quando não coloco a linha die(); a impressão é que não existe o if. Ele simplesmente segue abaixo. Com o die(); ele segue a instrução header() mas a instrução die() nunca é executada.

Comment: Bom dia, não poste respostas dentro da pergunta, pra isto use o botão responder. Neste caso não precisa nem postar uma resposta, já que o problema nada tem haver com linux ou die ou exit e sim que você não ligou o erros do php usando `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, esta resposta já responde bem ao seu problema http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/18812/3635

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você já tentou usar o [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ob-start.php) no início do código para limpar o buffer?

Sempre quando acontecia isso comigo, eu usava essa função, que resolvia o problema, espero que te ajude também!

Comment: Concordo. Mas na pagina não funcionou pra mim. tive que por no index.php, pois é o inicio do meu código. Pois tenho um index estático, e carrego apenas o conteúdo intermediario da pagina, mantendo o menu no topo e o rodapé em baixo. Então é só por o ob_start e ser feliz o programa em inteiro.

Answer (score 2):

A função `header()` serve basicamente para enviar cabeçalhos *HTTP*.

Normalmente funções que mudam ou enviam cabeçalhos *HTTP*, devem ser chamadas antes de qualquer outra saída de dados por parte do script.

Algumas dessas funções são:

- header / header_remove
- session_start / session_regenerate_id
- setcookie / setrawcookie

Veja:

```
<html>
<?php
/* This will give an error. Note the output
 * above, which is before the header() call */
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
?>
```

Esta chamada retorna erro, porque algo foi impresso, antes da requisição ter sido efetuada. Literalmente, nada pode ser impresso, antes de um *header* ter sido definido, isso inclui os espaços brancos antes e depois da *tag php*, caracteres especiais, etc.

Outra coisa que se deve ter em conta, é que depois de definirmos um *header* mais nada pode ser executado, por isso usa-se então o `exit, die`, para nos certificarmos de que mais nada é executado depois dessa linha.

---

**Algumas Referências:**

- [Headers - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)
- [Headers already sent... - SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)
- [Force URL chance... - SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467330/php-headerlocation-force-url-change-in-address-bar)

Comment: Bom dia @Edilson, você como usuário mais experiente, se notar que a pergunta já tem resposta, então prefira sinalizar como duplicata, este tipo de pergunta já foi feito bastante vezes aqui e já tem resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/18812/3635 - Até mais.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento as perguntas têm diferente abordagem, mas as respostas assemelham-se, no caso, a resposta desta pergunta que referenciaste, é também solução para esta pergunta, devo ter-me descuidado. Obrigado pelo aviso.

Comment: Bom dia, veja a ultima edição antes do rollback, o autor mesmo respondeu (erroneamente) dentro da pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/92944/3 a resposta a qual ele adicionou lá é basicamente o que esta no link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/18812/3635

Comment: Respondeu e removeu, aquela foi 3/4 esta que aí está é 4/4. Ainda por ser duplicada, seria bom se ele tivesse o bom grado de remover a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente sua requisição `header` encontra-se após algum HTML, portanto, já foi enviada alguma saída para o navegador. Cabeçalhos só podem ser enviados antes de qualquer saída HTML.

Logo, um `ob_start()` irá pegar todos os dados de saída e guardar em buffer. Os dados só serão enviados ao navegador no momento em que o buffer for encerrado.

```
session_start(); // 1ª linha do arquivo
ob_start(); // 2ª linha do arquivo
// ...
// ...
// ...
if (!$lRet):
// Volta para o cartão eletrônico.
header('Location: '.$_SESSION['CFG_DIR_ROOT'].'index.php');
endif;
// ...
// ...
// ...
```

Comment: Seria interessante se você juntasse, ao código, uma pequena explicação de como ele responde à pergunta.

Comment: @ramaral, obrigado pelo comentário, farei isso.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```
if(!isset($lRet)){
    // Volta para o cartão eletrônico.
    header('Location: '.$_SESSION['CFG_DIR_ROOT'].'index.php');
}
```

Lembre-se sempre de colocar `session_start()` na primeira linha do código.

Comment: Bom dia @AlissonAcioli, você como usuário mais experiente, se notar que a pergunta já tem resposta, então prefira sinalizar como duplicata, este tipo de pergunta já foi feito bastante vezes aqui e já tem resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/18812/3635 - Até mais.