# erro MPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser

Tags: php, dompdf

Olá,

Estou tendo um erro muito estranho usando a biblioteca mPDF para gerar PDF.

A página busca dados do banco de dados e exibe na página e mPDF por sua vez gera o pdf.

Porém, quando não gero o pdf os dados são exibidos, mas se gero pdf não exibe nada apenas essa msg de erro:

> mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file

Mas se não peço que gere os pdf a partir dos dados do banco o pdf é exibido normalmente.

Lembrando que a pasta do mpdf tá com permissão (deixei até com 777) para ver era isso, mas não resolveu.

Código para geração do pdf:

```
define('MPDP_PATH', 'MPDF54/');

include(MPDP_PATH.'mpdf.php');
$mpdf=new mPDF(); 
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: Acho que é algo parecido => http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4251/91

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faz isso:

```
define('MPDP_PATH', 'MPDF54/');

include(MPDP_PATH.'mpdf.php');

ob_clean();//Limpa o buffer de saída

$mpdf=new mPDF(); 
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```