# Como setar cookies e definir tempo de expiração?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cookies

Estou com uma div onde busco apenas usuarios logados, nela estou exibindo os usuarios porem cada atualizacao é inserido novos registros, me deram a dica de usar cookise mais nunca trabalhei com ele. o codigo a seguir esta dando  o erro Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at line 5

```
<?php
$id_usuario = $_SESSION['user_id'];
 $usuario = $_SESSION['user_name'];

setcookie($usuario, $id_usuario, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$usuario])) {
echo "Cookie named '" . $usuario . "' is not set!";
} else {
echo "Cookie '" . $usuario . "' is set!<br>";
echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$usuario];
}
?>
```

seguindo esse tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Comment: Ponha o código completo, incluindo a parte que coloca os nomes no arquivo, por favor.

Comment: Mal pergunte, você está iniciando a sessao com `session_start();` antes de tudo no código?

Comment: sim, o meu sistema de login esta completo e funcionando normalmente, esta pagina estou chamando ela dentro de uma div a cada X segundos

Comment: Sobre o erro **[Cannot modify header information](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251)** já tem pergunta e resposta aqui no site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na página onde o usuário faz o login, coloque o seguinte:

> setcookie($usuario, $id_usuario, time() + (60 * 10), "/");

isso fará com que dure por 10 minutos.
Já no restande da página, ponha isso:

```
<?php
ob_start()
$id_usuario = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$usuario = $_SESSION['user_name'];

if(!isset($_COOKIE[online])) {
include('usuariosonline.txt');
} else { 
//grava os dados no arquivo
setcookie(online, $id_usuario, time() + (60 * 10), "/");
$arquivo = fopen("usuariosonline.txt", "a");
fwrite($arquivo, "<p><img src='avatar/".$id_usuario.".jpg'/>".$usuario."</p>\n");
fclose($arquivo);
include('usuariosonline.txt');
}
?>
```

Esse código vai mostrar o arquivo usuários online se o cookie já existir e, se ele não existir, ele automaticamente criará o cookie e escreverá o nome do usuário no arquivo dos usuários online

Comment: realmente, adicionei porem não esta gravando no txt, e tambem o erro continua, outra coisa esse header location, como eu uso dentro duma div nao posso atualizar a pagina inteira

Comment: Havia um erro no código. Testei esse em meu servidor e funcionou. Era uma simples falha. Editei minha mensagem com o código novo