# Gerar arquivo csv em php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, csv

Olá pessoal estou tentando criar uma consulta em php no banco mysql para gerar um arquivo csv conforme o código abaixo. O problema é que a aparte que faria o download do arquivo está apresentando erro, já revisei algumas vezes e não encontrei o erro que cometi. O arquivo aparece na pasta FTP onde está o index.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda muito obrigado.

```
<?php
//PDO
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=banco', 'root', '123456');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM cadastro');   
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Criação do Arquivo csv sobre os dados obtidos de um SQL
$from = fopen("file.csv", 'wb');

foreach ($results as $result) 
{
    $results[$idx] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $result);        
    fwrite($from, '"'.implode('";"', $results[$idx]).'"'.PHP_EOL);
    }
   fclose($from);


   header("Content-type: application/csv");   
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");   
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
   header("Pragma: no-cache");
   $path = "file.csv";
   $from = fopen($path, 'r');
   $csv = fread($from, filesize($path));   
   fclose($from);
   echo $csv;
   ?>
```

Comment: Esta questão está na fila de reabertura. Entretanto, olhando para a questão, para as respostas e para os comentários nas respostas, eu fico em dúvida. Alguém aí poderia dar motivos seja para reabrir ou seja para manter fechada?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos eliminar essa gambiarra aqui do código:

```
$results[$idx] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $result);
```

O PHP já tem a função certa pra isso, que é `fputcsv`, e fora isso, tem um erro no jeito que foi montado esse seu loop.

Além disso, se é pra gerar e mandar pro cliente, não precisa
criar um arquivo em disco, basta mandar pra saída padrão:

```
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
```

Ou seja, basta isso:

```
<?php
   header( 'Content-type: application/csv' );   
   header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv' );   
   header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
   header( 'Pragma: no-cache');

   $pdo = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=banco', 'root', '123456' );
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM cadastro' );   
   $stmt->execute();
   $results = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

   $out = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
   foreach ( $results as $result ) 
   {
      fputcsv( $out, $result );
   }
   fclose( $out );
?>
```

Se quiser realmente otimizar, não precisar nem carregar tudo na memória. Basta em vez de `fetchAll`, usaro `fetch` e `fputcsv` linha a linha no loop, mas aí já foge um pouco da pergunta.

Só pra constar, se em alguma ocasião precisar realmente mandar um arquivo que está em disco para o usuário, não precisa desse `fread` do seu código. O PHP tem a função `readfile()` para fazer isso de uma vez só:

```
header("Content-type: application/csv");   
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");   
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
readfile( 'file.csv' );
```

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.readfile.php

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, mas ao testar o código meu servidor teste da o seguinte erro: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/public_html/fab/exportacsv.php:1) in /home/public_html/fab /exportacsv.php on line 2 - 3 -4 -5. respectivamente a linhas header, muito estranho.

Comment: Não é estranho não, esse é um erro clássico de quem não tem muita prática com PHP, acontece com bastante gente. Significa que seu script está mandando algum dado antes dos headers, o que invalida o uso destes. O problema não tem nada a ver com o código da resposta, pode ser por alguma modificação que você tenha feito, ou um problema no formato que usou ao salvar o arquivo. Entenda mais aqui, e veja as soluções: **[Erro - Cannot Modify Header Information](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/70)**

Comment: Era um espaço em branco antes do '<?php', como falou antes erro de um estudante, obrigado pelo apoio aprendi algo novo.

Answer (score 1):

Senhores,

Sei que a pergunta é referente a gerar CSV a partir de PHP, mas, já utilizei soluções nativas em SGBDs e gostei do resultado (principalmente com muitos dados) não há acesso aos dados por PHP. O script que disparará este comando pode até mesmo ter uma política de cache para não executar isso "toda vez", claro, dependendo do que se pretende.

Em MySQL você resolve este problema com um comando, claro, desde que viável na sua solução

```
SELECT id, description, date
FROM operations
WHERE type = 1
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/today_ops.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Espero ter contribuído.

Comment: Vale à pena dizer que esta solução vai gerar o CSV na máquina onde está rodando o DB, no caso.

Comment: @Bacco perfeitamente. Muito bem observado. Não é sempre que essa solução atende.

Comment: Vai do uso da pessoa, realmente. Em casos que o DB roda na mesma máquina, fica ainda mais simples. Neste caso, dá pra aproveitar a segunda parte do que eu pus na resposta para a pessoa baixar o arquivo já gerado com o método que vc propôs. O único cuidado é não criar uma _race condition_ da pessoa acessar a página para baixar o CSV bem na hora que está sendo atualizado. De qq forma, para coisas em volumes grandes que precisem ficar armazenadas, fazer pelo DB pode evitar o _overhead_ e _timeout_ do PHP, desde que o DB permita um número com folga de conexões simultâneas.