# Erro ao redirecionar depois de enviar formulário

Tags: php

#### Meu código:

```
     <?php
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        
        $email=$_POST[email];
        $nome=$_POST[nome];
        $cor=$_POST[cor];
        $nascimento=$_POST[nascimento];
        $cep=$_POST[cep];
        $endereco=$_POST[endereco];
        $numero=$_POST[numero];
        $complemento=$_POST[complemento];
        $referencia=$_POST[referencia];
        $bairro=$_POST[bairro];
        $cidade=$_POST[cidade];
        $uf=$_POST[uf];
         
        mail("meuemail@gmail.com","Assunto do email","
        Nome: $nome
        Data de nascimento: $nascimento
        CEP: $cep
        Endereço: $endereco
        Número endereço: $numero
        Complemento: $complemento
        Referência: $referencia
        Bairro: $bairro
        Cidade: $cidade
        Estado: $uf 
        ");

    /* Este header faz o redirecionamento, com alguns GET's que
serão usados na página na qual foi redirecionada. Exemplo, no
formulário foi colocado "João" no campo name="nome",
então nome é = a João. */
    
        header ("location: obrigado/?cor=$cor&nome=$nome&email=$email&cep=$cep&endereco=$endereco&numero=$numero&complemento=$complemento&bairro=$bairro&referencia=$referencia&cidade=$cidade&uf=$uf"); 
         
        ?>
```

Como podem ver, neste exemplo ele pega os dados que são preenchidos, mandam para esse script `PHP` através de um `<form name="formulario" method="post" action="concluido.php">`.

> Esse script além de enviar um email pra mim com esses dados cadastrados, ele também pega esses dados e insere nos `GET's` contidos na url para qual será redirecionada.

Isso costumava funcionar antigamente, porém não consigo mais fazê-lo funcionar. Sempre achei ele muito simples, talvez seja por isso que ele está tendo problemas.

> É possível fazer isto funcionar?

Observação: Está a redirecionar perfeitamente ao utilizar em `localhost`, mas utilizado em uma `hospedagem web` ocorre **ESTE ERRO**:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
> Não envia o e-mail para mim, e nem redireciona.

Comment: Qual erro acontece?

Comment: Vou postar aqui nos comentários o erro :) Só um momentinho...

Comment: @rray https://s11.postimg.org/9h98l00s3/Sem_T_tulo20161026093345.png

Comment: Removi a tag do título pois não precisa;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alexandre,

tente este código formatado em (UTF-8 sem BOM) e refeito.

```
<?php
    $email              = addslashes($_POST['email']);
    $nome               = addslashes($_POST['nome']);
    $cor                = addslashes($_POST['cor']);
    $nascimento     = addslashes($_POST['nascimento']);
    $cep                = addslashes($_POST['cep']);
    $endereco           = addslashes($_POST['endereco']);
    $numero         = addslashes($_POST['numero']);
    $complemento        = addslashes($_POST['complemento']);
    $referencia     = addslashes($_POST['referencia']);
    $bairro         = addslashes($_POST['bairro']);
    $cidade         = addslashes($_POST['cidade']);
    $uf             = addslashes($_POST['uf']);


    $destinatario    = "eu@seudominio.com.br";
    $assunto         = "Assunto Exemplo";
    $msg             = "Nome: $nome
    Data de nascimento: $nascimento
    CEP: $cep
    Endereço: $endereco
    Número endereço: $numero
    Complemento: $complemento
    Referência: $referencia
    Bairro: $bairro
    Cidade: $cidade
    Estado: $uf ";

    $headers         = "MIME-Version: 1.1\r\n";
    $headers        .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers        .= "From: eu@seudominio.com\r\n"; // remetente
    $headers        .= "Return-Path: eu@seudominio.com\r\n"; // return-path
    $envio           = mail($destinatario, $assunto, $msg, $headers);

    if($envio){
       header ("location: obrigado/?cor=$cor&nome=$nome&email=$email&cep=$cep&endereco=$endereco&numero=$numero&complemento=$complemento&bairro=$bairro&referencia=$referencia&cidade=$cidade&uf=$uf"); 
    }else{
     echo "A mensagem não pode ser enviada";
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Está dando o erro `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/xnshoptm/public_html/br/p/124678139/concluido.php`

Comment: Ok estou editando

Comment: O erro está nas linhas que contém esses `= addslashes`, pois o erro aparece em uma, e eu apago a linha, quando tento denovo, o erro pula pra próxima linha com `= addslashes`

Comment: @AlexandreLopes teste agora

Comment: Vou testar! Lucas :D

Comment: Espero que de certo ;)

Comment: Funcionou!!! Está redirecionando e não apareceu nenhum erro. Único problema é que não está chegando o e-mail pra mim, estou usando meu email do Gmail. :/

Comment: Chegou!!! Só que tá indo pra caixa de spam! :) Kkkkkk...

Comment: @AlexandreLopes Isso pode ser resolvido, usando **SMTP** ou algum outro método de enviar emails. Vou dar uma pesquisada e te mando!

Que bom que funcionou! HEHE **:P**

Comment: Acho que é porque é como se meu próprio e-mail tivesse mandado para ele próprio, kkkkkk

Comment: Mas não tem muito problema não, o importante é chegar, nem que seja na caixa de spam, kkk :D

Answer (score 5):

A página `php` que você colocou como exemplo esta recebendo via `POST` para capturar os "atributos" más pelo exemplo que você postou do formulário parece estar enviando via `GET`.

Mude o `method` de seu formulário para `POST` simples.

Comment: Lauro, na verdade era `POST`, eu tinha errado. Eu atualizei a pergunta :)

Answer (score 2):

No topo tem isso:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Essa linha escreve informações no cabeçalho.

No final tem outro header que serve para redirecionar para outra página.

```
header ("location: obrigado/?cor=$cor&nome=$....
```

Esse segundo header também precisa escrever no cabeçalho, mas como já foi disparado o cabeçalho no primeiro header(), acontece esse conflito, emitindo o famoso erro

```
Cannot modify header information..
```

Para resolver esse erro específico, remova ou desabilite o primeiro header()

```
//header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Esse primeiro header não faz sentido pois se está a redirecionar sem precisar imprimir nada na página corrente, não precisa invocá-lo.

Comment: Interessante... ;)

Answer (score 1):

O erro parece estar na hora de pegar as informações do `$_POST`, onde faltam aspas simples nos nomes das chaves em versões antigas isso era permitido e funcionava nas mais novas um warning é gerado ex: `Notice: Use of undefined constant email - assumed 'email'`.

Como o seu código tem uma chamada de `header()` e uma saida de texto não desejada (warning), acontece o erro [Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4251/91).

Para corrigir mude:

```
$email=$_POST[email];
```

Para:

```
 $email=$_POST['email'];
```

**Sugestão de melhoria:**

No lugar de gerar essa querystring na mão use a função [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) para simplificar o trabalho, passado um array associativo ela gera a querystring.

Mude:

```
header ("location: obrigado/?cor=$cor&nome=$nome&email=$email&cep=$cep&endereco=$endereco&numero=$numero&complemento=$complemento&bairro=$bairro&referencia=$referencia&cidade=$cidade&uf=$uf");
```

Por:

```
$queryString = '?'. http_build_query($_POST);
header('location: obrigado/'. $queryString);
```

Não confie na função `mail()` faça uma verificação se o email realmente foi enviado. Como por exemplo:

```
if(!mail(......)){
   die(print_r(error_get_last()));
}
```

Comment: Vou testar agora :)

Comment: Continua o mesmo erro: https://s11.postimg.org/9h98l00s3/Sem_T_tulo20161026093345.png

Comment: @AlexandreLopes o encode do seus arquivos é utf-8 without BOM?

Comment: Tem algum problema ou algo errado na resposta? posso corrigir

Comment: `charset=utf-8`, @rray, teria como editar sua resposta? colocando o código por completo, eu sou novo com PHP, aí eu não saquei muito bem como fazer funcionar, se você fizer isto, eu vou entende-lo perfeitamente :)

Comment: @AlexandreLopes qual editor de texto vc usa? geralmente o encode do arquivo fica na parte de baixo. vc precisa adicionar aspas simples em todas as chaves, do `$_POST['email']` até o `$_POST['uf']`. Para montar o teste rápido, comente a linha do `header()` assim é possível ver os erros antes dele direcionar a página.

Comment: Utilizo o Sublime Text. Adicionei todas as aspas simples como você mencionou.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes agora que vi, remova aquele primeiro `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: Veja o erro permanece: https://s13.postimg.org/3ylky6u4n/Sem_T_tulo20161026100711.png

Comment: @AlexandreLopes a linha 43 e anterior são quais?

Comment: Parece que tem um caracter invisivel na primeira linha do seu arquivo, tente mudar o encode dele para utf-8 without BOM.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes a linha 31 é do echo?

Comment: A linha do header com location. O erro parece está ai.

Comment: Veja: https://s12.postimg.org/rqp5q7s3x/Sem_T_tulo20161026102248.png

Comment: @AlexandreLopes sobre o como mudar o encode do arquivo veja [essa pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21289157/1342547)

Comment: Agora eu salvei aqui. Vou testar :)

Comment: O erro continua o mesmo: https://s12.postimg.org/rqp5q7s3x/Sem_T_tulo20161026102248.png essa linha 31, é a linha do `header ("location:`

Comment: @AlexandreLopes o erro diz que algum texto foi enviado na primeira de `concluido.php` imagino que seja o arquivo da pergunta ou ele é um include?

Answer (score 1):

Bom valos lá,

Primeiramente olhe a mensagem :

> "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by"*
>
> "Não é possível modificar a informação de encabeçamento - encabeçamentos já enviada pelo **(concluido.php line 1)**

Oque podes fazer é usar um **`echo "<script type='javascript'></script>";`**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    $email       = $_POST['email'];
    $nome        = $_POST['nome'];
    $cor         = $_POST['cor'];
    $nascimento  = $_POST['nascimento'];
    $cep         = $_POST['cep'];
    $endereco    = $_POST['endereco'];
    $numero      = $_POST['numero'];
    $complemento = $_POST['complemento'];
    $referencia  = $_POST['referencia'];
    $bairro      = $_POST['bairro'];
    $cidade      = $_POST['cidade'];
    $uf          = $_POST['uf'];

    mail("meuemail@gmail.com","Assunto do email","
    Nome: $nome
    Data de nascimento: $nascimento
    CEP: $cep
    Endereço: $endereco
    Número endereço: $numero
    Complemento: $complemento
    Referência: $referencia
    Bairro: $bairro
    Cidade: $cidade
    Estado: $uf 
    ");

/* Este header faz o redirecionamento, com alguns GET's que serão usados na página na qual foi redirecionada. Exemplo, no formulário foi colocado "João" no campo name="nome", então nome é = a João. */

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.location='obrigado/?cor=$cor&nome=$nome&email=$email&cep=$cep&endereco=$endereco&numero=$numero&complemento=$complemento&bairro=$bairro&referencia=$referencia&cidade=$cidade&uf=$uf';</script>"; 

    ?>
```

**Ps: não seria a forma totalmente ideal, más serve!**

Comment: Ele continua dando o mesmo erro, a diferença é que depois de exibir o erro, ele é redirecionado. Apenas isso :/

Comment: @AlexandreLopes Copie este código agora, este problema deve ser dado pois antes de abrir a tag **<?php** estava com espaços em branco! teste agora!

Comment: O problema não é esse não :(

Comment: @AlexandreLopes esté o código completo da tua página ?