# Qual a ordem correta de utilização das funções header e ob_start do PHP?

Tags: php, http

**Antes de iniciar a função ob_start();**

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
ob_start();
....
ob_end_flush();
```

---

**Depois de iniciar a função ob_start();**

```
ob_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
....
ob_end_flush();
```

---

Qual deve ser a forma correta de enviar os headers HTTP em um script PHP?

Comment: Apenas para explicar o motivo do voto de fechamento, a questão está sem um foco definido pois não é errado usar antes ou depois de um header(). Isso vai depender do contexto, o motivo pelo qual precisa invocar funções de output buffering. Se você adicionar a qual contexto se aplica, pode ser uma questão válida. Mas da forma como está, você mesmo pode ver nas respostas que recebeu... Nenhuma delas é errada, mas estão abordando contextos distintos ou nulos.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A resposta é: Não faz diferença, dependendo de onde você chama o `ob_start`.

O que eu respondi é polêmico, mas você precisa entender como funciona a captura de buffer e como funciona o envio de cabecalhos para o cliente pra poder entender.

Então leia com paciência:

## Por quê não faz diferença se eu chamar `ob_start` antes de `header` no caso especificado?

Quando você chama `ob_start`, está dizendo para o PHP guardar em memória tudo aquilo que está sendo enviado para o cliente. Ou seja, ao invés de o seu `echo` imprimir alguma coisa para o browser imediatamente, aquela sequência de saída é guardada em memória.

Veja esse pequeno [exemplo](https://ideone.com/m9KohF).

## Não entendeu ainda?

Se você ainda não entendeu, pode estar confundido o uso do `ob_start` com a recomendação de chamada das funções `header` e `session_start` na ordem correta. A ordem correta é: funções de headers devem ser chamada primeiro que a saída para o cliente.

Saída para o cliente é quando você emite um `echo` ou qualquer outra coisa que envie uma informação ao navegador.

## Mas por que há essa recomendação de chamar funções de headers antes de emitir uma saída para o cliente?

Só pra você entender, essas duas funções enviam para o navegador um cabeçalho. O cabeçalho, como indica o próprio nome, deve ser enviado primeiro do que o conteúdo.

Uma resposta HTTP é formatada mais ou menos assim:

```
HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8

Hello World!
```

Ou seja, primeiro vem o cabeçalho, depois, o conteúdo. A parte acima é o cabeçalho e, depois da quebra de linha, vem o conteúdo (aquilo que você costuma enviar através do `echo`).

Então, por isso é importante você chamar as funções `header` e `session_start`, para que os cabeçalhos sejam enviados ao cliente corretamente.

Exemplo:

```
 header('content-type: text/plain;');

 echo "Olá, mundo";
```

Caso contrário, se você fizer diferente disso, pode gerar o famoso erro descrito nessa pergunta:

[Erro - Cannot modify header information](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-cannot-modify-header-information)

Esse erro é do tipo *Warning*, que o PHP emite quando o programador chama a função `header` depois que o PHP enviou para o Cliente um conteúdo.

## Mas então por que você disse que chamar `ob_start` antes de `header` não faz diferença?

Porque com `ob_start`, como dito anteriormente, a saída que normalmente iria para o navegador é guardada todo em memória, até que você chama uma função `ob_get_contents` (ou similar) que capture a saída que foi enviada para memória, ou até que o script seja terminado (quando o script é encerrado, a captura de buffer é liberada automaticamente pelo php).

Então, com o `ob_start`, você poderia fazer isso, que seria totalmente aceitável:

```
  ob_start();

  echo "Olá, mundo";

  header('content-type: text/plain');

  echo ob_get_contents();
```

O código acima não daria erro porque eu chamei `ob_start` antes do `echo`, fazendo com que esse trecho fosse capturado para a memória ao invés de sair diretamente para o cliente. Aí, quando chamei `ob_get_contents`, a saída que estava na memória saiu para o cliente.

Isso aconteceu porque o `ob_start` guarda os dados enviados entre o lugar onde ele foi chamado até a chamada de uma função de captura ou até o final da execução do script.

Veja um exemplo similar [aqui](https://ideone.com/f9kPrY).

Se você fizesse da maneira abaixo, isso faria gerar um erro:

```
   echo "olá mundo";

   header('content-type: text/plain');
```

Veja o erro [aqui](https://ideone.com/EDnI5F).

Note que no primeiro exemplo, não é emitido um *Warning*, por causa do `ob_start()`.

Ou seja, no seu caso (que é similar aos exemplos que postei), quando se usa `ob_start`, a ordem não faz diferença, já que o buffer de saída não deixa as saídas serem emitidas imediatamente, e sim posteriormente a chamada de alguma função que recupera o buffer ou ao final da execução do script.

## Minha recomendação

Apesar de o `ob_start` não deixar que ocorra o erro quando uma função de saída de dados é chamada primeiro que a função de envio de cabeçalhos, minha recomendação é que você sempre chame as funções de headers o mais cedo possível por questões didáticas (todo programador vai esperar que a chamada de headers venha primeiro que o envio do conteúdo para o cliente).

Caso você desista de usar `ob_start` algum dia, você não teria problema em removê-lo, pois os headers estariam sendo chamado antes mesmo!

Então, resumindo: Se `ob_start` é chamado antes de qualquer saída de dados, ao chamar `header` após um `echo`, não fará diferença.

**Nota**: Note que o `ob_start` captura a saída a partir do momento em que é chamado. Se você chamá-lo depois de enviar um conteúdo para o cliente, a saída não será capturada.

[Exemplo](https://ideone.com/XKQftT)

**Nota²**: O `ob_start` faz com que a saída para o cliente possa ser usado em um momento posterior a chamada das funções de header. Se você chamar `ob_start` e enviar a saída do antes da chamada do `header`, também receberá um *Warning*.

Comment: Quem deu o negativo poderia provar que minha resposta está errada, por gentileza?

Comment: Não sei se foi, mas apenas informando que voto de retaliação não é um motivo real para votar negativo.

Comment: Deram negativo no meu também, alguém está negativando na zuera as respostas. Direto está acontecendo isso. E gostei muito da sua explicação, não imaginava que tinha tanta coisa.

Answer (score 3):

Você deve sempre colocar os header primeiro, porque caso tenha um redirecionamento, você pode acabar afetando para onde seus usuários serão redirecionado.

Outra coisa que acontece é que as informações podem ficar presas no buffer até  que você as libere. Irei dar um exemplo prático.

```
ob_start();
header("location: 1.html"); 
echo "send data"; 
header("location: 2.html"); // substitui o 1.html
ob_end_flush(); //e apenas aqui será enviado.
```

Como pode ver no código acima, o `ob_start()` irá armazenar o header até que ele seja liberado através do  `ob_end_flush()`

[Mais informações](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php)

Answer (score 3):

O uso interessante do `ob_start` é guardar as informações que seriam enviadas ao navegador em um cache de memória temporário.

Não existe uma recomendação oficial sobre o assunto, mas eu indico que você sempre chame a função ob_start primeiro.

Imagine que você tenha o seguinte código:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
ob_start();
try {
  algumaFuncaoQueGerouException();
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
  ob_end_clean();
  echo trataErroComoJSON($ex);
}
```

Neste caso você pode capturar todo o conteúdo que sairia para o navegador e ignorá-lo, exibindo apenas a mensagem de erro em um formato JSON. Mas e o cabeçalho que já foi enviado?

O cabeçalho já terá sido enviado, e você terá que conviver com isso, mesmo que ele esteja incorreto. Por outro lado, se você capturou os cabeçalho com o `ob_start`, você pode ignorá-lo também e evita gerar confusão para o navegador.
É claro que você pode sobrescrever todos os cabeçalhos novamente, mas isso vai se tornar muito mais trabalhoso do que simplesmente ignorá-los.

Answer (score 2):

A documentação do PHP não fala sobre nem recomenda nada sobre isso.

Sabe-se que os headers são enviados quando o primeiro byte é enviado ao navegador, por tanto por uma questão de boa prática, eu recomendo definir os headers primeiro antes de usar `ob_start()`

Comment: Não faz sentido isso que você falou, uma vez que o `ob_start` inicia a captura de saída. Sendo assim, independente da ordem, a saída que o usuário emitisse com um `echo`  ou com qualquer outra coisa só seria processada depois do término da execução do script, ou com a chamada de `ob_get_contents` (e funções semelhantes que recuperam aquilo que foi capturado no buffer). Inclusive tem uma gambiarra que o pessoa faz com `ob_start` justamente por não saber onde iniciou a saída de dados para o browser.