# identificar quando o form e enviado pelo botão submit

Tags: php, html

Bom montei um exemplo de forme bem simples em php. Eu tenho que identificar quando ele é enviado pelo botão e quando ele e enviado quando o usuário volta a página.

O problema é, se vc submeter o formulário 2 vezes e depois clicar no botão voltar ele fala que o método foi POST, sendo que não foi pois o usuário clicou em voltar.

Tem alguma forma de tratar isso?

Segue o exemplo bem simples.

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $txt = "POST";
} else {
    $txt = "GET";
}

echo $txt;
?>


<br><br><br>
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="ae" value="ae" />
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar" />
</form>
```

Comment: Na verdade o método foi sim POST, pois o voltar só repetiu a última ação que havia sido um POST. Talvez você possa setar um campo ao clicar submit que te permita identificar se a chamada veio do `click` ou não. Como o voltar vai submeter o mesmo valor, você pode setar a data/hora, alguma coisa assim que te ajude a identificar que foi um autêntico post pelo botão. Só umas ideias que podem te ajudar.

Comment: Poderia montar um exemplo com a data e hora?

Comment: @HugoBorges, normalmente quando você recebe um formulário no back-end você deve processá-lo e no final disso dar um redirect ao usuário, impedindo que ele *aperte f5* ou *volte a página* e re-envie o formulário.

Comment: @jlHertel o problema e que não da para eu usar o `redirect` pois ele tem que ser usando antes de qualquer `out-put` e eu executo alguns echo antes de enviar o formulário.

Comment: @HugoBorges, acho que você não entendeu o fluxo. O correto seria: 1 - Mostra a página com o formulário. 2 - Recebeu o POST do formulário, processa e no final da redirect para outra página, podendo ser o formulário novamente. Se no meio do processamento do formulário você tem `echo`, você pode utilizar a função `ob_start` para impedir a saida dos comandos.

Comment: @jlHertel obrigado pela ajuda, deu uma olhada na documentação do `ob_start` e resolveu 100% dos meu problemas. Obrigado

Comment: @jlHertel ok. eu usei o `// Inicializa o buffer de saida
ob_start();` no inicio do arquivo e o `// Descarrega o conteúdo interno do buffer
ob_end_flush();` no fim, Dessa forma posso usar o redirect onde eu quiser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao receber formulários no servidor é interessante sempre redirecionar o usuário ao final do processamento, de modo que ele não consiga apertar a tecla de atualizar no navegador.

Normalmente eu sigo o seguinte fluxo:

1. Processo algo e monto um formulário para o usuário
2. Recebo o POST do formulário no backend
3. Processo o formulário recebido
4. Redireciono o usuário, as vezes para uma listagem, as vezes de volta para a mesma página com formulário.

Pode ser que no passo 3 você faça `echo` ou `print` no meio do seu código.
Ou ainda, o seu código pode dar algum `Notice` ou `Warning`.

Para garantir que não vai haver problemas no redirect, é sempre interessante utilizar o buffer de saída com a função [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

[Esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186588/14919) pergunta descreve muito bem o uso da função.

Comment: bom surgiu uma dúvida, como exibir uma mensagem de sucesso e so depois executar o `redirect`?

Comment: Normalmente para estes casos você guarda na sessão do usuário as mensagens de sucesso/erro e mostra na página seguinte. Assim que a mensagem for mostrada, você remove novamente da sessão, para não mostrar duas vezes.