# Quais vantagens e desvantagens de usar <? ao invés de <?php?

Tags: php

De acordo com a documentação do PHP é possível habilitar o `short_open_tag` no arquivo `php.ini`, no qual é possível usar:

```
<? /* jon snow */ ?>
```

no lugar de:

```
<?php /* jon snow */ ?>
```

As questões são:

- É interessante usar `<?` ao invés de `<?php` ?
- Existe alguma funcionalidade especial quando se usa `<? ?>`?
- Quais vantagens e desvantagens de usar `<?` ao invés de `<?php`?
- Quanto ao uso do `<?=` no lugar de `<?php echo`, trata-se somente de economia de caracteres ao código?

Comment: Acredito não ser duplicada pois lá a discussão principal é entre `<?php` e `<?=`, enquanto aqui foi pedido entre `<?php` e `<?`. Estão fortemente relacionadas, mas acredito que não configura duplicata. Lá, por exemplo, não é tratado das semelhanças entre as tags e vantagens de desvantagens de cada.

Comment: @DanielOmine a pergunta não é qual a diferença, mas sim das vantagens e desvantagens do uso. Talvez encaixaria mais como relacionada do que duplicada. abs

Comment: Quando marcamos como duplicata as perguntas podem ser diferentes porém, as respostas idênticas. É o caso aqui. Tudo que foi respondido aqui é o mesmo que responderam na outra.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> É interessante usar `<?` ao invés de `<?php`?

Atualmente, não. E sinceramente, acredito que nunca foi. A tag `<?php` existe, no mínimo, desde a versão 2 da linguagem (alguns lugares citam que desde a versão 1) e desde então é recomendada o seu uso. A existência da tag `<?` meio que foi um erro de projeto do PHP em escolher uma tag que já era utilizada por um padrão conhecido a muito tempo, o XML. Nesse caso, não era possível adicionar código XML bruto dentro de um arquivo PHP pois daria erro de sintaxe:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
    <? 
    $arr = array("name" => "John", "age" => 99);

    foreach ($arr as $field => $value)
    {
        echo "<" . $field . ">" . $value . "</" . $field . ">";
    }
    ?>
</user>
```

Neste caso, o conteúdo `xml version encoding="UTF-8"` seria tratado como código PHP e, sendo inválido, geraria o erro de sintaxe previamente citado.

Outro ponto negativo, e o principal atualmente, é a dependência da habilitação da opção `short_open_tag` no arquivo `php.ini`. Por mais que seja uma alteração fácil de se fazer, o desenvolvedor terá problemas para migrar sua aplicação entre diferentes servidores. A cada novo servidor, deverá se preocupar em definir as opções corretas de configuração.

Utilizar a tag `<?php` elimina os dois problemas de uma vez, então não há motivos em usar `<?` no lugar de `<?php`.

**Nota**: Quando o arquivo for puramente PHP, aconselha-se a não utilizar a tag de fechamento `?>`, pois qualquer espaço em branco ou quebra de linha depois deste acionará o buffer de saída do PHP. Muitas vezes não é esse o comportamento esperado pelo desenvolvedor e é um erro muito difícil de ser depurado, principalmente quando trabalhado com `includes` de vários arquivos e lá no final você precisa dar o famoso `header("Location:")`, gerando o erro ainda mais famoso [*Cannot modify header information*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-cannot-modify-header-information).

> Existe alguma funcionalidade especial quando se usa `<? ?>`?

Não, nenhuma. A funcionalidade de ambas é a mesma. A tag `<?php` só existe para contornar os problemas supracitados.

> Quais vantagens e desvantagens de usar `<?` ao invés de `<?php`?

Vantagem: digitar 3 caracteres a menos (se o seu editor já não fizer isso para você). Desvantagens: pode gerar conflito com outras linguagens, como o XML e depende da configuração do servidor. Resumindo: use `<?php`.

> Quanto ao uso do `<?=` no lugar de `<?php echo`, trata-se somente de economia de caracteres ao código?

Na verdade, ela é diretamente relacionada a tag `<?`, tanto que para versões anteriores a 5.4.0, quando a opção `short_open_tag` estivesse desabilitada, a tag de impressão `<?=` também era. Vendo que a sintaxe dela auxilia muito quando for exibir uma variável PHP no meio do HTML, a partir da versão 5.4.0 essa tag, `<?=`, está sempre ativa, independente da opção nas configurações e pode ser utilizada sem medo.

```
<div>Nome: <?= $nome ?></div>
```

Vale lembrar que o caractere `;` após a variável, nesse caso, é opcional e, desta forma, o trecho de código acima é perfeitamente válido.

## Nota: a verdadeira tag

Acredito ser importante deixar claro que a tag correta é `<?php[whitespace]` e não apenas `<?php`. Parece não fazer diferença, mas, por exemplo, os código abaixos não seriam interpretados corretamente e seriam mostrados na tela como texto:

```
<?phpecho "Olá mundo" ?>
<?php/* comentário */ phpinfo(); ?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se a tag fosse somente `<?php`, funcionaria perfeitamente. Mas o que esse `[whitespace]` significa? É qualquer caractere que gere um espaçamento horizontal ou vertical, incluindo o próprio espaço em branco (), o tab (`\t`) e quebra de linha (`\n`).

## Extra

Outras tags que existiam no PHP, tais como `<%, %>`, `<%=` e `<script language="php">` foram removidas completamente do PHP 7.0.0 e não devem ser utilizadas em quaisquer circusntâncias.

## Referências

- [Documentação oficial: Tags PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)
- [Documentação oficial: Descrição das principais diretivas do php.ini](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)
- [Stack Overflow: Why would one omit the close tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4410704/1452488)
- [Software Engineering: Is it bad practice to use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185320/1452488)
- Stack Overflow: How to enable PHP short tags?