# Como enviar por email em php resultados de checkbox?

Tags: php

Toda vez que clico no botão enviar, eu recebo o e-mail com os dados certinhos, porém após enviar, recebo na página uma mensagem de erro: `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: modulocomercial in E:\Domains\diretivagestao.com\wwwroot\website\pageswebsite\enviar_orcamento.php on line 4`
Ou seja, sempre que eu não marcar algum checkbox da lista e enviar, ele dá erro por eu não te-lo preenchido, mas como faço para remover este erro e escolher quaisquer combinação de checkbox para o envio sem erro?

```
<div class="campo">
    <label>Interesse(s):</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="modulocomercial" value="comercial" /> Módulo Comercial
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="moduloindustria" value="industria" /> Módulo Indústria
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="modulovendas" value="vendas" /> Módulo Vendas
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="modulooficina" value="oficina" /> Módulo Oficina
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="modulofinanceiro" value="financeiro" /> Módulo Financeiro
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="modulocontabil" value="contabil" /> Módulo Contábil
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="modulograos" value="graos" /> Módulo Grãos
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="modulofiscal" value="fiscal" /> Módulo Fiscal
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="modulocombustiveis" value="combustiveis" /> Módulo Combustíveis
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="modulotodos" value="todos" /> Todos
    </label>
</div>
```

Formulario de envio:

```
<?
      $modulecomercial  =   $_POST['modulocomercial']; //pega os dados que foi digitado no ID modulo.
      $moduleindustria  =   $_POST['moduloindustria'];
      $modulevendas  =   $_POST['modulovendas'];
      $moduleoficina  =   $_POST['modulooficina'];
      $modulefinanceiro  =   $_POST['modulofinanceiro'];
      $modulecontabil  =   $_POST['modulocontabil'];
      $modulegraos  =   $_POST['modulograos']; 
      $modulefiscal  =   $_POST['modulofiscal'];
      $modulecombustiveis  =   $_POST['modulocombustiveis'];
      $moduletodos  =   $_POST['modulotodos'];


      $corpo = "Este é um contato enviado pelo site com as seguintes informações sobre os modulos:\n\n\n";

      $corpo .= "Módulo(s): " . $modulecomercial . ", " . $moduleindustria . ", " . $modulevendas . ", " . $moduleoficina . ", " . $modulefinanceiro . ", " . $modulecontabil . ", " . $modulegraos . ", " . $modulefiscal . ", " . $modulecombustiveis . ", " . $moduletodos . "\n";

     $email_to = 'meuemail@email.com';

?>
```

Comment: Se vc não marcar nenhum valor é enviado para o php. Nesse minhas sugestões são trocar todos os checkbox por selects onde o valor padrão é `não`. Ou deixar os checkbox como um array. No lugar de pegar ele individualmente vai usar um foreach.

Comment: Grato pela contribuição, mas não entendi o que disseste, sou iniciante em php, já fiquei feliz que meu e-mail está sendo enviado hehehehe, alguma maneira simples de remover este erro amigo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente, o valor `$_POST["X"]` só existirá se o campo `X` possuir um valor no formulário. No caso do *checkbox*, só haverá valor se você selecioná-lo e, portanto, se não selecionar, todas suas variáveis `$_POST` não existirão. Ou seja, antes de enviar o e-mail você precisará verificar se há algum valor a ser enviado utilizando a função `isset`:

```
if (isset($_POST['modulocomercial'])) {
    $modulecomercial = $_POST['modulocomercial'];
} else {
    $modulecomercial = "";
}
```

Ou utilizando o operador ternário:

```
$modulecomercial = isset($_POST['modulocomercial']) ? $_POST['modulocomercial'] : "";
```

Isso deverá ser feito com todas as variáveis.

---

Uma alternativa mais prática é definir os *checkbox* com o mesmo nome, adicionando `[]` ao final:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="modulos[]" value="comercial" /> Módulo Comercial
<input type="checkbox" name="modulos[]" value="industria" />
...
```

E, no PHP, ao enviar o e-mail, fazer:

```
$modulos = isset($_POST["modulos"]) ? implode(", ", $_POST["modulos"]) : "Nenhum módulo selecionado.";
```

E, no corpo do e-mail:

```
$corpo .= "Módulos: " . $modulos;
```

> E **muito cuidado** ao utilizar as *short tags*. Leia mais em:
>
> [Quais vantagens e desvantagens de usar <? ao invés de <?php?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205241/5878)

Comment: Meu muito OBRIGADO á você Anderson, elucidou toda minha questão com exemplos e ainda um plus para o iniciante aqui sobre as short tags, mais uma vez, MUITO OBRIGADO POR SUA CONTRIBUIÇÃO, grande abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Pode simplificar a criação do corpo do email o primeiro passo é deixar todos so checkbox com o mesmo nome e adicionar colchetes. Quando esses eles forem enviados serão entendidos como um array pelo, basta fazer uma verificação se existe algo que foi marcado e por fim dar um `implode()` para formatar (transformar em string) todos os elementos do array separados por algum delimitador.

1 - Passo, mude os nomes:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="modulocomercial" value="comercial" /> Módulo Comercial
</label>
<label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="moduloindustria" value="industria" /> Módulo Indústria
</label>
```

Para algo como:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="modulo[]" value="comercial" /> Módulo Comercial
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="modulo[]" value="industria" /> Módulo Indústria
</label>
```

2 - No php pode usar o seguinte código:

```
$corpo = "Este é um contato enviado pelo site com as seguintes informações sobre os modulos: <br>";
if(!empty($_POST['modulo'])){
    $corpo .= implode(', <br>', $_POST['modulo']);
    echo $corpo;
}
```

Precisa adaptar conforme o uso, nesse exemplo a saída é algo como:

```
Este é um contato enviado pelo site com as seguintes informações sobre os modulos:
comercial,
industria
```

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO rray, muito grato amigo, entendi, dei uma mudada e deu certinho, muito grato por sua contribuição cara, grande abraço!