# Função $_SESSION não funciona

Tags: php, html

Estou efetuando um processo em meu código, onde a $_SESSION['teste'] pega o valor que retorna do banco, onde ele executa sua função em partes, pois se eu tenho uma string unica, ele carrega a informação perfeitamente, mas se a string tem espaço ele não reconhece o valor inteiro e traz os dados pela metade.Exemplo: se o banco retornar o valor "Rua Teste" o valor que a $_SESSION retorna é apenas "Rua".

Gostaria de saber se a função $_SESSION não reconhece valores com espaçamento e se existe alguma maneira de resgatar este valor e trocar a informação entre duas páginas PHP´s.

Configuracao.php:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
             <label>Endereço</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="end" name="end" value=<?php echo $_SESSION['endereco'] ?>><br>
         </div>
```

Php que atualiza os dados:

```
$_SESSION['endereco'] = $consulta["endereco"] ;
```

Comment: Pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código com problemas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no seu HTML, não no PHP. Ao fazer:

```
value=<?php echo $_SESSION['endereco'] ?>
```

Se a sessão possuir espaço em branco, quando gerado o HTML, ficaria:

```
value=Rua Teste
```

E seguindo as especificações do HTML, o navegador irá considerar apenas "Rua" como valor de `value` e "Teste" como uma propriedade. Para que seja tudo considerado como `value` será necessário inserir as aspas:

```
value="<?php echo $_SESSION['endereco'] ?>"
```

Vale lembrar também que para ebixir a informação você pode utilizar as tags `<?= ?>`:

```
value="<?= $_SESSION['endereco'] ?>"
```

[Quais vantagens e desvantagens de usar <? ao invés de <?php?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205241/5878)

Comment: Eu havia feito um teste deste jeito, mas esqueci que testei numa linha sem separação de espaço kk, funcionou valeu!