# Erro Trying to get property... PHP + Erro og:image API Facebook (Compartilhar)

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho outros exemplos aqui mas nenhum funcionou comigo

Tenho uma instrução para puxar uma imagem do banco de dados, só que ela está dando o erro

> "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ...";

```
$q= $db->Select("produto", "nome, imagem", "WHERE id = 21 AND masterid = 100");
if($q){
    $prod= mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
    $thumb = $prod->imagem;
}
```

O que faço pra corrigi-lo?

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/.../.../.../public_html/sistema/.../.../.../header.php on line 6 [RESOLVIDO O PROBLEMA ACIMA]

Outra coisa galera.

Resolvido o problema acima sobre Non-object, eu quero passar o valor dessa váriavel:

```
$thumb = str_replace("../", "http://www.siteexemplohere.com/", ($prod['imagem']));
```

Isto é, o valor da $thumb, para a:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $thumb ? $thumb : " <?php echo $Raiz; ?>/assets/img/thumbs/default.png "; ?>"/>
```

porque eu quero que o usuário ao clicar no botão de compartilhar Facebook, a caixa de compartilhamento aparece a Imagem do produto + descrição do produto (esse ta tranquilo);

Segui a documentação e não funciona... Obrigado pela ajuda que estão me dando... Cada dica uma ideia para formular um outra solução do problema

Lembrando que quando dou um var_dump(), ele está pegando do banco normalmente, já fiz o var_dump do $thumb apos ser pego do banco e depois de inserido no "meta".

Comment: Passe o código inteiro do erro, isso mostrará em qual linha exatamente é o problema.

Comment: O que o erro indica é que `$prod` não é um objeto e por isso não pode fazer `->imagem`. É facil de confirmar isso fazendo `var_dump($prod);` na linha antes da que dá erro.

Comment: @Isac e como corrige isso?

Comment: Primeiro, usando o `var_dump` para saber com o que estamos lidando. Depois, ver como foi implementado `$db`, para saber qual é o retorno de `Select`.

Comment: Dica: você pode substituir o <?php echo $variavel ?> por <?=$variavel ?>. É só habilitar o short_tags no php.ini

Comment: aaah sim isso ja tlg

Comment: Outra coisa, quando eu disse que vc poderia alterar sua pergunta e acrescentar o código, eu achei que o erro era no mesmo trecho, kkk

Comment: Ok, rsrs... Mas esse problema voce sabe como resolve? tem alguma ideiw

Comment: Depois dessa instrução **echo $thumb ? $thumb :** tem um erro. O certo é: `<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $thumb ? $thumb : echo "{$Raiz}/assets/img/thumbs/default.png"; ?>"/>`. Você já está dentro da tag PHP. Não precisa abrir outra.

Comment: @eliangela Só a título de informação, a tag `<?= ?>` não é uma *short tag*, então não precisa habilitá-la. Ela funciona por padrão desde a versão 5.4. A *short tag* é apenas `<? ?>`; comentei disso [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205245/5878).

Comment: Não sabia disso. Obrigada, @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que o **mysql_fetch_assoc** retorna um array associativo. Você deve usar com array:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}
```

Se vc quiser usar com objetos, deve usar o **mysql_fetch_object**:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from mytable");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $imagem = $row->imagem;
}
```

Sobre o segundo problema, depois da instrução echo **$thumb ? $thumb :** tem um erro. O certo é:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $thumb ? $thumb : "{$Raiz}/assets/img/thumbs/default.png"; ?>"/>
```

Você já está dentro da tag PHP. Não precisa abrir outra.

Comment: Aaah entendi, então tera que ser pelo "fetch_assoc" mesmo. Acontece que eu passo esse dado com uma função para retornar thumbnail. Essa informação deve ir para o metatag og:image do facebook, para compartilhar entendem?

Usando a sugestão de voces acontece isso:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function returnThumbnail() in /home/.../.../.../public_html/sistema/.../.../view/header.php on line 6

Comment: mesmo assim eu já defini a função na pagina, tranquilo... Problema é que sempre gera outro erro.

Comment: Por favor, edite sua pergunta e coloque o código lá para conseguirmos ajudá-lo melhor

Comment: Posso fazer isso? Tipo, mudar agora o escopo da questão ignorando as respostas aqui inseridas? ou só acrescento abaixo?

Comment: Pode acrescentar seu código na sua pergunta lá em cima.

Answer (score 2):

Imagino que a entrada 'imagem' deva ser acessada como `$prod['imagem']`, não como `$prod->imagem` visto que $prod é um array associativo em caso de sucesso da função [mysqli_fetch_assoc](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).