# Como redirecionar usuário após login de acordo com o tipo de usuário?

Tags: php, html, mysql

no sistema existem 2 tipos de usuários 1 = admin e 2 = professor, e após fazer o login preciso redirecionar cada um para uma pagina diferente.
Esse é meu código php e html.

```
require "lib/authenticate.php";
$error = false;
$password = $email = $user_tipo = "";

if (!$login && $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 if (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

    $conn = connect_db();

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["email"]);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["password"]);
    $password = md5($password);

    $sql = "SELECT user_ID,name,email,password,tipo FROM users
        WHERE email = '$email';";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if($result){
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            if ($user["password"] == $password) {

                $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user["user_ID"];
                $_SESSION["user_name"] = $user["name"];
                $_SESSION["user_email"] = $user["email"];
                $_SESSION["user_tipo"] = $user["tipo"];

                header("Location: " . dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) .     "/index.php");
                exit();
            }
            else {
                $error_msg = "Senha incorreta!";
                $error = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $error_msg = "Usuário não encontrado!";
            $error = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        $error_msg = mysqli_error($conn);
        $error = true;
    }
}
else {
    $error_msg = "Por favor, preencha todos os dados.";
    $error = true;
}

}


?>
<!-- FIM PHP LOGIN -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>[WEB 1] Exemplo Sistema de Login - Registro</title>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!--Import materialize.css-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
<!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

</head>
<body>

<!-- INICIO HTML LOGIN -->

<?php
 if ($user_tipo == 1): {
    header('Location: admin.php');
 } else ($user_tipo != 1): {
     header('Location: perfil.php')
 }

?>

</body>
</html>
<?php exit(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>



<?php if ($error): ?>
<h3 style="color:red;"><?php echo $error_msg; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-3">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col s4">

            </div>
            <form class="col s4" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"   method="post">
                <h5>Evo System <br><small>faça o login</small></h5>
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control  input-sm chat-input" placeholder="seu@email.com.br" value="<?php echo $email;   ?>" required><br>

                <label for="password">Senha: </label>
                <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="form-control input-sm chat-input" placeholder="sua senha"  required><br>


                <div class="wrapper">
                    <span class="group-btn">     
                        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-md center-block" type="submit" name="submit" value="Entrar">
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="col s4"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- FIM HTML LOGIN -->
</div>




  <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
             Materialize.updateTextFields();
        });
  </scrip>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não bastaria fazer um `if` em `$user["tipo"]` e utilizar `header("Location")` para as diferentes páginas?

Comment: Então, é o que eu estou tentando fazer ali, porém se eu colocar 2 if, ou o else ali da na mesma, se eu logar com admin ele funciona, se logar com o outro não passa, continua na tela de login.

Comment: Anderson, se tu puder ser mais específico, talvez eu entenda melhor o que estou fazendo errado. Não sou experiente então pode ser que esteja deixando algo passar por ser iniciante.

Comment: Após o login, o usuário não é redirecionado para a página `index.php`? Esta é a página `index.php`?

Comment: Isso estou fazendo esse código na pagina index.php

Comment: de onde vem esse $login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código está errado,  você  não pode usar uma condição dentro de um `else` e você também não usou `;` depois  do ultimo parenteses do `header` de usuário não adm. Corrija por:

```
<!-- INICIO HTML LOGIN -->

<?php
 if ($user_tipo == 1): {
    header('Location: admin.php');
 } elseif ($user_tipo != 1): {
     header('Location: perfil.php');
 }

?>
```

Comment: Era sobre isso que o Andersson estava falando nos comentários acima.

Answer (score 0):

> Esse redirecionamento já poderia ter sido feito antes, mesmo porque todo código que trabalhe com headers (sessões, cookies, redirecionamentos e encriptação) devem ser enviados, criados, definidos e modificados antes do HTML.

```
if ($user["password"] == $password) {

    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user["user_ID"];
    $_SESSION["user_name"] = $user["name"];
    $_SESSION["user_email"] = $user["email"];
    $_SESSION["user_tipo"] = $user["tipo"];

    $_user_tipo=$user["tipo"];

    if ($_user_tipo == 1): {
        header('Location: admin.php');
        } elseif ($_user_tipo == 2): {
        header('Location: perfil.php')
        }else{
        //caso nenhum dos dois
    }
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está emitindo um `header` após já enviar o `body`, que é enviado por `<!-- FIM PHP LOGIN -->`, isso não é permitido, por padrão, você deveria de estar obtendo um:

> [Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-cannot-modify-header-information)

*Se isto "funcionasse".*

---

Para corrigir pode simplesmente fazer:

```
//...

$redirecionamentos = [
    '1' => 'admin.php',
    '2' => 'perfil.php',
];

if (array_key_exists($_SESSION['user_tipo'], $redirecionamentos)) {

    header('Location: ' . $redirecionamentos[ $_SESSION['user_tipo'] ], true, 302);

}

?>
<!-- FIM PHP LOGIN -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
</html>
//...
```

Utilizando esta ordem, antes do HTML, isto poderia funcionar, assim como pode utilizar qualquer uma das soluções que foram apresentadas antes. Neste caso especifico, se o usuário for `1` ou `2` ele irá redirecionar para o respectivo local, determinado pela array. Será enviado o `header` antes do `body`, como esperado. O cabeçalho terá o local, definido por `$redirecionamentos[ $_SESSION['user_tipo'] ]`, assim como o código, `302`, de redirecionamento temporário.

---

*Apenas porque não consigo ficar quieto, **mas está fora da questão perguntada**.*

1. Não utilize o MD5() ele é considerado quebrado:

   - A maior parte das senhas são fracas e previsíveis, o [RockYou.txt](https://wiki.skullsecurity.org/Passwords) é um dicionário bem forte, unindo ao [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/).
   - O PHP tem o `password_hash()` e o `hash_pbkdf2()` nativamente, com custo ajustável e com suporte adequado para salt.
2. Esqueça o `$user["password"] == $password`:

   - Ele é vulnerável por comparar com tipagem fraca, experimente usar [`md5('aabg7XSs') == md5('240610708')`](https://3v4l.org/KX3ko) e me diga o resultado, pois é.
   - Ele é vulnerável por timming-attack, uma vez que utiliza `memcmp`.