# duvida com session

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou tentando abrir uma session no php porém a mesma não grava valor, me questionei se é o modo que faço o redirecionamento então queria tirar a minha dúvida, básicamente oque faço é pegar o login e senha e passar para uma pagina de login por ajax, nessa pagina de login faço a autenticação via json e se retornar valido redireciono no ajax para representante.php, porém quando tento pegar os valores da minha session os valores não estão la, queria saber se é por causa do redirecionamento por javascript, caso alguém poder me ajudar a encontrar o erro obrigado, sou novo no php, Vou deixar explicado.

Aqui a função que envia por ajax o login e senha para a Login.php

```
$(document).ready( function() {

     $('#logar').click(function(){
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val(); 

   $.ajax({ 

         url: 'controllers/Login.php',
         data: "username=" +username + "&password="+password ,
         type: 'GET',
         success: function(output) {
          alert(output);
           if(output != ''){
              window.location.href = "http://bravetech.com.br/politizar/representante.php";
           }
           else {
             alert('não logou');
           }
         }
      })
     });
  });
```

Em seguida recebo eles na login.php faço a autenticação por json e retorno no ajax o isValid que retorna um boolean

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
 //echo "<script>alert('$username');</script>";

 session_name("start");
 session_start("start");

        $data = array(
            "username" => $username, 
            "password" => $password
                     );

        $data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   
        $ch = curl_init('http://politizar.azurewebsites.net/api/account/login');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
        );                                                                                                                   

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $dados = json_decode($result, true);
        //print_r($dados);
        $access = $dados['object']['access_token'];
        $sucess = $dados['isValid'];

        //echo $sucess;
        //echo "<script>alert('$sucess');</script>";
        if($sucess) {
          // echo "<script>alert('$sucess');</script>";

           $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
           $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        }
        else {
            session_destroy();
            //echo "<script>alert('Nao foi');</script>";
           unset ($_SESSION['username']);
           unset ($_SESSION['password']);
        }
        echo $sucess;
```

Logo depois na função ajax redireciono para a Representante.php que utiliza uma função da listarRepresentante.php

```
session_start("start");
$representantes = listarRepresentante();
```

Na listar representante tento adquirir os valores da session porém não vai

```
echo $_SESSION['username'];

session_start("start");
if((!isset ($_SESSION['username']) == true) and (!isset ($_SESSION['password']) == true))
{
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    unset($_SESSION['password']);
    header('location:index.php');
} 

$user = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Queria saber se é o modo que redirecionei por ajax e se puder também ajudar a solucionar, Obrigado

Comment: O session_start não tem que estar na primeira linha, ou seja, antes do echo $_SESSION['username'];?

Comment: outra coisa Não emita output (echo) antes de enviar os headers!

Comment: Sim @LeoCaracciolo aquele echo foi de um teste de antes, a questão é que ele sempre vem vazio mesmo eu colocando depois, ou seja naquela condição if ele sempre entra e redireciona pro index, e essa do output antes de enviar os headers como assim? Em que parte você está falando?

Comment: mandar um echo $_SESSION['username']; antes de um header('location:index.php');   https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-cannot-modify-header-information