# Erro para iniciar sessão em site php

Tags: php

Tenho esse código para iniciar a sessão do meu site:

```
session_start();
ob_start();
define('URL', 'http://www.pardaldobico.com.br/');

define('CONTROLER', 'home');
define('METODO', 'index');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

**Porém o servidor está apresentando esse erro:**

PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/pardaldobicocom/public_html/index.php:14) in /home/pardaldobicocom/public_html/config/Config.php on line 2

PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/pardaldobicocom/public_html/index.php:14) in /home/pardaldobicocom/public_html/config/Config.php on line 8

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: A segunda mensagem tem um topico que fala disso : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-cannot-modify-header-information

Comment: Olá Francene Arnaut, bem-vinda! Aproveita e leia esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1):

Tem que estar assim

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 ob_start();
 ...............
 ...............
```

Assim pode

```
 <?php

 session_start();
 ob_start();
 ...............
 ...............
```

Assim não pode

```
 <?php // Espaço antes da tag PHP | Envio do header
session_start();
?>
```

Nem assim

```
 <?php
 echo 'Olá Francene Arnaut'; // Aqui está o header, sendo enviado ao usuário do site 
 através do comando echo
 session_start(); // Início de sessão depois do envio do header = Erro
 ?>
```

> Resumo

- Não criar e/ou definir uma sessão depois de enviar um echo;
- Todo código que trabalhe com sessões, cookies, redirecionamentos e encriptação `(headers)` devem ser definidos, criados, enviados e modificados antes do HTML.

[**Erro - Cannot modify header information**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-cannot-modify-header-information)

Comment: Leo, aonde está "assim não pode", pode sim porque espaços dentro do delimitador de abertura do "<?php" não são interpretados como saída de cabeçalho. O que não pode é um espaço antes da abertura do "<?php". De qualquer forma pelo exemplo +1

Comment: @RafaelSalomão, ops, faltou algo no espaço, valeu!

Comment: Agora sim perfeito! Assim pode ! =P

Comment: hahahaha, obrigado  :)

Answer (score 0):

Francene, verifique espaços em branco antes da abertura do seu php. Se está mensagem está aparecendo indica que o cabeçalho de resposta já foi enviado ao navegador, e portanto não é possível anexar os dados de sessão ao cabeçalho. Geralmente isso acontece quando você tem um saída de impressão no seu código ou um espaço em branco no seu php antes da abertura do script `<?php`. Certifique-se de iniciar a sessão sempre no topo do seu script.