# Como usar variavel PHP em outras páginas

Tags: php, sql, cookies

Tenho um script que traz os resultados de uma busca sql da seguinte forma:

```
$sql = (...);
$result = $db->query($sql);
while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    $ids = $obj->id_prestador.",";
}
```

Se faço um echo $ids depois de criar o $ids, ele traz por exemplo: "710, 720, 730,".

Aí em outra página eu queria poder pegar essa informação para poder rodar um script que envia esses ID's para um aplicativo, como posso fazer?

Tentei por cookie que seria o melhor pra mim, mas daí ele só trouxe o 1º resultado ("710,").

```
$sql = (...);
$result = $db->query($sql);
while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    $ids = $obj->id_prestador.",";
    setcookie("cookieprestador",$ids)
}
```

Eu queria poder pegar em qualquer página o $ids como "710, 720, 730,".

ATUALIZANDO:
converti em array e usei implode e deu certo, porém quando faço o setcookie dá mensagem de Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by output started at .....

Abaixo como ficou:

```
$files = array();
 while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $files[] = $obj["id_prestador"];
 }
$string = implode(', ', $files);
setcookie("cookieprestador",$string);
```

Comment: E por quê não define o `cookie` depois do `while`?

Comment: eu tentei, mas daí o cookie vem em branco

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo corrija o erro "Cannot modify header information" seguindo isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-cannot-modify-header-information se ainda tiver problema mesmo depois de corrigir o erro se ainda tiver outro problema edite a pergunta que verei se é possivel reabrir.

Answer (score 0):

**Esse erro:**
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by output started at

Já passei varias vezes por ele, ele acontece quando você faz um **saída de texto antes de guardar um cookie ou sessão** , se atente nisso e caso não seja isso...no meu caso já passei por esse problema e não tinha saída de dados antes de guardar o cookie e a solução foi criar um novo arquivo e colar tudo que tinha em um arquivo no outro novo e dai resolveu.