# Meu login não pega a $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho os seguintes códigos:

**conn-login.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

//Conexão MYSQLI - LOGIN GLOBAL
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'login', 'senha', 'bancodedados');

?>
```

**login.php**:

```
<?php
include 'conn-login.php';

header('Content-Type: application/json');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $email_l = $_POST['email'];
    $senha_l = md5($_POST['senha']);

    $sql = "SELECT u.id, u.id_farmacia, u.usuario, u.email, u.senha, u.accesskey, f.db_database, f.db_username, f.db_password FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN farmacias f ON u.id_farmacia = f.id WHERE (email =? AND senha =?) LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email_l, $senha_l);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $id_farmacia, $usuario, $email, $senha, $accesskey, $database, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $stmt->store_result();

    if($stmt->num_rows <= 0){

        $var = Array(
            'status' => 'ERRO',
            'msg' => 'Usuário não cadastrado e/ou senha incorreta!'
        );

    } else {

        while ($ln = $stmt->fetch()){

            $_SESSION['database'] = $database;
            $_SESSION['dbuser'] = $dbuser;
            $_SESSION['dbpass'] = $dbpass;

            $var = Array(
                'status' => 'OK',
                'accesskey' => $accesskey
            );
        };

    }
}    
echo json_encode($var);
exit;
$stmt->close(); 

?>
```

e depois o init.php, onde pega as sessions do usuário para conectar ao um novo banco de dados (banco de dados do usuário logado).

**init.php**

```
<?

//Conexão MYSQLI
$db = $_SESSION['database'];
$dbuser = $_SESSION['dbuser'];
$dbpass = $_SESSION['dbpass'];

var_dump($_SESSION);

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$mysqli->query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
$mysqli->query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
$mysqli->query('SET character_set_results=utf8');

//Data Padrão do Brasil (GMT -3)
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

?>
```

Quando uso o INIT.PHP, o VAR_DUMP mostra NULL.

No host, quando uso o arquivo pacientes.php, onde resgato os dados de todos os pacientes:

```
[21-Sep-2017 16:45:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/gui/public_html/sistemafp/init.php on line 9
[21-Sep-2017 16:45:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/gui/public_html/sistemafp/init.php on line 11
[21-Sep-2017 16:45:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/gui/public_html/sistemafp/init.php on line 12
[21-Sep-2017 16:45:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/gui/public_html/sistemafp/init.php on line 13
[21-Sep-2017 16:45:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/gui/public_html/sistemafp/init.php on line 14
[21-Sep-2017 13:45:49 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/gui/public_html/sistemafp/pac.php on line 5
[21-Sep-2017 13:45:49 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on null in /home/gui/public_html/sistemafp/pac.php on line 6
```

pacientes.php:

```
<?php
include 'init.php'; 

if(isset($_POST['id_paciente'])){
//restante do meu código
}
```

Onde estou errando? =(

Comment: Cara, isso `!isset ($_SESSION['dbuser']) == true` tá muito errado, misturar `!` com `== true` é receita para desastre e confusão de lógica.

Comment: Hahahaha, é um código bem antigo. Já corrigi.

Comment: Guilherme, notei uma coisa, troca `<?` por `<?php` no init.php

Comment: Corrigi tudo: mesma coisa.

Comment: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/gui/public_html/sistemafp/init.php:1) in /home/gui/public_html/sistemafp/init.php on line 2

Comment: Sim, o init.php incluo em outos scripts PHP, que precisam de conexão ao banco de dados que vem das $_SESSION, mas como não estou conseguindo pegar as sessoes, da erro.

Answer (score 1):

Falta `session_start` no init.php, você pode fazer:

```
<?php

session_start();


if((!isset ($_SESSION['dbuser'])) and (!isset ($_SESSION['dbpass'])))
{
```

Supondo que o init.php seja incluido em outro arquivo inclua ele no topo antes de qualquer espaço, como explicado nesta pergunta:

- [Erro - Cannot modify header information](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4251/3635)

Ou seja se fizer algo como:

```
<html>
<?php

include 'init.php';
```

Vai falhar, se fizer:

```
<?php

echo 'oi';

include 'init.php';
```

Vai falhar também, então faça assim:

```
<?php
include 'init.php';
?>
<html>
```

Se houver um espaço ou quebra de linha que for antes do `session_start` vai ocorrer o erro, como por exemplo:

[image: problema]

E é claro que não cria os cookies, porque os headers já foram enviados.

Comment: Nos outros, tenho que deixar o session_start(); ?

Comment: @GuilhermeLirio só no init.php, pois com o include já vai pegar, desde que venha antes de qualquer echo ou espaço/html, só mantem no conn-login além do init.

Comment: Mas como irei pegar as $_SESSION no conn-login.php ?

Comment: O teu conn-login só conecta, como eu disse, só o conn-login e o init devem ter session_start, mantém nos 2, não falei pra tirar do conn-login.

Comment: Testei aqui, e deu a mesma coisa. Outra detalhe: não cria um cookie quando loga.

Comment: PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/gui/public_html/sistemafp/init.php:1) in /home/gui/public_html/sistemafp/init.php on line 2
PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/gui/public_html/sistemafp/init.php:1) in /home/gui/public_html/sistemafp/init.php on line 2

Comment: Mas deu na mesma "o que?", deu erro "Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by" ou outro erro, ou nenhum erro? Cara manda os 3 arquivos, conn-login, init e um que esteja incluindo o com include pra eu ver, você deve tá fazendo confusão.

Comment: Poh cara, eu já expliquei na resposta "Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by" é quando tem espaço ou echo antes do session_start, por isso o include tem que ir antes do `<HTML>`, eu até te mandei o link pra vc entender https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4251/3635, lê de novo a resposta por favor.

Comment: @GuilhermeLirio faz o seguinte, manda os 3 arquivos, conn-login, init e um que esteja incluindo o com include pra eu ver usando o http://pastebin.com, você deve tá fazendo confusão

Comment: Eu não estou usando PHP junto com HTML, só uso separadamente. Vou editar o meu post exatamente como está aqui.

Comment: Cara você tá fazendo confusão, as páginas que você usa o `include 'init.php'` com certeza tem HTML ou echo antes do include, não precisa estar o HTML propriamente no mesmo script. Cara manda os 3 arquivos porque eu não tenho nem como imaginar aonde vc esta se atrapalhando, assim eu consigo ajustar pra ti e te mando de volta, mas manda via pastebin.com ou dropbox ou qualquer sistema de compartilhamento, mas por favor não manda tudo, só os 3 arquivos que eu pedi.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Y5Kwwc4c

Comment: Poh cara vc mandou tudo misturado e nem mandou o que eu pedi. Presta atenção por favor, se não vamos ficar 3 dias aqui, manda o arquivo que vc esta incluindo o init.php e não o init.php. @GuilhermeLirio

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZDGu5ypP

Comment: tá deve ter algum espaçamento em algum lugar, faz o seguinte leia tudo isso primeiro: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4251/3635 e depois procura em todos arquivos e veja se não tem espaço algum, mesmo que seja uma simples quebra de linha.

Comment: Não tem, por isso estou achando estranho. Nem cookie está criando!

Comment: @GuilhermeLirio se deu o erro é claro que não vai criar o cookie, como eu já disse, me manda via dropbox, googledrive ou qualquer outro meio os arquivos originais, somente os que citei já, acho que já pedi umas 3 vezes.

Comment: Dei um tempo, pra ve se encontrava o erro, mas nada. Consigo dar um echo nas $sessions no login, mas o arquivo init.php não consegue pegar as sessões.

Comment: @GuilhermeLirio manda pro meu e-mail todos os arquivos, **menos** arquivos de senha e **menos** dados de banco de dados... O e-mail é este brcontainer@yahoo.com.br, esse é o máximo que posso fazer por ti agora.

Comment: Não é por nada não, mas não vou enviar os meus arquivos. Te enviei o pastebin, EXATAMENTE como está aqui amigo. Quer que eu te mande separadamente, coloco lá sem problemas. 
O tópico está exatamente como está agora, e não está dando erro algum, mas não está pegando a sessão para conexão.

Se não puder ajudar assim, agradeço desde já a tentativa de ajuda!

Comment: @GuilhermeLirio Se esta ocorrendo erro é porque mesmo você acreditando que estão corretos, eles devem estar errados em algum ponto que você não percebeu, eu não sei mais o que fazer pra te ajudar, como disse é bem claro que esta havendo alguma confusão de sua parte, o máximo que posso fazer por até passando do limite "permitido" da comunidade foi lhe enviar meu e-mail para que eu mesmo pudesse checar aonde você fez a confusão, como você não pode me enviar e não consegue criar um exemplo "minimizado" que cause a falha (MCVE) eu não tenho como te ajudar, porque não é um erro na linguagem...

Comment: ... é uma confusão de  sua parte, e infelizmente eu não tenho como adivinhar, a unica maneira é ou você cria um MCVE ou você me envia os arquivos, eu não tenho interesse em teus scripts, sou programador experiente e garanto que entre pegar coisas dos outros e criar as minhas eu terei mais lucro criando as minhas proprias baseados na experiencia de 9 anos de programação que tenho em diversas linguagens, como c, c++, python, php, java, javascript, vb.net e etc. Faça como quiser @GuilhermeLirio, ofereci toda ajuda que foi possivel, cabe a você agora seguir a dicas, depende de você.

Comment: Acredito que descobri o erro: Limpei uns arquivos no meu servidor e curiosamente, começou a pegar o $_SESSION na outra página. E tambem modifiquei essa linha no PHP.ini: session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions". Não sei se tem algo haver.
Mais cedo @GuilhermeNascimento te enviei os arquivos.