# Como usar a função Location em orientação a objetos

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

estou tentando direcionar o usuário para a pagina de painel, quando ele fizer o login na pagina inicial, porém ao direcionar dá o erro abaixo, mas se eu usar javascript com o mesmo caminho dá certo.

Usando o Location:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando utilizo a linha de código abaixo eu consigo o redirecionamento, porém acho mais certo usar o Location.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Evite postar a imagem do código. Poste o código em si. [mcve]

Comment: Eu tento mas quando é código em HTML não aparece na tela quando salvo

Comment: Ao colar o código basta seleciona-lo e pressionar `Ctrl + K`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro - "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss os problemas são diferentes. Na pergunta indicada o erro é `Cannot modify header`. Nessa pergunta, o erro é devido o redirecionamento funcionar como o esperado no JS, porém não redirecionar como o esperado quando utilizado o `php`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr não, o problema é exatamente esse. A questão é que o autor omitiu da pergunta a mensagem de erro que ele mesmo citou.

Answer (score 0):

A url não estão iguais como foi comentado na pergunta

Observe as linhas abaixo:

**Header:**

```
header("Location:/views/painel.php");
```

**Html**

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=views/painel.php' />";
```

Observe que no `header` você está adicionando uma `/` *(barra*) antes da URL. Quando você adiciona essa barra no início, significa que o usuário terá que ser redirecionado para `<raiz-do-projeto>/views/painel.php`

Sem a barra, você informa que o usuário deve ser redirecionado a parti da URL atual + endereço informado. Ex:

---

Imagine que você está na área de administração do site: `https://www.example.com/admin/`

Quando você acessa com a barra no início (como está no *header*), você está informando para o usuário ser redirecionado para `https://www.example.com/views/painel.php`

Quando você acessa **sem** a barra no início (como está no *html*), você está informando para o usuário ser redirecionado para `https://www.example.com/admin/views/painel.php`

---

Outro erro no seu código são os `echo` antes do `Location`.

Quando você escreve imprimi algo com `echo`, `print` etc *(ou até mesmo há caracteres "escondido" antes da abertura da tag `<?php`)*. O `PHP` não consegue modificar as informações do `header`.