# Sistema de login com erro

Tags: php, login

Tenho um sistema de Login, que já funciona em outro site e estou tentando transferir pra outro, e não funciona de jeito nenhum. Gostaria que alguém desse uma olhada. Se digito um usuário errado, retorna um erro de usuário inválido, então está checando o banco. Quando insiro um usuário certo, aparece as seguintes mensagens de erro:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already
>   sent by (output started at
>   /home/netosale/public_html/e-educacao/validacao.php:2) in
>   /home/netosale/public_html/e-educacao/validacao.php on line 28
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   /home/netosale/public_html/e-educacao/validacao.php:2) in
>   /home/netosale/public_html/e-educacao/validacao.php on line 28
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/netosale/public_html/e-educacao/validacao.php:2) in
>   /home/netosale/public_html/e-educacao/validacao.php on line 36

Vou lá nessas duas linhas, e não consigo localizar absolutamente nada de anormal. O que pode estar acontecendo. Já baixei diversos outros sistemas de login, e todos dão erro. Será que é algum problema bom o bootstrap ou coisa parecida? Segue código pra que dêem uma olhada:

```
<?php
     // Verifica se houve POST e se o usuсrio ou a senha щ(sуo) vazio(s)
  if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($_POST['usuario']) OR empty($_POST['senha']))) {
      header("Location: index.php"); exit;
  }
  // Tenta se conectar ao servidor MySQL
  mysql_connect('localhost', 'xzthyb45', '164544515151561') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
  // Tenta se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL
  mysql_select_db('ljklfdfjkldj') or trigger_error(mysql_error());

  $usuario = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
  $senha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['senha']); 
  // Validaчуo do usuсrio/senha digitados
  $sql = "SELECT `id`, `nome`, `nivel` FROM `userPerms` WHERE (`usuario` = '".$usuario ."') AND (`senha` = '". sha1($senha) ."') AND (`ativo` = 1) LIMIT 1";
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
  if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
      // Mensagem de erro quando os dados sуo invсlidos e/ou o usuсrio nуo foi encontrado
      echo "Login invсlido!"; exit;
  } else {
     //  Salva os dados encontados na variсvel $resultado
     $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
  }


      // Se a sessуo nуo existir, inicia uma
      if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

       //Salva os dados encontrados na sessуo
      $_SESSION['UsuarioID'] = $resultado['id'];
      $_SESSION['UsuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
      $_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] = $resultado['nivel'];

       // Redireciona o visitante
      **header("Location: novaTela.php");** 
      exit;


?>
```

Comment: Duplicata de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4251/5878

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` deve ser sempre a primeira coisa que deve ser executada na sua aplicação, se ele for executado depois ou for duplicado, aparecerá esse erro.

Apague isso:

```
// Se a sessуo nуo existir, inicia uma
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
```

E coloque session_start(); como a primeira coisa executada no seu `index.php`

Comment: Bom dia Samuel. Fiz isso, mas continua dando o erro abaixo: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/netosale/public_html/e-educacao/validacao.php:2) in /home/netosale/public_html/e-educacao/validacao.php on line 3

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/netosale/public_html/e-educacao/validacao.php:2) in /home/netosale/public_html/e-educacao/validacao.php on line 36

Comment: Edita sua pergunta colocando o conteúdo de todos esses arquivos.