# Problema com página de Login, redirecionamento

Tags: php, login, pgadmin

Ela funciona bem, não deixa passar as credenciais que não sejam as configuradas. Mas na hora de redirecionar ela para a outra, não funciona.

```
session_start();

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $isim = $_POST['login'];
    $sifre = $_POST['password'];

    var_dump($isim, $sifre);

    if($isim == 'teste' && password_verify($sifre, '$2y$10$OvT4fn4/S7cF2O4Rgr1hK.lhz0lKPaaEuyO/Bxn23HA7lFQEsCLoy')) {
        $_SESSION['auth'] = 1;

        header('Location: main.php');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Depois disso ela deveria me redirecionar para a página `"main.php"`, mas o que aparece é uma tela em branco. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso queiram acessar para observar:

username: teste

password: teste

https://raindroipstexter.000webhostapp.com/panel/login.php

Coloquei este code, agora me aparecem outros erros suprimidos.

> error_reporting(E_ALL); 
>   ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

[image]

Comment: Veja o que `password_verify` está retornando `var_dump(password_verify('teste', '$2y$10$OvT4fn4/S7cF2O4Rgr1hK.lhz0lKPaaEuyO/Bxn23HA7lFQEsCLoy'));`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro - "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent)

Comment: coloca o var_dump dentro do if pra ver se ele tá aceitando como verdadeiro, se não imprimir nada na tela é porque a condição não está sendo verdadeira

Comment: Se o var_dump ainda estiver sendo exibido, então esta está sendo verdadeira, após confirmar você a apaga do seu script, creio que não pode ter nada de output antes do header