# Como impedir o reenvio de dados ao atualizar(F5) no PHP?

Tags: php

Boa noite pessoal, estou criando um jogo online onde o usuário tem a opção de utilizar um item para recuperar HP. Ao clicar em consumir, um alert aparece na tela informando que o item foi consumido e que o HP foi recuperado.

O problema, como vocês podem imaginar, é que toda vez que eu aperto F5 o HP continua aumenta e o alert aparece novamente. Tentei usar **unset($_POST[''])** para limpar o que foi escolhido pelo usuário mas não funcionou.

Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Comment: Idealmente, uma requisição POST jamais deveria possuir uma página HTML como resposta, justamente por causa deste problema. O correto seria você definir o cabeçalho `Location` e redirecionar o cliente novamente à página original.

Comment: É que essa requisição acontece na "página principal" do jogo: taberna.php. Consumir o item que recupera HP é uma das funções disponíveis nesta página, então o ideal é que após consumir o item o usuário permaneça nessa página, entende?

Comment: Isso não muda nada, você pode redirecionar para ela mesma, mas sem post.

Comment: Pode me dizer como fazer isso?

Comment: Exato, fazendo o `Location` para a mesma página, o cliente passará a fazer uma requisição GET e não mais uma POST.

Comment: Tem 5 links no fechamento da pergunta, lá tem mais detalhado o que você precisa.

Comment: Certo, obrigado pela ajuda pessoal, acho que entendi

Comment: Melhor ainda seria mandar para um "recebe.php" que redireciona para a "taberna.php" de volta, assim confunde menos o código. (o usuário não vai enxergar essa "recebe.php" pq ja vai ser enviado de volta com `header( 'Location: /recebe.php');die();`

Comment: Uma página vazia que só teria um redirecionamento para a página principal?

Comment: Exato, nessa só teria o PHP de salvar no DB ou processar os dados, e o header location. Leia esse link aqui, pode ajudar se encontrar um erro de headers: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/70

Comment: Este erro foi o primeiro que eu encontrei quando comecei, criei minha conta aqui justamente para descobrir como resolve-lo hahahahaha.
Muito obrigado pela ajuda, entendi o que tenho que fazer