# Como redirecionar o usuário para uma pagina especifica com PHP?

Tags: php, login, redirecionamento

Gostaria de saber como faço para redirecionar o usuário para a pagina que eu quiser assim que ele se logar? 
exemplo

login:diego.santos
senha:12345
queria que redirecionasse para exemplo id1.php

login:santos.diego
senha:12345
queria que redirecionasse para exemplo id2.php

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar a função `header`, por exemplo:

```
/** Redirecionar o usuário para /home.php: */
header('Location: /home.php');
```

Link para a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php).

#### Uma observação importante:

Você só pode usar essa função **antes de ter enviado qualquer resposta** ao cliente, tendo em vista que é um cabeçalho da resposta.

Para saber mais, considere ler [essa pergunta e resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent).

Answer (score 0):

O melhor é se criasses Tags para cada utilizador e verificasses as tags, mas se queres uma coisa básica podes usar este código:

```
if($nome == "diego.santos" && $password == "12345"){
header('Location: id1.php');
}else if($nome == "santos.diego" && $password == "12345"){
header('Location: id2.php');
}
```

**Isto é um exemplo rápido e não é uma forma correta de fazer Login**

Comment: Qual seria a forma correta ?preciso redirecionar 10 usuários cada um para sua página.

Comment: Depende muito do estejas a usar e de que tenhas acesso, caso estejas a usar uma base de dados e tenhas um id único para cada utilizador podes fazer assim `header('Location: id' . $userid . '.php')`

Comment: Cara .. no BD cada um tem um id ! Agora precisava fazer com que cada um, assim que se logasse fosse para alguma página que eu escolher .