# DOMPDF Salvar/Download arquivo no cliente

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

Estou utilizando o dompdf, preciso fazer o download automatico do arquivo, como fazer isso?

Estou utilizando o código abaixo:

```
 $dompdf = new DOMPDF ();
 $dompdf->load_html($resultado[0]['recibo']);
 $dompdf->render();
 $dompdf->stream("Recibo.pdf", array("Attachment" => true));
```

Era pra abrir o dialogo de salvar o arquivo, mas to recebendo o seguinte erro:

Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent

Pq?

Comment: "headers already sent" significa que tem algo antes do teu DOMPDF que esta sendo enviado junto no download, talvez um echo, um print, ou HTML mesmo. Ou seja o DOMPDF tem que ser executado em uma página que não tenha qualquer outro conteudo, como HTML ou texto, somente o DOMPDF mesmo.

Comment: Alguma alternativa ao DOMPDF? Ta foda usar isso aqui.

Comment: Não é culpa do DOMPDF e nem vai conseguir resolver o problema usando outra lib, leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/18812/3635

Comment: resolvi tirando um $_GET que passava vazio

Comment: Pois é, o $_GET devia emitir um warning antes do header location, ai o erro, conteudo de texto ou HTML antes do DOMPDF e do header location.