# PHP - Mostrar mensagem de dados inseridos correctamente

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Estou com dificuldade em colocar uma mensagem a dizer : Dados inseridos com sucesso e depois enviar para outra página.

```
<?php
  include 'ligacao_pdo.php';

    $condutor = $_POST['condutor'];
    $carro = $_POST['carro'];
    $matricula = $_POST['matricula'];

 if (!$ligacao->query("INSERT INTO condutor (condutor, carro, matricula) VALUES ('$condutor', '$carro', '$matricula')"))

{
   echo"SUCESSO";
   header("location: add.php");

 }
```

Comment: Se você vai redirecionar para outra página, por que exibir uma mensagem?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro - "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent)

Comment: Se tiver sucesso salve a mensagem de sucesso em uma variável de sessão, assim na outra página vc chama a variável, vou fazer um exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Na página que faz a inserção no banco, vc salva uma variável de sessão com a mensagem, assim:

```
<?php
include 'ligacao_pdo.php';
session_start();
$condutor = $_POST['condutor'];
$carro = $_POST['carro'];
$matricula = $_POST['matricula'];

if (!$ligacao->query("INSERT INTO condutor (condutor, carro, matricula) VALUES ('$condutor', '$carro', '$matricula')"))
{
    $_SESSION['sucesso'] = "Dados salvos com sucesso!";
    header("location: add.php");
}
?>
```

E na add.php que a página para qual o usuário será redirecionado:

```
<script>
    alert("<?= $_SESSION['sucesso'];?>");
</script>
```

OU só um echo:

```
<?= $_SESSION['sucesso']; ?>
```

testa aí.

Comment: Não estou a conseguir redireccionar para a página add.php

Comment: Dá algum erro?
Estão no mesmo diretório?