# Erro ao invocar metodo Setter PHP com Interface!

Tags: php-7

Fala galera, tudo beleza?

Eu estou estudando Interfaces em PHP e estou tendo um erro ao invocar o método setter nos meus atributos.

```
<!-- User Interface -->
<?php
session_start();
interface User {

public function userName($uName);
public function userEmail($uMail);
public function userPasswd($uPass); 

}

class Cliente implements User{
private $userName;
private $userEmail;
private $userPasswd;

/**
 * Get the value of userName
 */ 
public function getUserName()
{
    return $this->userName;
}

/**
 * Set the value of userName
 *
 * @return  self
 */ 
public function setUserName($userName)
{
    $this->userName = $userName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get the value of userEmail
 */ 
public function getUserEmail()
{
    return $this->userEmail;
}

/**
 * Set the value of userEmail
 *
 * @return  self
 */ 
public function setUserEmail($userEmail)
{
    $this->userEmail = $userEmail;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get the value of userPasswd
 */ 
public function getUserPasswd()
{
    return $this->userPasswd;
}

/**
 * Set the value of userPasswd
 *
 * @return  self
 */ 
public function setUserPasswd($userPasswd)
{
    $this->userPasswd = $userPasswd;

    return $this;
}

public function userName($uName)
{              
    $this.setUserName($uName);
    echo    "<br>".
            "<p>Nome:".getUserName()."</p>";         

}

public function userEmail($uMail)
{
    $this.setUserEmail($uMail);
    echo    "<br>".
            "<p>Email:".getUserEmail()."</p>";

}

public function userPasswd($uPass)
{

    $this.setUserPasswd($uPass);
    echo    "<br>".
            "<p>Email:".getUserPasswd()."</p>";       

}



}

$usuario = new Cliente();

if(isset($_POST["name"])){
    $usuario->userName($_POST["name"]);
}

if(isset($_POST["email"])){
    $usuario->userEmail($_POST["email"]);
}

if(isset($_POST["passwd"])){
    $usuario->userPasswd($_POST["passwd"]);
}

?>
```

E o Erro:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function setUserName() in D:\Programacao\Xampp\htdocs\PHP7\interface\exe02.php:79 Stack trace: #0 
D:\Programacao\Xampp\htdocs\PHP7\interface\exe02.php(109): Cliente->userName('Vitor') #1 {main} thrown in D:\Programacao\Xampp\htdocs\PHP7\interface\exe02.php on line 79
```

Não acho que o erro esteja relacionado com a Interface, mas não entendo ele retornar Undefined em um método existente e Public.

Os dados estão vindo de um form em outra pagina, acredito que seja irrelevante para o problema.

Desde já agradeço a atenção

Comment: Sintaxe incorreta em alguns trechos.  nunca se usa nada além disso para invocar métodos. "->" vc coloca pontos e asvezes omite o $this->

Comment: Sim, a resposta abaixo me indicou esses erros de sintaxe, mas obrigado mesmo assim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu script esta cheio de erros, primeiro:

```
$this.setUserEmail($uMail);
```

O `$this` em PHP usa `->` e não ponto, deveria ser:

```
$this->setUserEmail($uMail);
```

Segundo, métodos da classe devem ser sempre acessadas via `$this` em caso de objetos e se forem estáticos com `self::` (ou `parent::` que neste caso seria equivalente ao `super()` em Java), isto:

```
"<p>Email:".getUserEmail()."</p>";
```

Deveria ser isto:

```
"<p>Email:".$this->getUserEmail()."</p>";
```

Em mais de um lugar do script tem estes 2 problemas, corrija todos eles e provavelmente vai funcionar.

---

Outro problema (que talvez seja um problema ou não, se você estiver usando **buffer**), `session_start` usa o header em HTTP para declarar os cookies, todo header de uma resposta HTTP (todo site é HTTP) envia os headers antes do corpo, mas no momento que você adicionou

```
<!-- User Interface -->
```

Antes do `session_start` você estará forçando o PHP a enviar o corpo e o `session_start` não vai funcionar porque será impossivel enviar o header

Leia mais em:

- [Erro - "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4251/3635)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Foi desatenção minha em relação ao uso do $this, já corrigi e funcionou perfeitamente! Quanto a questão do header, eu não sabia mesmo que poderia ocorrer esse problema, obrigado novamente!!