# Converter Boleto PHP em PDF

Tags: php, codeigniter

Eu preciso converter boletos PHP gerados em HTML para PDF.

[codeigniter-boleto](https://github.com/natanfelles/codeigniter-boleto)

Tentei utilizar a biblioteca DomPDF, assim como FPDF e por fim, MPDF (esta última, pelo que li em alguns fóruns, seria melhor, por questões de compatibilidade CSS).

Meu trabalho está sendo no framework CodeIgniter.

Alguém, por favor, que já passou por este problema pode me ajudar a resolver este problema, visto que estou recebendo os erros abaixo:

> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Program Files (x86)\VertrigoServ\www\material\application\libraries\boleto\include\layout_bb.php:494)
>
> mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file

E não estou conseguindo gerar o PDF.

```
public function index()
{
    $dados = array(
        // Informações necessárias para todos os bancos
        'dias_de_prazo_para_pagamento' => 5,
        'taxa_boleto'                  => 1,
        'pedido'                       => array(
            'nome'           => 'Serviços de Desenvolvimento Web',
            'quantidade'     => '10',
            'valor_unitario' => '80',
            'numero'         => 10000000025,
            'aceite'         => 'N',
            'especie'        => 'R$',
            'especie_doc'    => 'DM',
        ),
        'sacado'                       => array(
            'nome'     => 'João da Silva',
            'endereco' => 'Av. Meninas Bonitas, 777',
            'cidade'   => 'Sapiranga',
            'uf'       => 'RS',
            'cep'      => '93816-630',
        ),
        // Informações necessárias que são específicas do Banco do Brasil
        'variacao_carteira'            => '019',
        'contrato'                     => 999999,
        'convenio'                     => 7777777,
    );

    // Gera o boleto
    //$this->boleto->bb($dados);
    
    $this->load->helper('mpdf');
    $html = ($this->boleto->bb($dados));
    pdf_create($html, 'boleto' . date('d/m/y'), TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro - "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent)

Comment: Não é duplicata! Eu consigo gerar qualquer outro tipo de PDF, mas não consegui gerar utilizando o boleto PHP, talvez alguem tenha passado por isto

Comment: Você tentou apenas gerar na tela o boleto? Pra ver se não tem nenhum erro.

Comment: Na tela ele gera normalmente, no PDF que não gera

Comment: Hey, tá errado: $html = ($this->boleto->bb($dados)); ... $data['boleto'] = $this->boleto->bb($dados); $html = $this->load->view('boleto', $data);

Comment: O PDF tem algumas particularidades, você tem o HTML, colococa aqui tbm

Comment: Mas porque devo chamar uma view ?

`$this->load->view('boleto', $data);`

Eu não tenho esta view.

Se observar no repositório https://github.com/natanfelles/codeigniter-boleto, não precisa de view