# Censura de Pagina para não logado

Tags: php, html, mysqli, login

Estou com um problema na hora de colocar um bloqueio de pagina...

Quando coloco o bloqueio no topo do site, que no caso estava usando isso:

```
    if(!empty($_SESSION['id'])){
    echo "Olá ".$_SESSION['nome'].", Bem vindo <br>";
    echo "<a href='sair.php'>Sair</a>";
}else{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Área restrita";
    header("Location: login.php");  
}
```

Ele me dá esse erro: **headers already sent**

Por conta dessa linha na minha pagina:

```
> if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)){      $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p
> style='color:green;'>Item apagado com sucesso</p>";
>       header("Location: adm_tabela.php"); **//Essa Linha que dá o erro**
```

Como fazer o bloqueio dela para que nao de erro ?

Comment: É porque está fazendo dois redirecionamentos. Tem que acabar o script no `else`... Tenta colocar um `die();` depois da linha `header("Location: login.php");` no `else`

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4251/23400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema ocorre porque você está fazendo `header: Location: ...` duas vezes, já que o script não é interrompido quando deveria (ao final do `else`, uma vez que a intenção é redirecionar o usuário sem permissão para a página de login).

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent) tem mais detalhes, e neste trecho está a descrição do problema:

> A página/output sempre segue os headers. O PHP é obrigado a passar os
>   headers ao servidor primeiramente. **Ele pode apenas fazer isto uma vez.**
>   E depois da quebra de linha dupla (envio de output para simplificar),
>   ele não pode adicionar mais headers. (grifei)

Para corrigir basta fazer [`exit`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.die.php) ou [`die`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4251/erro-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent) no final do `else`, assim o redirecionamento ocorrerá e o script será interrompido:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['id'])){        
    echo "Olá ".$_SESSION['nome'].", Bem vindo <br>";
    echo "<a href='sair.php'>Sair</a>";
}

else {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Área restrita";
    header("Location: login.php"); 
    exit();
}
```